# Convertir PDO a Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Necesito convertir este código `PDO` a `Mysqli` pero sin array porque yo le mando los datos de la siguiente manera

```
$_SESSION['CodUsua']

function usuario_por_codigo($CodUsua)
    {
        $con = conexion("root", "");
        $consulta = $con->prepare("select * from usuarios where CodUsua = :CodUsua");
        $consulta->execute(array(':CodUsua' => $CodUsua));
        $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
        return $resultado;
    }
```

Comment: igual mysqli preparado?

Comment: es que no entiendo ese código PDO:/ y quiero más o menos saber como va o mandarle datos sin el array

Comment: okey, te pasare como se asigna.

Comment: es que no entiendo para que sirve prepare,execute,fetchall además quisiera saber su equivalencia en mysqli ... y tengo la duda de que porque se coloca array? no se si se coloca por la base de datos o por si en el registro hice una función en la cual puse los datos en un arreglo

Comment: **Recomendaría seguir usando PDO**

Comment: aún tengo una duda

Comment: @CarlosBonilla voy poco a poco, es que estoy comiendo y publicando jajajaj

Comment: jajaja enserio gracias

Comment: por lo que entendi en esa parte le estoy diciendo que ':CodUsua' tendra el valor de $CodUsua así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**¿Como funciona PDO?.**

> PDO: objetos de datos de PHP.

Son una forma de consultar a la base de datos preparando antes la setnencia SQL, de manera que esta se guarde y ejecute antes en el motor SQL y luego le asignemos los parametros o datos que queremos que se trabajen con la consulta.

El codigo una vez se ejecuta este unira al codigo SQL los parametros y ejecutara la consulta.

Evitando que puedan manipular tu string de SQL y los datos.

---

**Paso cero:** El funcionamiento.

Las consultas PDO preparadas funcionan asi:

1) Creo mi sentencia SQL.

2) La preparo.

3) Asigno los parámetros que tendrá (Sino hay, seguimos directo a la ejecución).

4) Ejecuto la sentencia.

5) Los retorno para usarlos.

---

**Primer paso:** La conexion.

Este codigo de conexion esta adaptado a la guia de phpdelusion.net.
La cual asegura sentencias preparadas con proteccion anti inyeccion SQL.

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$base= "basedatos";
$codificacion= "utf8";
$usuario = "root";
$contraseña = "pass";

try {
    $datosConexion = "mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$base;charset=$codificacion";
    $atributosConexion= [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                         PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                         PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false];
    $conexion= new PDO($datosConexion,$usuario,$contrasena,$atributosConexion);


    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    }
```

---

**Segundo paso**: Las consultas simples:

Estas son cuando queremos obtener datos sencillos (sin condiciones WHERE) de la base de datos, para eso NO necesitamos preparar nada.

Por lo tanto no usaremos preparacion, sino el comando `query()`

```
query() :
```

> Ejecuta una consulta estandarizada SQL a la base de datos, esto
>   requiere escapar correctamente los datos para evitar inyecciones sql
>   (vease: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)), generalmente se usa
>   cuando obtendrás datos sin ninguna condición o característica, es
>   decir sin usar WHERE.

Serian de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = 'SELECT nombre, color, calorias FROM frutas ORDER BY nombre';
    foreach ($conexion->query($sql) as $valor) {
        echo $valor['nombre'] . "\t";
        echo $valor['color'] . "\t";
        echo $valor['calorias'] . "\n";
    }
```

---

**Tercer paso:** Usando condiciones WHERE o mejor dicho, usando parámetros.

Ahora veamos, que ocurre si necesitamos colocarle parametros a las sentencias SQL, para obtener algo asi:

```
"SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = $usuario";
```

Para eso debemos asignar parametros, usando `execute()`

```
execute() :
```

> Corre o ejecuta una sentencia preparada que permite asignar parámetros
>   que evitan la inyección SQL ya que no debes recurrir a comillas o
>   escapar caracteres, en el caso de que quieras ejecutar de nuevo la
>   consulta a la base de datos, basta con ejecutar execute de nuevo para
>   hacerlo.

Esto requiere ademas que la sentencia se prepare antes.

**Ejemplo:**

```
//preparacion
$consulta = $conexion->prepare('SELECT nombre, color, calorias FROM frutas
    WHERE calorias < :calorias AND color = :color');

//Asignacion, ojo, se puede usar bindParam, pero segun he leido es mejor usar bindValue

$consulta->bindValue(':calorias', $calorias);
$consulta->bindValue('color', $color);

//Ejecuto la sentencia.
$consulta->execute();
```

**Donde:**

```
 $consulta->bindValue('calorias', $calorias) -> Asignar parametros
```

Le asignamos $calorias al parametro calorias , el cual corresponde al campo calorias de la tabla frutas.

---

**Cuarto Paso:** Marcado de posiciones.

Cuando vamos a asignar parametros a las sentencais, estos ocuparan un lugar llamado *Marcado de poscicion*, hay dos formas de utilizarlos.

**1) Usando ":nombreDelCampo"**

Tenemos la siguiente sentencia SQL:

```
"SELECT nombre FROM producto WHERE idProducto = $producto";
```

Su version parametrizada seria:

```
"SELECT nombre FROM producto WHERE idProducto = :producto";
```

**Donde**

```
idProducto es el campo de la tabla
:producto es la cajita que luego recibira el valor asignado
```

Esta forma permite que nosotros asignemos en cualquier orden posible los parametros, pues de igual manera como esten ordenados ellos ya tienen su lugar correspondiente.

**Ejemplo 2:**

```
"SELECT nombre FROM producto WHERE idProducto = :producto AND precio > :precio";
```

Si en esta sentencia hacemos esto:

```
$consulta->bindValue(':precio', $precio);
$consulta->bindValue(':producto', $producto);
```

No habra problemas, esta forma tambien permite mantener una mejor mantenibilidad del sistema, al poder tener nombres para cada parametro.

**2) Usando ?**

Otra forma es usar el signo interrogatorio cerrado (?), la ventaja no escribes tanto jejeje, la desventaja el codigo debe asignar los parametros en el mismo orden que estan puestos en la sentencia SQL.

**Ejemplo:**

Tenemos la siguiente sentencia SQL:

```
"SELECT nombre FROM producto WHERE idProducto = $producto";
```

Su version parametrizada seria:

```
"SELECT nombre FROM producto WHERE idProducto = ?";
```

Donde ? recibira la asignacion al parametro.

**Ejemplo 2:**

```
"SELECT nombre FROM producto WHERE idProducto = ? AND precio > ?";
```

Si en esta sentencia hacemos esto:

```
$consulta->bindValue(1, $precio);
$consulta->bindValue(2, $producto);
```

Causa error, porque estamos asignando el precio al ID y el ID al precio.

por lo tanto para esta forma se debe seguir el orden.

Siendo lo correcto:

```
$consulta->bindValue(1, $producto);
$consulta->bindValue(2, $precio);
```

Usamos 1,2,3,4,5 para el numero de marcador de posición, porque la funcion `bindValue` espera dos valores.

---

**Quinto Paso:** Notas adicionales

Como observas en la sentencia SQL cuando igualamos idProducto = :idProducto , se presentan dos puntos, eso representa que :idProducto es una cajita donde se metera luego el valor de la variable asignada.

Esto porque las sentencias preparadas primero mandan a MySQL la sentencia:

```
SELECT nombre, color, calorias FROM frutas
        WHERE calorias < :calorias AND color = :color
Y luego le mandan los valores

:color, $color
```

Para que al darle execute ambas se combinen algo asi:

```
SELECT nombre, color, calorias FROM frutas
        WHERE calorias < $calorias AND color=$color
```

Pero todo ocurre dentro del mismo MySQL, no en el PHP.

NOTA: Colocar los dos puntos en la asignacion es opcional, tambien funciona asi:

```
$consulta->bindValue("producto", $producto);
```

**Sexto paso:** Formas de asignar parametros

Para asignar parametros a PDO, tenemos distintas formas igualmente validas, te mostrare dos por ahora:

**1) Usando array:**

```
$_SESSION['CodUsua']

function usuario_por_codigo($CodUsua)
    {
        $con = conexion("root", "");
        $consulta = $con->prepare("select * from usuarios where CodUsua = :CodUsua");
        $consulta->execute(array(':CodUsua' => $CodUsua));
        $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
        return $resultado;
    }
```

**2) Usando bindValue:**

```
 $_SESSION['CodUsua']

    function usuario_por_codigo($CodUsua)
        {
            $con = conexion("root", "");
            $consulta = $con->prepare("select * from usuarios where CodUsua = :CodUsua");
            $consulta->bindValue(':CodUsua',$CodUsua);
            $consulta->execute;
            $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
            return $resultado;
        }
```

**Octavo paso:** ¿Falta mas?, seee. Obtener los resultados.

Una vez hemos preparado, asignado y ejecutado, falta recuperar los datos, para eso usamos `fetch`

Tenemos diferentes posibilidades de recuperar los datos, pero te dejare la que yo uso:

PARA MAYOR CONOCIMIENTO ENTRA A:

**http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php**

**Consultas simples**:

```
foreach ($conexion->query($sql) as $valor) {
        echo $valor['nombre'] . "\t";
        echo $valor['color'] . "\t";
        echo $valor['calorias'] . "\n";
    }
```

**Consultas preparadas:**
**fetchAll:** Devolver la siguiente fila como un array indexado por nombre de columna

```
    // 1 //
    $consulta->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($consulta->fetchAll() as $key => $value) {
        return $value;
    }

    //2//
    $consulta = $conexion->query('SELECT name FROM users');
    while ($resultados = $consulta->fetch())
    {
     echo $resultados['campoBaseDatos'] . "\n";
    }

    //3//
    $sql = 'SELECT primerNombre FROM  usuarios';
    foreach ($conexion->query($sql) as $valor) {
        echo $valor['primerNombre'] . "\t";
    }

    //4//
    $resultados=$consulta->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($consulta->fetchAll() as $key => $value) {
        $primerNombre= $value["campodelabasededatosqueconsultamos"];
        $primerApellido= $value["primerApellido"];
    }
```

Comment: aún me queda una duda

Comment: @CarlosBonilla dime=

Comment: ':CodUsua' ese dato de donde lo obtengo? ese seria el nombre de la tabla de la base de datos? y el otro $CodUsua sería el dato que voy a mandarle vdd?

Comment: revisa la respuesta @CarlosBonilla

Comment: por lo que entendi en esa parte le estoy diciendo que ':CodUsua' tendra el valor de $CodUsua así?

Comment: @CarlosBonilla exactamente,

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @CarlosBonilla a la orden, cualquier duda , no dudes en preguntar, falta solo colocar una ultima cosita.

Comment: que hace falta colocar? y no hay una forma para que pueda contactar contigo ya que debo hacer un proyecto y tengo demasiadas dudas

Comment: @CarlosBonilla ya termine la respuesta, la mejor manera de ayudarte es pasandote este link para que leas una guia de PDO:

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Esta completa, luego de que la leas me dices tus dudas (esta en ingles) realmente PDO es muy repetitivo, es solo preparar, asignar, ejecutar y recuperar

Comment: bueno adelante y gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81028/manejar-conexiones-a-bases-de-datos-mysql-mediante-pdo-principios-b%C3%A1sicos/81029?noredirect=1#comment149984_81029 @CarlosBonilla eh aqui una guia que se esta armando buena