# Consultar y leer datos MySQL mediante PDO de forma segura y eficiente

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Dado que [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php) es una de las clases recomendadas por PHP para manejar nuestras conexiones a las bases de datos MySQL (la otra es MySQLi), y sabiendo que la extensión `mysql_*` es desde hace un tiempo obsoleta. Quisiera saber cómo consultar a una base de datos de forma segura mediante PDO y cómo leer los datos obtenidos en la consulta. Si es posible, sería útil una respuesta que indique con claridad en cuáles casos se debe usar consultas preparadas y en cuales no.

Nota: Esta pregunta conlleva una auto-respuesta que será marcada como *Wiki de comunidad*, con la esperanza de que la misma sirva como punto de referencia para promover **buenas prácticas** en el uso de PDO.

Lo que me ha motivado a realizarla ha sido la gran cantidad de preguntas planteadas al respecto en Stackoverflow, y la alta cantidad de respuestas dadas que no previenen en absoluto de peligros tan graves como la Inyección SQL.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61040/discussion-on-question-by-a-cedano-manejar-conexiones-a-bases-de-datos-mysql-me).

Comment: La pregunta fue reabierta por la comunidad ¿por qué la pones en espera de nuevo? ¿Exceso en tu autoridad de moderador @Luiggi-Mendoza?

Comment: La pregunta no fue reabierta por la comunidad, tenía 2 votos y otro moderador la abrió (eso también es autoridad de moderador, no son los 5 votos de la comunidad). Si tienes más dudas sobre el estado de esta pregunta, puedes publicar en meta respecto a esta pregunta. De momento, seguirá cerrada.

Comment: Me gustaría que la vuelvan a abrir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gran parte de esta respuesta está tomada de la que es sin duda una de las mejores guías de PDO que conozco publicada en phpdelusions bajo el título: [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

En un principio la respuesta (y la pregunta) eran más extensas. La he reducido a los aspectos principales de PDO, en los que, por experiencia, veo más fallos en las preguntas planteadas aquí.

## I. Consultas en PDO

Podemos decir que hay **dos tipos de consultas en PDO**:

### 1. Consultas sin criterios o filtros

Si en la consulta **no intervienen datos desde el exterior**, la misma se puede pasar directamente a la base de datos, sin riesgo, mediante el método  [`query`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), el cual ejecutará la consulta y devolverá un objeto especial de la clase [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). Luego podrá leerse ese recurso para obtener las filas reales:

```
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $row['name'] . "\n";
    }
```

Además, el método `query()` nos permite usar un encadenamiento de método puro para consultas `SELECT`.

### 2. Consultas con criterios o filtros

Si en la consulta intervienen datos desde el exterior, es decir, **si se va a utilizar alguna variable en ella**, hay una sola manera correcta de proceder: **usando consultas preparadas**. La razón por la que es tan importante se explica en detalle en las respuestas a: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967) En esencia, el no usar consultas preparadas podría permitir a cualquier usuario mal intencionado enviar a la base de datos o al mismo sistema, código malicioso.

#### ¿Cómo se escribe y se prepara una consulta?

Aunque parezca complicado, sobre todo al principio, no lo es. Se trata de dos sencillos pasos:

- Se escribe la consulta sustituyendo las variables que intervienen en ella (datos que vienen desde el exterior), por un marcador. Hay dos tipos de marcadores. Uno se llama marcador de posición: `?` y otro se llama marcador de nombre `:nombrecualquiera`.

Podemos usar cualquiera de los dos, pero no uno y otro combinados.

- El paso siguiente es preparar la consulta, usando el método [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) y  luego ejecutarla usando [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). En el método `execute` enviamos a la base de datos los valores que hemos recibido desde el exterior. De esta forma *viajan* separados de la instrucción SQL en sí, haciendo casi imposible el hecho de la *Inyección SQL*.

Para preparar consultas, PDO admite los marcadores de posición (`?`) y de nombre (`:email`). Veremos ejemplos de cada uno y lo que los  caracteriza y lo que hay que tener en cuenta.

Un ejemplo usando **marcadores de posición `?`**:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND status=?');
$stmt->execute([$email, $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Nótese que para los marcadores de posición hay que proporcionar una matriz regular con valores. Las comillas nunca deben utilizarse alrededor de marcadores de posición.

Los marcadores de posición permiten escribir un código más corto, pero son sensibles al orden de los argumentos (que deben ser exactamente iguales al orden de los marcadores de posición correspondientes en la consulta).

Un ejemplo usando marcadores de nombre `:nombre`:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND status=:status');
$stmt->execute(['email' => $email, 'status' => $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Nótese que para los marcadores de nombre tiene que pasar una matriz asociativa, donde las claves tienen que coincidir con los nombres del marcador  en la consulta. Los marcadores de nombre hacen que su código sea más detallado, permiten orden de enlace aleatorio.

Los marcadores de nombre siempre comienzan con dos puntos y se pueden escribir utilizando sólo letras, dígitos y subrayados. Las comillas nunca deben utilizarse alrededor de marcadores de nombre.

También tenga en cuenta que a pesar de una ilusión generalizada, los dos puntos  "`:`" en las llaves no son necesarios. Es decir, son obligatorios en la instrucción SQL, pero no en el array que se pasa posteriormente.

Cuando la consulta es preparada usando el método `prepare()`, éste devolverá el mismo objeto `PDOStatement` del que hablábamos anteriormente, pero sin datos adjuntos a él.

Finalmente, para ejecutar la consulta, se usa el método `execute()` de este objeto, pasando variables en él, en forma de array. Y después de eso, podremos obtener los datos resultantes de la consulta (si es aplicable).

> Si eres un programador de PHP que te respetas, una de las cosas que
>   debes saber es que **nunca** debes escribir una consulta como esta:
>
> <s>`$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND
>   status='$status'";`</s>
>
> La forma correcta es usar consultas preparadas como se explica más arriba.

#### ¿Cómo funciona una consulta preparada?

La imagen muestra cómo funcionaría una consulta preparada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una de las cosas que vemos es que la consulta preparada no sólo nos ayuda a prevenir código malicioso, sino también a optimizar  nuestro código.

### 3. Ejecutando consultas del tipo `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`

Podemos decir que para PDO, cualquiera de estas 4 consultas son iguales. Porque lo que hace PDO en todas ellas es preparar una consulta con marcadores (de posición o de nombre) y, a continuación, ejecutarla, enviando variables por separado. El proceso es esencialmente el mismo. La única diferencia es (como las consultas DML no devuelven ningún dato), que puede utilizar el método de encadenamiento y, por tanto, llamar a `execute()` junto con `prepare()`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name = ? WHERE id = ?";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$name, $id]);
```

Sin embargo, si desea obtener el número de filas afectadas, el código tendrá que tener tres líneas como estas:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM goods WHERE category = ?");
$stmt->execute([$cat]);
$deleted = $stmt->rowCount();
```

## `II. Leyendo los datos obtenidos`

### 2.1 Obteniendo datos fuera de la declaración: `foreach`

La manera más básica y directa de obtener varias filas de una sentencia sería mediante el bucle foreach(). Gracias a la interfaz [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/es/class.traversable.php), con `PDOStatement` puede iterarse utilizando el operador `foreach()`:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

Este método es amigable para la memoria, ya que no carga todas las filas resultantes de golpe, sino que las entrega una por una (aunque hay que tener en cuenta lo que se dice en el apartado *Mysqlnd y consultas almacenadas en búfer.*).

### 2.2 Obteniendo datos fuera de la declaración (o statement): `fetch`

La función [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) obtiene una sola fila de la base de datos y mueve el puntero interno en el conjunto de resultados, por lo que las llamadas consecuentes a esta función devolverán todas las filas resultantes una por una. Esto hace que este método sea un análogo áspero a `mysql_fetch_array()`, pero funciona de una manera ligeramente diferente: en lugar de muchas funciones separadas (`mysql_fetch_assoc()`, `mysql_fetch_row()`, etc), sólo hay una, pero su comportamiento puede ser cambiado por un parámetro. Hay muchos modos de búsqueda en PDO, y los discutiremos más adelante, pero aquí hay unos pocos para empezar:

`PDO::FETCH_NUM` devuelve matriz enumerada

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` devuelve matriz asociativa

`PDO::FETCH_BOTH` - hace lo que los dos anteriores

`PDO::FETCH_OBJ` devuelve el objeto

`PDO::FETCH_LAZY` permite los tres métodos (numéricos asociativos y de objetos) sin sobrecarga de memoria.

De lo anterior se puede decir que esta función debe utilizarse en dos casos:

1. Cuando sólo se espera una fila, para obtener esa fila sólo. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   ```

Le dará una fila de la consulta, en forma de matriz asociativa.

2. Cuando necesitamos procesar los datos devueltos de alguna manera antes de usarlos. En este caso tiene que ser ejecutado a través de un bucle habitual, como el `foreach` mostrado anteriormente.

Otro modo útil es `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`, que puede crear un objeto de clase particular:

```
$news = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM news')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'News');
```

producirá una matriz de objetos de la clase `News`, estableciendo las propiedades de la clase a los valores devueltos. Tenga en cuenta que en este modo:

- Las propiedades se establecen antes de llamar al constructor
- para todas las propiedades indefinidas debe llamarse al método mágico `__set`
- si no hay un método `__set` en la clase, se creará una nueva propiedad
- las propiedades privadas se llenarán también, esto es un poco inesperado, pero muy práctico

Tenga en cuenta que el modo predeterminado es `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, pero puede cambiarlo usando la opción de configuración `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` como se muestra en el ejemplo de conexión. Por lo tanto, una vez establecido, puede omitirse la mayor parte del tiempo.

### 2.3 Obtención de datos fuera de la declaración en docenas de diferentes formatos: `fetchAll()`

[`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) es la función más interesante, con las características más asombrosas. Sobre todo gracias a su existencia se puede llamar a PDO un envoltorio, ya que esta función puede automatizar muchas operaciones realizadas de otra manera manualmente.

`fetchAll()` devuelve una matriz que consiste en todas las filas devueltas por la consulta. De este hecho podemos sacar dos conclusiones:

1. Esta función no debe utilizarse si se han seleccionado muchas filas. En caso de que un bucle `while` convencional deba ser utilizado, es mejor buscar las filas una por una en vez de conseguirlas todas en el arsenal inmediatamente. "Muchos" significa más de lo que es adecuado para mostrarse en una página web promedio.
2. Esta función es útil sobre todo en una aplicación web moderna que nunca envía datos inmediatamente durante la búsqueda, sino que la pasa a la plantilla.

Usted se sorprenderá, en cuántos formatos diferentes esta función puede devolver datos (y lo poco que un usuario promedio de PHP sabe de ellos), todos controlados por las variables `PDO::FETCH_*`. Algunos de ellos son:

#### 2.3.1 Obteniendo una matriz plana

De forma predeterminada, esta función devolverá simplemente una matriz 
 enumerada con todas las filas devueltas. Pero constantes de formato de fila, como `PDO::FETCH_NUM`, `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, etc. pueden cambiar el formato de fila. Por ejemplo:

```
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users')->fetchAll();
var_export($data);
/* array (
  0 => array('John'),
  1 => array('Mike'),
  2 => array('Mary'),
  3 => array('Kathy'),
)*/
```

#### 2.3.2 Obteniendo una columna

A menudo es muy útil obtener una matriz unidimensional simple fuera de la consulta, si sólo se necesita una columna entre muchas filas obtenidas:

```
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
/* array (
  0 => 'John',
  1 => 'Mike',
  2 => 'Mary',
)*/
```

#### 2.3.3 Obteniendo pares llave-valor (key-value)

La constante `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` se revela muy útil cuando necesitamos obtener la misma columna, pero no indexada por números en orden sino por otro campo:

```
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name FROM users')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
/* array (
  104 => 'John',
  110 => 'Mike',
  120 => 'Mary',
)*/
```

Tenga en cuenta que tiene que seleccionar sólo dos columnas para este modo, la primera de las cuales debe tener valores únicos.

#### 2.3.4 Obteniendo filas indexadas por un campo único

`PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` hace algo igual a lo de arriba, pero no obteniendo una columna sino una fila completa, pero indexada por un campo único:

```
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM users')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
/* array (
  104 => array (
    'name' => 'John',
    'car' => 'Toyota',
  ),
  110 => array (
    'name' => 'Mike',
    'car' => 'Ford',
  ),
  120 => array (
    'name' => 'Mary',
    'car' => 'Mazda',
  ),
)*/
```

Tenga en cuenta que la primera columna seleccionada tiene que ser única (en esta consulta se supone que la primera columna es id, pero para estar más seguro es mejor listarla de forma explícita).

#### 2.3.5 Obtención de filas agrupadas por algún campo

`PDO::FETCH_GROUP` agrupará las filas en una matriz anidada, donde los índices serán valores únicos de las primeras columnas, y los valores serán arrays similares a los devueltos por `fetchAll()`. El siguiente código, por ejemplo, separará a los niños de las niñas y los pondrá en diferentes matrices:

```
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT sex, name, car FROM users')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
/* array (
  'male' => array (
    0 => array (
      'name' => 'John',
      'car' => 'Toyota',
    ),
    1 => array (
      'name' => 'Mike',
      'car' => 'Ford',
    ),
  ),
  'female' => array (
    0 => array (
      'name' => 'Mary',
      'car' => 'Mazda',
    ),
    1 => array (
      'name' => 'Kathy',
      'car' => 'Mazda',
    ),
  ),
)*/
```

Por lo tanto, esta es la solución ideal para una demanda tan popular como "eventos agrupados por fecha" o "productos agrupados por categoría".

**Otros modos**

Por supuesto, hay un `PDO::FETCH_FUNC` para los amantes de la programación funcional.

### 2.5 Contando filas con PDO

Aunque PDO ofrece una función llamada `rowCount()` esta suele ser usada inadecuadamente en muchos ejemplos de código, sobre todo en dos casos:

1. Para saber si una consulta arroja datos. Si lo piensa, verá que se trata de una función de uso indebido en la web. La mayor parte del tiempo se utiliza para no contar nada, sino como una mera bandera (sólo para ver si había datos devueltos). Pero para tal caso ¡usted tiene los datos en sí! Solo obtenga sus datos, usando `fetch()` o `fetchAll()` y podrá hacer las verificaciones con ellos.

   ```
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name=?");
   $stmt->execute([$name]);
   $userExists = $stmt->fetchColumn();
   ```

Exactamente lo mismo con conseguir una sola fila o una matriz con filas:

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetchAll();
if ($data) {
    // ¡Tiene los datos, no necesita para nada usar rowCount()!
}
```

Recuerde que en este primer caso no necesita el recuento, el número real de filas, sino más bien una bandera booleana para verificar si hay datos.

2. El segundo caso de uso más popular para esta función nunca debe ser utilizado en absoluto. ¡Uno nunca debe utilizar el `rowCount()` para contar las filas en la base de datos! En su lugar, uno tiene que pedir a la base de datos que los cuente y devuelva el resultado en una sola fila:

   ```
   $count = $pdo->query("SELECT count(1) FROM t")->fetchColumn();
   ```

Esta es la única manera apropiada.

En esencia:

- Si necesita saber cuántas filas hay en la tabla, utilice la consulta `SELECT COUNT (*)`.
- Si necesita saber si su consulta ha devuelto cualquier dato, compruebe los datos.
- Si todavía necesitas saber cuántas filas ha sido devuelta por alguna consulta (aunque apenas puedo imaginar un caso), puedes usar `rowCount()` o simplemente llamar `count()` a la matriz devuelta por `fetchAll()` ).

#### 4.6 Filas afectadas y último `id` insertado

PDO utiliza la función `rowCount()` para devolver tanto el número de filas devueltas por la instrucción `SELECT` como el número de filas afectadas por consultas DML. Por lo tanto, para obtener el número de filas afectadas, simplemente llame a esta función después de realizar una consulta.

Otra pregunta frecuente es causada por el hecho de que MySQL no actualizará la fila, **si el nuevo valor es el mismo que el antiguo**. Por lo tanto, el número de filas afectadas podría **diferir** del número de filas igualadas por la cláusula `WHERE`. A veces es necesario conocer este último número.

Aunque puede indicar a `rowCount()` que devuelva el número de filas igualadas en lugar de las filas afectadas al establecer la opción `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` como `TRUE`, hay que tener en cuenta que esta es una opción de conexión única y, por lo tanto, no puede cambiar su comportamiento durante el tiempo de ejecución. Lo cual en muchos contextos podría no ser muy conveniente.

Desafortunadamente, no hay ninguna contraparte PDO para la función `mysql(i)_info()` que puede ser fácilmente analizada y el número deseado encontrado. **Este es uno de los inconvenientes menores PDO.**

Un identificador auto-generado de un campo de secuencia o auto_increment en MySQL
 se puede obtener con la función [`lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php). Una respuesta a una pregunta frecuente, "¿Es esta función segura de usar en un entorno concurrente?" La respuesta es: sí, es seguro. Al ser simplemente una interfaz para la función [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html) de la API MySQL C, es perfectamente seguro.

#### 2.6 Consultas preparadas y cláusula `LIKE`

A pesar de la facilidad general de uso de PDO, hay algunas dificultades. Una de las principales es cuando tenemos que utilizar marcadores de posición con la cláusula `LIKE` . Al principio se podría pensar que tal consulta funciona:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%?%'");
```

Pero no, producirá un error. Para entender su naturaleza, uno tiene que entender que, como se dijo anteriormente, un marcador de posición tiene que representar un literal completo de datos solamente una cadena o un número. Y de ninguna manera puede representar una parte de un literal o una parte arbitraria de SQL. Por lo tanto, al trabajar con `LIKE`, tenemos que preparar nuestro literal completo primero, y luego enviarlo a la consulta de la manera habitual:

```
$search = "%$search%";
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$search]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

#### 2.8 Declaraciones preparadas y cláusula `IN`

Al igual que se dijo anteriormente, es imposible sustituir una parte de consulta arbitraria con un marcador de posición. Por lo tanto, para los valores separados por comas, como para `IN ()`, se debe crear un conjunto de `?` manualmente y ponerlos en la consulta:

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($arr);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

En caso de que haya otros marcadores de posición en la consulta, puede utilizar la función `array_merge()` para unir todas las variables en una sola matriz, agregando las demás variables en forma de matrices, en el orden en que aparecen en la consulta:

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=? AND column IN ($in) AND bar=? AND baz=?";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$params = array_merge([$foo], $arr, [$bar, $baz]);
$stm->execute($params);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Si está utilizando marcadores de posición con nombre, el código sería un poco más complejo, ya que tiene que crear una secuencia de los marcadores de posición con nombre: p. e.: `:id0,:id1,:id2` El código sería:

```
// other parameters that are going into query
$params = ["foo" => "foo", "bar" => "bar"];

$ids = [1,2,3];
$in = "";
foreach ($ids as $i => $item)
{
    $key = ":id".$i;
    $in .= "$key,";
    $in_params[$key] = $item; // collecting values into key-value array
}
$in = rtrim($in,","); // :id0,:id1,:id2

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=:foo AND id IN ($in) AND bar=:bar";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array_merge($params,$in_params)); // just merge two arrays
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Afortunadamente, para los marcadores de posición con nombres no tenemos que seguir el orden estricto, así que podemos combinar nuestros arrays en cualquier orden.

Comment: Falto citar los rollback... como manejarlos. etc

Comment: Soy yo el del -1. Esta pregunta está incompleta: dices que vas a mencionar 22 puntos, pero te quedas en 2. Y me parece que no te van a caber todos en una única respuesta (lo que viene a probar que la pregunta es demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro El punto 3 dice: **continuará**, a lo cual debo agregar ahora, **si me dejan**. Es más fácil darle al botón _cerrar_ y votar -1,  que traducir 22 puntos de un tema de suma importancia que podría ser útil a mucha gente. No comparto tu opinión en esto. Si la respuesta no entra en el formato del sitio podría existir al menos como enlaces que respondan a 22 preguntas planteadas en esSO.

Comment: 22 preguntas con un alcance más corto (y práctico) tendría mucho más sentido que esto. Tal y como está ahora es increíblemente amplio y si se permitieran preguntas como ésta, ¿por qué no "guía completa de Haskell"?¿o "manual de referencia de turbo pascal"?¿o...? Estaríamos creando un mal precedente y abriendo una puerta que sería muy difícil de cerrar y que admite más malas preguntas que buenas.

Comment: La puerta que tenemos abierta ahora @AlvaroMontoro es la de un código mediocre en muchos usuarios de habla hispana y respuestas igualmente mediocres... basta con darse un paseo pos esSO. Según tu criterio, [preguntas como estas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/5587982) no deberían de existir aquí. Pues ya ves la acogida que ha tenido en el sitio en inglés y ya ves que mucha gente se ha dedicado a responder, claro, eso es mucho más difícil que apretar el botón _cerrar_. A eso la llamo _estrechez_ de visión y dejar la puerta abierta al código mediocre.

Comment: Esa pregunta son enlaces a 100 preguntas concretas y diferentes que ya existían y que, en su totalidad, sirven de referencia para un tema particular. Pero no dejan de ser 100 preguntas separadas y concretas. Tal y como planteas la pregunta, quieres lo mismo en una nueva y única pregunta. No es lo mismo.

Comment: @A.Cedano, excelente aporte :), sugeriria que al colocar los ejemplos los campos de las tablas y tablas tengan nombres en español, ademas de que cuando muestres  la ejecucion de consultas, abarques las distintas formas de asignar parametros (array, bindValue,bindParam, etc)

Comment: @Victor-Random cuando esté terminada entonces pensaré a traducir la parte del código. Gracias por tu interés.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hermano, en el punto 3.3.2, dices esto "Las soluciones para los casos de uso más frecuentes se pueden encontrar en en punto 14 de esta respuesta." si son 7 puntos, cual seria ahora el 14?

Comment: @A.Cedano Hermano te invito a terminar la pregunta o que me hagas llegar la informacion de PDO , lo agradeceria con el corazon

Comment: @Victor-Random Se cerró la pregunta hace unos días y parece que la mayoría (no por mucho) están a favor de que siga cerrada. Cabe imaginar que esto desanime a Cedano. Si tu o cualquier otro quereis cambiar o ayudar a mantener esta tendencia podeis hacerlo haciendo +1/-1 y comentando en Meta en : [¿Qué ocurre con la pregunta “Manejar conexiones a bases de datos MySQL mediante PDO: principios básicos”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2279/qu%c3%a9-ocurre-con-la-pregunta-manejar-conexiones-a-bases-de-datos-mysql-mediante)

Comment: @A.Cedano me encantaria que me la pasaras a mi correo: victoraav2017@gmail.com Si opuedes pasar la completa GENIAL

Comment: @Victor-Random La publicaré aquí, en cuanto tenga tiempo: https://stackoverflowdelusions.wordpress.com de ese modo una respuesta valiosa no quedará aplastada en el inmenso foro de esSO. Si la versión en inglés [es considerada un foro](https://phpdelusions.net), esta mucho más.