# Mensajes con php y ajax

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Al momento de querer hacer un fetch_array me manda este error y no logro resolverlo

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_array()

mi codigo hasta el momento es el siguiente

```
<?php 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE receiver = $us ORDER BY id DESC";
            $run = $conexion->query($query);

            while ($row = $run->fetch_array()) : <--- aqui marca el error

            ?>
            <!--  -->
              <div id="chat_data">
                <span style="color:green"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </span>
                <span style="color:brown"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>
                <span style="float:right"><?php echo fecha($mensas['send']); ?></span>
              </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <form action="single-mensajes.php" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="name_empresa" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][3])  ?>">
              <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="Ingresa el mensaje"></textarea>
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['receiver']; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['emitter']; ?>">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
            </form>

            <?php

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

              $name = $_POST['name'];
              $message = $_POST['message'];
              $receiver = $_POST['receiver'];
              $emitter = $_POST['emitter'];

              $query = "INSERT INTO mensajes (emitter, receiver, message, name) VALUES('$emitter', '$receiver', '$message', '$name')";

              $run = $conexion->query($query);

              if ($run) {
                echo "<embed loop='false' src='chat.way' hidden='true' autoplay='true' />";
              }
            }            

            ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: PDO no tiene un método llamado `fetch_array` sino  un método `fetch` dentro del cual indicas cómo quieres el resultado. Ejemplo: `while ($row = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {...` Ver: **[El punto 4.2 de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81029/29967)**  y el **[Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)**

Comment: Por otra parte, tu código es vulnerable a la **Inyección SQL**. Es una mala práctica construir directamente las cadenas SQL con los valores. Los estándares actuales de programación exigen al menos el uso de **consultas preparadas**, en las cuales se pasa por un lado la consulta SQL con marcadores de posición y por otro lado se pasan los datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano claro, que no es un abuena practica, solo lo puse todo junto para que fuera una manera mas facil de leer, pero gracias por el comentario

Comment: De nada. En lo que tienes que facilitar las cosas cuando preguntas es tratando de explicar lo más claro posible el problema. Poner un código **vulnerable** no facilita nada, más bien lo complica porque hace que alguien se dedique a indicarte que _tu código es vulnerable_ porque se asume que compartes el código tal y como lo tienes escrito. En mi caso, si te respondo a esta pregunta me voy a tomar el tiempo de indicarte que tu código no es seguro y de mostrarte un código seguro, porque lo considero más importante que un simple error de sintaxis o de método.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por tu retroalimentacion, lo tomare en cuenta para futuras preguntas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia la siguiente linea:

```
while($row = $run->fetch_array()){
```

por la siguiente:

```
while($row = $run->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
```

Lo que pasa aquí es que si usas fetch como ya dijo @A.Cedano sólo se esta obteniendo un resultado sin importar que la consulta devuelva 2 o más.

En cuanto a:  `PDO::FETCH__PALABRA` puedes usar `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`,que devuelve un array que con indices asociativos y con indices numericos o `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` que solo te permite usar indices asociativos

Comment: Creo que para este caso sería mejor usar solo `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` y no `fetchAll`, puesto que los resultados van a ser recorridos dentro de un bucle. Ver los puntos 4.2 y 4.4 de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81029/29967

Comment: Esta vez tengo un nuevo problema y he leido el post que compartiste en el link, pero no he tenido acierto ingrese un parametro WHERE y ha tirado error https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82352/chat-ajax-y-php?noredirect=1#comment152215_82352