# Chat Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy tratando de mandar a llamar algunos datos de mi base de datos dependiendo del id de emisor y el id del receptor pero este me tira un error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in line 16

**EDITADO**

```
<?php 

require 'functions.php';

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "empleos";

$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$db_name, $user, $pass);

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE receiver = $us AND emitter = ? ORDER BY id DESC';
            $run = $conexion->query($query);

            while ($row = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :

            ?>
            <!--  -->
              <div id="chat_data">
                <span style="color:green"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </span><br>
                <span style="color:brown"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>
                <span style="float:right"><?php echo fecha($row['send']); ?></span><br><hr>
              </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

la variable $us viene de un fichero llamado functions.php

```
@$us = $_SESSION['usuario'][0];
```

anteriormente funcionaba a la perfeccion pero le puse las condicionales en el query `WHERE receiver = $us AND emitter = emitter` y fue ahi cuando comenzo a tirar ese error

en mi base de datos la tengo de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: $us es una variable de php? No la veo por ninguna parte en tu codigo. Y que estas intentando hacer con emitter? Creo que por alli anda el error. Tendrias que enlazar esas variables con la consulta. Puedes hacerlo por separado o usando un arreglo de asociacion. Te recomiendo este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php) en la parte de PDO.

Comment: la variable $us esta definida en el inicio de sesion, de ahi tomo el id de quien ha iniciado sesion

Comment: @KennyBarrera si le quito el `WHERE` deja de fallar, pero por desgracia si necesito el where :/

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos la variable `$us` donde está ? el valor de `emitter`  será fijo? ¿También es una variable ? si es lo segundo le hace falta el `$` , si es cadena también  las comillas simples aunque no sería lo correcto. Sí usa `PDO` **emplee sentencias preparadas.**

Comment: @Dev.Joel acabo de editar mi pregunta

Comment: Si te ha servido mi respuesta, considera marcarla como aceptada, esto con el fin de subir tu reputacion y ayudar con la calidad del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

> Intenta usando consultas preparadas para tu consulta ya que la que
>   tienes es vulnerable a inyeccion sql

El error esta en tu sentencia, `emmiter = emitter` deberías haberle pasado una variable `emmiter = $emitter`

Trata mejor esto:

```
<?php 
    require 'functions.php';
    //use contstantes para añadir un poco de seguridad y evitar posibles modificaciones que algún hacker podría hacer
    DEFINE('HOSTDB',"host=localhost;dbname=empleos");
    DEFINE('UNAME',"root");
    DEFINE('PASS', '');

    $conexion = new PDO(HOSTDB, UNAME, PASS);
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE receiver = :us ORDER BY id ASC";

    $result = $conexion->prepare($stmt); //preparas la consulta
    $result->execute(array(":us"=>$us)); //le pasas parametros y ejectutas

    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) : <-- Aqui tira el error

?>
<!--  -->
<div id="chat_data">
    <span style="color:green"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </span><br>
    <span style="color:brown"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>
    <span style="float:right"><?php echo fecha($row['send']); ?></span><br><hr>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: la cuestion es que no tengo la variable de emitter, ya que esa parte es de la base de datos, es por ello que le puse el ?

Comment: Pues si la pones en la consulta quire decir que de alguna forma la debes obtener, si no entonces modifico mi respuesta para que funcione sin tener emitter. Listo ya la edite.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta apareciendo porque el enunciado de tu consulta esta mal, por eso al ejecutar la función `query()` te esta devolviendo `false` seguramente, y de allí el error "*Call to a member function fetch() on boolean*" que significa que no puedes ejectuar la función `fetch()` sobre un boolean.

Cuando usas objetos `PDO` para manejar tus conexiones y consultas a la base de datos, tienes que parametrizar tus variables de una sola forma, no puedes mezclarlas.

Como tu código no se inclina por una u otra forma de parametrizar, te presento dos opciones. (Solo veremos el código de la consulta, porque la creación de tu objeto `PDO` y tu conexión todo esta bien)

**1. Marcador de posición**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE receiver = ? AND emitter = ? ORDER BY id DESC';  
$run = $conexion->prepare($query);
$run->execute([$us, $emitter]);
```

Puedes notar que primero se tiene que preparar la consulta y sobre la consulta ya preparada se manda a ejecutar. Puedes notar tambien que cuando mandas a ejecutar la consulta, debes mandarle un array con la información que sustituirá los signos de interrogación. El orden del array que mandas con la función `execute` debe ser el mismo orden en que quieres que aparezcan en los signos de interrogación. Despues de este minimo cambio, tu codigo seguirá igual, y no debes tener ningún problema.

**2. Marcador por nombre**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE receiver = :us AND emitter = :emitter ORDER BY id DESC';  
$run = $conexion->prepare($query);
$run->execute(["us" => $us,"emitter" => $emitter]);
```

Esta forma difiere unicamente en que en vez de un signo de interrogación, puedes poner un nombre que identifica a la variable. El comportamiento es el mismo y como puedes ver, en vez de que la funcion `execute` reciba un arreglo simple, recibe un arreglo asociativo, en donde cada nombre que pusiste en tu consulta esta relacionado con una variable. Para este caso, no importa el orden en que este el arreglo asociativo.

Cualquiera de estas dos opciones deberian corregir el error que tienes y podrias correr con toda normalidad tu codigo sin ningún cambio extra. Saludos.