# Crear query sin repetir valor de columnas

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer un query en el cual no se repita un valor ya que este se repite varias veces. en mi base de datos, tengo estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo generar un query para que no se repita el valor de emitter? por ejemplo que no se repita el numero 2?

hasta el momento mi query va quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
function obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us){
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM mensajes WHERE receiver = $us AND emitter = emitter AND seen_empresa = 0 LIMIT 1 ");
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchAll();
}
```

Probe con `DISTINCT` pero no resulto

**SOLUCION**

Gracias a @A.Cedano

```
function obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us){
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
        FROM mensajes WHERE receiver = $us AND seen_empresa = 
        0 GROUP BY emitter ORDER BY id ASC ");
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchAll();
}
```

de esta manera deja de repetirse emitter

Comment: Indica solo cada campo que necesites; por ejemplo si solo colocas *distinct* **emitter, receiver** quedara, pero si hay más que requieres siempre que no varien te servira.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas veras, en mi base de datos tengo 6 valores, pero solo no quiero que se repitan lo que es emitter, mi query quedaria algo como: `SELECT DISTINCT emitter, valor 2, valor 3, 4, 5, 6 FROM tabla etc` es correcto ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción sería usar `GROUP BY`.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT  emitter, reciever 
    FROM tabla_emitter GROUP BY emitter;
```

**Resultado**

```
    emitter    reciever
    1          1
    2          4
    3          7
```

Y si quieres un array de los recievers relacionados con ese emitter. Combinas `GROUP_CONCAT` con `GROUP BY`.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT  emitter, GROUP_CONCAT(reciever SEPARATOR '|') as recivers 
    FROM tabla_emitter GROUP BY emitter;
```

**Resultado**

```
    emitter    recivers
    1          1|2|3
    2          4|5|6
    3          7
```

---

#### [`Ver DEMO`](http://rextester.com/VIKZOW15254)

Comment: Gracias por tu respues! solo que hay un inconveniente, ya que tengo que mostrar todo de la base de datos :/ y de igual manera, el conteo de las filas para poder crear otra funcion.

Comment: olvida mi comentario anterior, eres un genio!!! muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Bueno, eso no es problema, en el `SELECT` agregas las columnas que quieras de la base de datos. Ejemplo: `SELECT  COUNT(*), emitter, unacolumna, otracolumna ...` etc.

Comment: edite la pregunta pero ya con la respuesta, espero esta bien!

Comment: La consulta está bien, pero **no es segura**, ya que veo que estás usando PHP y no usas consultas preparadas. Consiste en pasar la instrucción SQL por un lado y los datos por otro, para evitar de ese modo la Inyección SQL. Sugiero que leas cuando puedas [el apartado III de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81029/29967) para mejorar la seguridad en el manejo de los datos. En cuanto a editar la pregunta con la respuesta no es necesario, para eso existe(n) la(s) respuesta(s) de quienes respondamos a la pregunta.

Comment: Interesante el comando GROUP_CONCAT()   @A.Cedano

Comment: @A.Cedano cambiare mi sql para darle seguridad, gracias por la retroalimentacion :)