# Agrupar campos repetidos de una consulta MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla intermedia (N:M) en MySQL en la que almaceno el `idProfesor` y `idMateria`, al recuperar los datos desde PHP me retorna 5 filas:

```
id | idMateria | idProfesor
---+-----------+-----------
1  | 1         | 1
2  | 2         | 1
3  | 3         | 1
4  | 2         | 2
5  | 3         | 2
```

Lo que quiero saber es cómo mostrar en la vista de PHP solo el id del profesor 1, sus 3 materias que da, después el id del profesor 2 y sus dos materias que da, pero **que el id del profesor solo salga una vez**.

Ejemplo:

```
idProfesor = 1
----------------
idMateria  = 1
idMateria  = 2
idMateria  = 3


idProfesor = 2
------------------
idMateria  = 2
idMateria  = 3
```

Comment: Menuda trabalenguas, pon la estructura de las tablas y las consultas si quieres que te ayudemos. PD: Lo que buscas es GROUP BY

Comment: Puedes usar una combinación de `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP BY`, para obtener solamente el id de cada profesor en una columna y en otra columna, separados por algún caracter especial, la materias. Luego, por programación haces un `split` usando ese separador y tendrás un array con las materias. [Puedes verificar una solución parecida al final de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967).

Comment: En el bucle donde dibujas los `tr` de tu tabla (si es que lo estás haciendo asi), puedes comprobar si en la fila anterior el campo `idProfesor` es igual al actual, en cuyo caso imprimes una celda vacía. Obviamente compruebas que la fila sea mayor a 0 para que no preguntes por el valor de la fila -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No agrupes  en la consulta, básicamente haz un condicional en el while al recorrer las filas en php, ejemplo:

```
$idProfesor = 0;
while ( $result = /* fetch */ ) {
    // Compruebas si es diferente para mostrarlo o no
    if ($idProfesor != $result['idProfesor']) {
        echo $result['idProfesor'];
        // asignas el nuevo id
        $idProfesor = $result['idProfesor'];
    }
    // Muestra las materias
    echo $result['materia'];

    /* RESTO DEL while */
}
```

Comment: Muchas Muchas Gracias, primero que nada por entender mi trabalenguas jajaja en verdad muchas gracias es lo que buscaba hermano, un saludo :D

Comment: @OscarBautista si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).