# Problema en consulta mysql php pdo se repiten los datos

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Compañeros de StackOverFlow, tengo la siguiente duda, estoy tratando de realizar un sistema simple de test o evaluacion en php y cree mi base de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
+----------------+
| Tables_in_game |
+----------------+
| answers        |
| questions      |
+----------------+
```

Tabla de preguntas (Questions)

```
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| question | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type     | varchar(5) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Tabla de respuestas (Answers)

```
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_question | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| answer      | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_right    | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Mi consulta PHP PDO es la siguiente:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=game', 'root', '');
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions LEFT JOIN answers ON (questions.id = answers.id_question) WHERE questions.type = :type');
    $type = "quiz3";
    $stmt->bindParam(':type', $type);
    $stmt->execute();
```

El problema es que al recorrerlo me imprime varias veces la pregunta segun las respuestas que tenga la pregunta:

```
<div class="container">
        <?php foreach ($stmt as $val): ?>
        <p>
            <?= $val['question']; ?>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <?= $val['answer']; ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
```

Lo que necesito es poder imprimir una sola vez la pregunta y poder imprimir todas las posibles respuestas.

A manera de ejemplo muestro como deberia quedar:

> Esta es la pregunta #1............
>
> 1. Respuesta #1
> 2. Respuesta #2
> 3. Respuesta #3
> 4. Respuesta #4

Comment: Aummm puedes hacer dos querys ooooohh.. como sabes que todas las filas te van a dar la pregunta puede colocar una bandera que en la primera vuelta imprima la pregunta y en las demás no.

Comment: Puedes hacer una consulta combinando `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP_BY`, de ese modo te traerá una columna con todas las respuestas y un separador. Luego haces `explode` de esa columna. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967), al final de la respuesta. Imagina que los `emitter` son las preguntas y los `receiver` son las respuestas.

Comment: Aprovecho para comentar que las preguntas se mostraran de manera ramdon, @A.Cedano me podrias dar un ejemplo amigo, no entendi muy bien el tuyo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer una consulta combinando `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP_BY`, de ese modo te traerá una columna con todas las respuestas y un separador. Luego haces explode de esa columna.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    q.id,
    q.question, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.answer SEPARATOR '|') all_answers
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN answers a ON (q.id = a.id_question) 
WHERE q.type = :type
GROUP BY q.id
```

Tendrías un resultado más o menos así:

```
id    question                                    all_answers
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     ¿De qué color es el caballo blanco?         blanco|negro|incoloro
```

### Lectura en PHP

La consulta escrita así te traerá un array parecido a este:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [question] => ¿De qué color es el caballo blanco?
            [all_answers] => blanco|negro|incoloro
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [question] => ¿En qué batalla murió Napoleón?
            [all_answers] => En la última|En Waterloo|En ninguna
        )

)
```

Este sería un ejemplo de código para leer los resultados:

```
foreach ($arrDatos as $row){
    $strHTML="";
    $strHTML="Pregunta ".$row["id"].": ".$row["question"].PHP_EOL;
    $strHTML.="<ul>";
    $a=explode("|",$row["all_answers"]);
    foreach ($a as $v){
        $strHTML.= "<li>$v</li>";
    }
    $strHTML.="</ul><hr />";
    echo $strHTML;
}
```

Dicho código te imprimirá esto:

```html
<p>Pregunta 1: ¿De qué color es el caballo blanco?</p>
<ul>
  <li>blanco</li>
  <li>negro</li>
  <li>incoloro</li>
</ul>
<hr /><p>Pregunta 2: ¿En qué batalla murió Napoleón?</p>
<ul>
  <li>En la última</li>
  <li>En Waterloo</li>
  <li>En ninguna</li>
</ul>
<hr />
```

---

### Más datos en el `GROUP_CONCAT` y orden interno

Puedes agregar más datos en el `GROUP_CONCAT`, y además los podemos ordenar por alguna columna si queremos. Aplicaremos también `COALESCE`, para asegurarnos de que siempre tendremos los datos iguales, ya que si hay algún valor `NULL` en alguna columna nuestro bello código fallará.

Veamos:

```
SELECT 
    q.id,
    q.question, 
    GROUP_CONCAT
       (
         COALESCE(a.id,''),'. '
         COALESCE(a.answer,'')
         SEPARATOR '|'ORDER BY a.id
       ) all_answers    
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN answers a ON (q.id = a.id_question) 
WHERE q.type = :type
GROUP BY q.id
```

Ahora la columna `all_answers` vendrá así:

```
all_answers
-----------------------------------
1. blanco|2. negro|3. incoloro
```

Mejor veamos un ejemplo del array completo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [question] => ¿De qué color es el caballo blanco?
            [all_answers] => 1. blanco|2. negro|3. incoloro
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [question] => ¿En qué batalla murió Napoleón?
            [all_answers] => 4. En la última|5. En Waterloo|6. En ninguna
        )

)
```

Ahora ya tenemos la respuesta con su `id` al lado y un punto. Esta es una manera práctica de traer datos agrupados sin tener que repetir filas.

Si leemos los resultados con el mismo código de más arriba, tendríamos algo así:

```html
<p>Pregunta 1: ¿De qué color es el caballa blanco?</p>
<ul>
  <li>1. blanco</li>
  <li>2. negro</li>
  <li>3. incoloro</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<p>Pregunta 2: ¿En qué batalla murió Napoleón?</p>
<ul>
  <li>4. En la última</li>
  <li>5. En Waterloo</li>
  <li>6. En ninguna</li>
</ul>
<hr />
```

Comment: Una consulta, como podria hacer group_concat  a otras columnas por ejemplo la answers.id?

Comment: Es para hacer esto: <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A.ID" > A.ANSWER<br>

Comment: @ByGroxD, ahora te muestro.

Comment: Vale, si puedes si, si no no hay problema, me idee una solucion y resulto bien, sin embargo si puedes seria bueno ver otra manera de hacerlo.

Comment: Mira cómo quedó ahora @ByGroxD. Recomendaría que escribas la consulta como la he puesto en la última parte, usando `COALESCE` ,de ese modo los resultados tendrán siempre la misma estructura, aunque alguna columna sea `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

USA EN TU CONSULTA sql  UN "list group" este sirve para agrupar segun los datos que no quieres que se repitan

ejemplo "SELECT * FROM nombre de la tabla list group campo de la tabla que no quieres que se repita "

Comment: Hola, al hacer esto evidentemente me arroja un solo resultado, pero tambien me imprime una sola respuesta, no  todas.