# MySQL Dos select en una consulta

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Mi consulta Mysql es la siguiente:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(FCH_ABST) as MES, 
YEAR(FCH_ABST) as ANIO, 
TTL_VNTS AS MQ01 
FROM maquina6_abastos 
WHERE NM_MQ = 111 
AND FCH_ABST BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-30'
```

Lo que me devuelve ésta tabla como resultado:

```
     MES     ANIO    MQ01
   January   2018     80
    March    2018    180
    April    2018     95
```

Ahora quiero agregar una sub consulta para otra columna que se llame MQ02 con el siguiente script:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(FCH_ABST) as MES, 
YEAR(FCH_ABST) as ANIO,
(SELECT TTL_VNTS
FROM maquina6_abastos
WHERE NM_MQ = 111 
) as ventasMes1,
(
SELECT TTL_VNTS
FROM maquina6_abastos
WHERE NM_MQ = 112 
) as ventasMes2 

FROM maquina6_abastos 
WHERE FCH_ABST BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-30'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FCH_ABST,'%m-%Y') 
ORDER BY FCH_ABST
```

La base de datos tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
NM_MQ     TTL_VNTS    FCH_ABST
 110         50      2018-01-01
 110         30      2018-01-15
 110         100     2018-03-01
 110         80      2018-03-15
 110         92      2018-04-15
 111         40      2018-01-01
 111         20      2018-01-15
 111         90      2018-03-01
 111         50      2018-03-15
 111         60      2018-04-15
 112         10      2018-01-01
 112         30      2018-01-15
 112         40      2018-03-01
 112         70      2018-03-15
 112         50      2018-04-15
```

Lo cual me retorna el error #1242 "Subconsulta retorna mas de una línea". 
En realidad espero poder obtener tres columnas llamadas MQ01, MQ02, MQ03 Pero no he podido pasar de este punto. Agradecería cualquier orientación.

Comment: Creo que debes comparar ambas consultas por separado y asegurarte que devuelvan la misma cantidad de registros.

Comment: sin ver datos ni estructura ni nada, es imposible ayudarte. sin embargo el error es claro. La subconsulta tiene que devolver una sola linea, y tu query devuelve mas de una

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer sub-consultas basadas en la misma tabla? ¿Por qué no usas por ejemplo `GROUP_CONCAT` en combinación con `GROUP BY`? [He aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967) de lo que digo.

Comment: muy buena la sugerencia de @A.Cedano seria mucho mejor que pusiera un ejemplo o a su vez un link