# duda con pivote sql

Tags: mysql

cuento con una tabla de papas

```
idpapapa| nombrepapa| 
0001    |  fernando |
0002    |    otro papa|
```

y una de alumnos donde con la siguiente info

```
idhijo| id papa | nombre hijo
1    |     0001  |  rebeca
2    |    0001   |  ruben
```

como puedo hacer un query que me acomode las columas de la siguiente manera

```
idpapa  |   nombre papa|  hijo 1 |hijo 2 
0001   |   fernando    |rebeca   | ruben
```

por lo que he encontrado se puede con pivote, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Hola, podrían darse casos en que un padre tiene mas de 2 hijos o no tenga ninguno, ¿no seria mejor una columna que diga **hijos** y que se acomoden los nombres de lo hijos con algún separador?

Comment: Como dice @the-breaker, es mejor traer a todos los hijos en una misma columna con un separador y luego por programación mostrarlos con el formato que quieras. Eso sería muy fácil con `GROUP_CONCAT` y evitaría que, en el caso de querer consultar varios padres te traiga una tabla alocada con columnas dispares en cada fila. Si quieres [puedes consultar este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967)  donde he explicado también cómo tratar los resultados de la columna por programación. Se habla también de cómo ordenar los datos, etc.