# ¿Cómo puedo evitar mostrar el titulo de una categoría cuando no exista contenido en la misma?

Tags: php, mysqli

He agregado una ordenación de noticias por sus categorías, donde cada noticia nueva que se encuentra en la tabla `one_more_news` se le añade el `id` de la tabla `category`

La cual se visualiza todos los títulos de las nuevas noticias con sus respectiva categoría sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 PREMIER LEAGUE
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 1
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2

 CUP AMERICA
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Aquellos resultados los ejecuta la siguiente consulta:

```
   $stmtcategory = $con->prepare("SELECT id_category,title_category FROM category WHERE active=?");
   $stmtcategory->bind_param("i",$active);
   $active = "1";
   $stmtcategory->execute();
   $stmtcategory->store_result();

   if ($stmtcategory->num_rows>0) {
    $stmtcategory->bind_result($id_category, $title_category);
    while ($stmtcategory->fetch()) {
      echo '<div class="date-text">
              <h4>'.$title_category.'</h4>
              <ul>';

      $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_one_more_news,cover_page,title,description,detail,url,date_post FROM one_more_news WHERE id_category=? order by id_one_more_news ASC LIMIT 2");
      $stmt->bind_param("i",$id_category);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();

      if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id_one_more_news, $cover_page, $title, $description, $detail, $url, $date_post);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

          echo '<li>'.$title.'</li>';

        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
      } else {
        //echo "<span>No existe noticias nuevas</span>";
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo "No existe noticias nuevas";
  }
```

Mi pequeño problema en el código de la consulta, es que cuando no existe contenido para una categoría, el titulo de aquella categoría se muestra, dando como resultado lo siguiente:

```
 PREMIER LEAGUE
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 1
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2

 CUP AMERICA
```

Me pueden explicar, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el titulo de la categoría no aparezca, cuando no tenga noticia vinculada de la misma categoría?

---

## Información Adicional

Tabla `category`

```
id_category   title_category    active
   1          PREMIER LEAGUE      1
   2          CUP AMERICA         1
```

Tabla `one_more_news`

```
id_one_more_news ..... title   .........  id_category   active
      1                ....                    1          1
      2                ...                     1          1
```

Comment: podrias hacerlo con una condicion y dentro de la condicion puedes colocar algo como:
`if(isset($titulo))`
el cual diria que si el titulo exite, entonces dentro de ese condicional haces el echo del contenido

Comment: @AsdrubalHernandez El titulo de la categoría siempre va existir, lo que yo deseo es no mostrar el titulo de la categoría solo cuando no exista noticia vinculado ha aquella categoría

Comment: ¿Tus tablas están relacionadas por alguna columna? Si no es así te convendría relacionarlas, así tienes dos ventajas: la primera es que obtienes toda la información mediante una sola consulta; la segunda es que usando `INNER JOIN` no te traerá datos que no existan en el contenido relacionado.

Comment: Correcto, si escribes la consulta así:  `SELECT * FROM category c INNER JOIN one_more_news n ON c.id_category = n.id_category` te traerá solamente cuando haya `id_category` coincidentes en ambas tablas. Nótese que puedes refinar tu consulta, según tu necesidad... o sea, agregarle algún `WHERE` o un `GROUP_CONCAT  ... GROUP BY` si quieres todas las `one_more_news` relacionadas, etc.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano he añadido información adicional sobre las estructuras de las tablas de la base de datos, yo cuento con dos tablas para ello una denominada `category` y otra llamada `one_more_news` no se en que sentido estén relacionadas, lo que si es cierto, es que yo tomo es el id, de la tabla `category` y ese id, lo añado en la columna de la tabla `one_more_news`, espero la información adicional ayude.

Comment: @A.Cedano Solo debo modificar la primera consulta, sobre las categorías.

Comment: Es que no necesitas dos consultas, con una sola puedes obtener todo lo que necesitas. [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967),  es un caso muy similar al tuyo. Supongamos que las preguntas son las categorías y las respuestas son las one_more_news. Observa cómo se obtiene todo  mediante una sola consulta y luego por código se da formato a la información. Se trae en una sola columna, con un separador, las respuestas (que serían las  one_more_news tuyas) y luego con `explode`  de presentan como dependientes de cada pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Puedes ayudarme por favor, cuando tengas tiempo con el planteamiento del código, no se manejar muy bien la combinación de tablas en una sola consulta.

Comment: Mañana podría echarte una mano, ahora mismo no es posible para mi, dado que tendría que revisar tu código y adaptarlo al problema. No es tan complicado pero se requiere un poquito de tiempo para escribir una respuesta que sea clara. Pero si te fijas, el planteamiento es el mismo de la respuesta que te indico más arriba. Lo más delicado es saber leer la columna que viene con el separador, lo cual también explico allí. Bueno, mañana puedo escribirte una respuesta si es preciso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias amigo, a lo que puedas, buen día.

Comment: Hoy puedo proponerte una solución a este problema, pero tengo una duda sobre la columna `active` que aparece en ambas tablas. ¿Cuál es el sentido de esa columna y por qué está repetida en las dos tablas?

Comment: @A.Cedano el active es para poder mostrar o no aquella categoría para no eliminar ese dato y luego volver a registrar nuevamente esa  categoría  por por decir, y la otra funciona igual se puede escribir por ejemplo una notica pero si no queremos que se muestre todavía se agrega el valor 0. No sé si sea el mejor método correcto amigo, pero la iniciativa en un asunto así me parece lógico creo yo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eduardo lo prometido es deuda.

Aquí te dejo una propuesta de código basada en lo que se ha dicho en comentarios. La consulta ejecutada saca provecho del concepto de bases de datos relacionales, obteniendo datos de varias tablas mediante índices que sirven para relacionar los datos contenidos en ellas. Eso nos evitará tener que enviar dos consultas a la base de datos. Y evitará el problema original que tienes de datos repetidos.

> **NOTA DE EDICIÓN:** Debido a que indicabas que hacía falta también la url para construir un enlace, la consulta ha sido modificada para que
>   arroje los datos así más o menos:
>
> ```
>         [title_category] => PREMIER LEAGUE
>         [data] => News 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news1|
>                   News 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news2|
>                   News 5: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news5
> ```
>
> Los datos vienen agrupados en una clave `data` con dos separadores. El
>   primer separador `|` separa cada subtítulo, y el separador `≠` separa
>   el texto del subtítulo y la url. De ese modo trabajaremos los
>   resultados por código para mostrar el contenido organizado. Se usan
>   unos operadores ternarios para verificar que realmente hay una url y
>   un título, si no hay url no se presentará el link por supuesto, y si
>   no hay texto del título se presentará en el enlace la palabra `No data`... esto lo puedes cambiar, claro está.

Como antes, el código pone cada información dentro de su respectivo `<li>`.

He implementando un control para cuando los datos vengan vacíos.

<s>Aunque no veo que uses todas las columnas del `SELECT` las he puesto todas (así puedes ver con más amplitud como funciona `GROUP_CONCAT`). Si no las vas a usar las quitas y listo. Al final he quitado las columnas que no se usaban por razones de simplicidad, debido a que quise crear una prueba de concepto en `phpfiddle`. Si hubieran más columnas, vendrían igual que `title`, con cada valor separado por `|`.</s>

Ahí va el código actualizado, con los controles también sobre la conexión y sobre la preparación del statement. Si falla me lo dices y si no entiendes algo, pregunta en comentarios. Espero te sea de ayuda. Lo he probado en el nuevo fiddle (enlace actualizado al final)  y me funciona perfectamente.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);
if ($con){
    $strSQL="SELECT 
                 c.title_category,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(n.title,''),'≠',COALESCE(n.url,'') SEPARATOR '|') data
             FROM category_20180712 c 
                 INNER JOIN one_more_news_20180712 n ON c.id_category=n.id_category
             WHERE c.active=?
             GROUP BY c.id_category"; 
    if($stmtcategory = $con->prepare($strSQL)){
        $stmtcategory->bind_param("i",$active);
        $active = "1";
        $stmtcategory->execute();
        $stmtcategory->store_result();
        $strHTML='<div class="date-text">';
        if ($stmtcategory->num_rows>0) {
            $stmtcategory->bind_result($title_category, $data);
            $arrResult=array();
            while ($stmtcategory->fetch()) {
                $arrResult[]=array("title_category"=>$title_category, "data"=>$data);
            }
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($arrResult);
            foreach ($arrResult as $row){
                $strHTML.="<h4>".$row["title_category"]."</h4>";
                $strHTML.="<ul>";
                $arrTitleNews=explode("|",$row["data"]);
                if(count(array_filter($arrTitleNews)) == 0){
                    $strHTML.="<li><span>No existe noticias nuevas</span></li>";
                }else{
                    foreach ($arrTitleNews as $theData){
                        $arrTitleParts=explode("≠",$theData);
                        $partOne=($arrTitleParts[0]) ? $arrTitleParts[0] : "No data";
                        $theTitle=($arrTitleParts[1]) ? '<li><a href="http://'.$arrTitleParts[1].'">'.$partOne.'</a></li>' : "";
                        $strHTML.=$theTitle;       
                    }
                }
                $strHTML.="</ul>";                  
            }       
        } else {
            $strHTML.="<ul>";  
            $strHTML.="<span>No existen noticias nuevas</span>";
            $strHTML.="</ul>";  
        }
        $strHTML.="</div>";
        $stmtcategory->close();
    }else{
        $strHTML="Ocurrió un error en la consulta";
    }
    $con->close();
}else{
    $strHTML="Error, la conexión es nula";
}  
echo $strHTML;
?>
```

---

#### Prueba de concepto

Aquí puedes ver una prueba basada en datos reales: <kbd>**[VER DEMO EN PHPFIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/sn5h-9ehu)**</kbd> (pulsar **`Run - F9`** para ver el resultado).

La consulta trae ahora los datos así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title_category] => PREMIER LEAGUE
            [data] => News 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news1|News 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news2|News 5: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title_category] => CUP AMERICA
            [data] => News 3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news3|News 4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news4|News 6: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news6
        )

)
```

Y la lectura que hacemos dentro del `foreach` nos permite obtener un resultado como este:

```html
<div class="date-text">
  <h4>PREMIER LEAGUE</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/news1">News 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/news2">News 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/news5">News 5: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h4>CUP AMERICA</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/news3">News 3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/news4">News 4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/news6">News 6: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80177/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-puedo-evitar-mostrar-el-titulo-de-una-ca).

Comment: @Eduardo he actualizado el código, cambiando la forma de concatenar la información de modo que la construcción de los `<li>` se pueda hacer con mayor facilidad. Revísalo cuando puedas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Amigo la variable `$data` que se encuentra en `bind_result($title_category, $data);` y demás parte debo reemplazarlo por la variable `$url` que en mi caso es la url de lo contenidos?

Comment: @Eduardo puedes dejarla tal cual. Es sólo una variable que uso para obtener los datos, los cuales ya no se recuperan como columnas separadas. Lo que se hace ahora es recuperar tanto el título como la url en una sola columna (por eso la he llamado `$data` para que sea más descriptivo). Si te fijas en el var_dump podrás ver algo como esto: `[data] => News 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news1|News 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news2|News 5: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet≠www.example.com/news5` o sea, una sola columna que luego trabajamos por código p/ mostrar los `<li>`

Comment: @A.Cedano Comprendo amigo, funciona muy bien, aunque no debería aparecer el titulo de la categoría si no existen datos en la columna url, porque al no tener registro de una url, no aparece el texto, pero sí el titulo de la categoría.

Comment: @Eduardo no entendí bien lo que quisiste decir en el último comentario...

Comment: @A.Cedano Me olvidaba sobre esto *no entendí bien lo que quisiste decir en el último comentario* Era sobre esto, yo se que esto nunca sucederá, porque nunca se dejaran datos vacíos en un registro, pero he llenado todos los datos excepto el titulo y la url, [si puedes observar al final](http://futbolworldcup.com/) de la página en **More news** la categoría aparece `PREMIER LEAGUE`

Comment: @Eduardo sigo sin lograr entender . Quizá convendría que lo plantees en una nueva pregunta si se trata de una situación nueva surgida a raíz de haber resuelto esta pregunta ¿?