# ¿ Como agrupar registros de a partir un registro padre?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo en cuanto al listado de paginas para poder agregar permisos a dicho usuario, pero tengo algunas inconveniencias con respecto al listado.

- Lo que quiero hacer es listar las paginas de acuerdo al registro padre y que se separen por un espacio.

Aquí tengo la base de datos como esta estructurado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que quiero es mostrar en la web de la siguiente forma, esto como un ejemplo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde Node #1, Node #2,.... deben ser los menús principales y así sucesivamente de acuerdo al los registros que se encuentran.

Hay forma de hacerlos ?

Comment: que haz intentado? por favor lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Trate de mostrar los registros agrupando por los parent pero no lo logre

Comment: sin importar si te quedó tu query o no añade el código que haz tratado de ahí se puede partir para apoyarte

Comment: Puedes hacer esto mediante una combinación de `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP BY`. Recuerdo que hay al menos dos casos parecidos al tuyo que fueron resueltos de este modo: [1er caso, en el que se trataba de mostrar unas categorías y un sub-listado de noticias relacionadas con esa categoría](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/178844/29967)  y luego un [2do caso en el que se trataba de preguntas y un sub-listado de las posibles respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967). El primer caso es más detallado, se explica cómo leer los resultados, cómo controlar los nulos y hay una prueba de concepto.