# ¿Como comparar campo de un registro actual con el siguiente, con el objetivo de de saber si está repetido o no?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente query:

```
SELECT pa.codigo,
   @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS nro
FROM presupuestosa pa , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE pa.obra=18
AND pa.empresa=1 ORDER BY codigo ASC
```

Deseo que por cada campo código repetido, pueda guardar el valor 1 en rownum y en caso contrario rownonum tenga valor 0, de tal forma me sirva esos valores como undicadores. Es decir un ejemplo así debería arrojar como resultado:

```
|Codigo |nro  |

|3      |   0 |
|5      |   1 |
|5      |   1 |
|7      |   0 |
|8      |   0 |
|9      |   0 |
|11     |   1 |
|11     |   1 |
|12     |   0 |
```

HE tratado de utilizar la sentencia case tratando de comparar la fila actual del código con la siguiente, pero no se cómo hacerlo, si alguien tiene alguna idea, se lo agradecería

Comment: ponga su codigo de las sentencias case que has usado, ya que asi es la forma mas optima de comparar ese tipo de valores

Comment: y eso es necesario desde la consulta ? o bien puedes traer los resultado y luego comparalos, seria otra posible solucion

Comment: Quizá te puede interesar algo como esto: `SELECT
    p.codigo,  COUNT(*) total
FROM
    presupuestosa p WHERE p.obra=18
AND p.empresa=1 GROUP BY
    p.codigo, p.obra, p.empresa;` Lo que hará la consulta será: mostrar una primera columna que es `codigo` y una segunda columna que es `total`, indicando las veces que ese código está repetido. No es exactamente lo que quieres, pero quizá sea más práctico. Con esta opción puedes hacer uso de `GROUP_CONCAT` por ejemplo si quieres mostrar otros campos de cada repetido.

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpame la pregunta, pero hasta donde sabaia COUNT(*) contaba todos los registros que trae la consulta, indiferentemente de que sean iguales o no, o Bueno, eso es lo que tenia entendido :O

Comment: va mejor una subquery para agrupar y contar y devolver en un join 0 o 1 si hay mas de 1

Comment: @srJJ no, aquí la clave es el `GROUP BY`. Al usar `COUNT` combinado con `GROUP BY` te contará los registros agrupados por `codigo, obra, empresa`.  Voy a escribir una respuesta con prueba de concepto, para que al menos quede como alternativa.

Comment: @A.Cedano ok, entiendo, disculpe si le molesta, pero hasta donde le entendi al compañero lo que quiere no es que le omita los repetidos, sino, que cuando haya un repetido tambien le traiga un valor de 1 o cero si no esta repetido

Comment: @srJJ no es ninguna molestia, se aprende también de los comentarios de los demás o los comentarios motivan a mejorar nuestras respuestas. Entendí el requerimiento planteado en la pregunta. Yo estoy simplemente ofreciendo una posible solución desde otra perspectiva. Lo he escrito como respuesta porque pienso que puede ser una vía de solución válida (y con ciertas ventajas) para situaciones como estas.

Comment: @A.Cedano aqui se motiva muy bien :XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando un subquey que cuenta los registros agrupados por obra y código, luego un left join para traducir los totales a 0 ó 1.

```
SELECT o.id, o.obra, o.Codigo, IFNULL(n.hayDupes,0) as nro, o.cosa 
FROM Table1 o
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT i.Codigo, COUNT(i.Codigo) AS total, 1 AS hayDupes 
    FROM Table1 i 
    WHERE i.obra = 18
    GROUP BY i.obra, i.codigo 
    HAVING total>1
    ) AS n
  ON n.Codigo = o.Codigo 
WHERE o.obra = 18;
```

hay que repetir el id de obra para que agrupe bien, eso tal vez se pueda mejorar

un fidel: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca674b4/1

**explaineishon**

En la subconsulta se agrupan los registros por obra y código y se cuentan, además se agrega una columna `hayDupes` que siempre vale `1`.

La magia se manifiesta entre `HAVING total>1` que hace que sólo retorne registros duplicados (2 o mas) y la transformación de `hayDupes = NULL` a `0` en la consulta exterior.

Esto es: en la consulta exterior se retorna la columna `nro` con el valor de `hayDupes` que siempre vale `1`, ó si la columna de la subconsulta `hayDupes` no existe (`IFNULL`) retorna `0`.

Debido al `LEFT JOIN` en la consulta exterior sólo se incluyen resultados de la sub consulta que cumplan la condición de tener el mismo `Codigo`.

Finalmente se filtra por id de obra.

Puede que haya una forma mas eficiente usando teoría de grupos para filtrar la intersección, pero no llego a tanto =P (el self join es lo que generalmente se usa en estos casos)

Comment: he aprendido algo nuevo !!

Answer (score 3):

Dado que se trata de un control de duplicados, una posible solución sería una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT
    p.codigo,  
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR '|') ids, 
    COUNT(*) total
FROM
    presupuestosa p 
WHERE p.obra=18 AND p.empresa=1
GROUP BY p.codigo, p.obra, p.empresa;
```

Esta consulta agrupará por `codigo, obra, empresa` y arrojará en la columna `total` la cantidad de registros que haya en cada grupo. La columna `ids` lograda con `GROUP_CONCAT` es un plus, por si te interesa saber por ejemplo cuáles son los id de cada valor repetido, vendrán separados por `|`.

Esto te permitirá unos resultados más simples y fáciles de analizar.

---

### Prueba de concepto

<kbd>[**VER DEMO EN REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/YNEVB84265)</kbd>

Hice una prueba basada en datos reales (no puse todos los registros que muestras, sólo unos pocos por motivos de brevedad) y puse un caso en el que hay tres duplicados, para mostrar que la consulta puede tener un alcance interesante: saber de una vez cuántos duplicados hay...

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS presupuesto_20180729 
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        codigo INT,
        obra INT,
        empresa INT
    )ENGINE=INNODB;

    INSERT INTO presupuesto_20180729 (codigo, obra, empresa) VALUES 
                (1,1,1),
                (2,1,1),
                (3,18,1),
                (5,18,1),
                (5,18,1),
                (5,18,1),
                (7,18,1),
                (11,18,1),
                (11,18,1)
        ;

SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';


SELECT
    p.codigo,  
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR '|') ids, 
    COUNT(*) total
FROM
    presupuesto_20180729 p 
WHERE p.obra=18 AND p.empresa=1
GROUP BY p.codigo, p.obra, p.empresa;
```

**Resultado:**

```
codigo    ids      total
-------------------------
3         3          1
5         4|5|6      3
7         7          1
11        8|9        2
```

Comment: pudieras de favor explicarme ¿cómo es que funciona GROUP CONCAT? no me termina de quedar claro su funcionamiento gracias

Comment: @Alfredo como su nombre lo indica: *agrupa*  (`GROUP`)  y *concatena* (`CONCAT`
) usando el separador que le indiques (o la `,` por defecto). En pocas palabras te muestra en una sola columna todos los valores agrupados por el `GROUP BY`.  Aquí yo le pido el valor de la columna `id` de cada fila que tenga el mismo: `codigo,obra,empresa`, separado por `|`. Por ejemplo, en la 2ª fila del resultado tenemos los valores `4|5|6`... si te fijas en el insert verás que las filas `4,5,6` tiene el código `5` y tiene la obra `18` y la empresa `1`. Lo interesante de `GROUP_CONCAT` es que en 1 sola columna..

Comment: ... puedo presentar otros datos adicionales que necesite y que de otro modo tendría que traerlos repitiendo filas. Por ejemplo, si necesito esos `x` ids, de otro modo tenría que repetir `x` filas para tenerlos, mientras que aquí los tengo todos en una sola fila. Además **puedo traer  más columnas si quisiera...** Ahora te muestro un enlace donde esta práctica es de una utilidad interesante: [por ejemplo en este caso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967)  y aquí tienes [un caso de aplicación para resolver un problema más complejo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/179317/29967).

Comment: gracias @A. Cedano +1 por la explicación extra

Comment: @A.Cedano Maestr :)  ahora comprendo mucho mejor de lo que me hablas, muchas gracias tambien aprendi algo nuevo, pero aun falta que segun el requerimiento, necesita que si esta repetido marque 1 sino un 0, creo que con lo que le hiciste mas un CASE ya puede quedar full

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera aportarte este query te permite saber si el registro esta repetido mas de una oportunidad, por otra parte la palabra `asc` es redundante ya que por defecto se ordena `asc`.

```
select tp.codigo,@rownum+1 AS nro
from(
    SELECT count(1) cantidad,pa.codigo
    FROM presupuestosa pa 
    WHERE pa.obra=18 AND pa.empresa=1 
    Group by pa.codigo
    having count(1)> 1
)tp
    ORDER BY tp.codigo
```

Espero que te sirva.