# ¿Cómo agregar más condiciones y parámetros a una consulta unida mediante INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysqli

He agregado nuevas columnas a mi tabla de noticias `more_news` entre ellas las columnas, `language, type_cover`.

Al `WHERE c.active=?` intente agregar un `AND c.language=?` pero me muestra el siguiente mensaje: *Ocurrió un error en la consulta*

```
$strSQL="SELECT
         c.title_category,
         GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(n.mini_title,''),'≠',COALESCE(n.url,'') SEPARATOR '|') data
         FROM category c 
         INNER JOIN news_more n ON c.id_category=n.id_category
         WHERE c.active=?
         GROUP BY c.id_category
         LIMIT 10";
```

No se si el procedimiento es el adecuado, no se trabajar muy bien con tablas unidas, este procedimiento nace desde la siguiente [respuesta & pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178844/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitar-mostrar-el-titulo-de-una-categor%C3%ADa-cuando-no-exista-contenido).

Les describo las estructura de las tablas:

Tabla: `category`

```
id_category   title_category    active
   1          PREMIER LEAGUE      1
   2          CUP AMERICA         1
```

Tabla: `news_more`

```
id_one_more_news   country region   language   id_category   active
      1                  global        es            1          1
      2                  global        es            1          1
      3                    co          en            1          1
```

Entonces necesito pesarles más condiciones al `WHERE` entre ellas quiero mostrar solo los datos que este en el idioma ingles tomando datos desde la columna `language` -> `en`.

Si más adelante desee aplicar otras condiciones, pueden explicarme cuales son los procesos y cambios a seguir.

Comment: Eduardo, @alanfcm ha explicado en su respuesta la forma correcta de aplicar el filtro `WHERE` con la nueva condición.

Comment: @A.Cedano Es extraño ahora si funciono, que condiciones debe estar las tablas, con atributos `NULL` u otros, porque hice una nueva tabla y funciona pero en la otra tabla no, y tiene los mismos datos.

Comment: Cuando quieres que te una todos los datos poniendo `NULL` cuando no haya coincidencias, entonces debes usar `LEFT JOIN` en lugar de `INNER JOIN`. No sé si es a eso a lo que te refieres.

Comment: @A.Cedano No exactamente pero ya voy a descargar el archivo sql el que no me funciona y el que si me funciona para ver que cambios tienen ambos que hace que no funcione el anterior, por los mismos datos están, bueno gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el ejemplo que pusiste, si quieres agregar otro parametro lo harias asi:

```
$strSQL="SELECT 
             c.title_category,
             GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(n.title,''),'≠',COALESCE(n.url,'') SEPARATOR '|') data
         FROM category_20180712 c 
             INNER JOIN one_more_news_20180712 n ON c.id_category=n.id_category
         WHERE c.active=? AND c.language=?
         GROUP BY c.id_category"; 
if($stmtcategory = $con->prepare($strSQL)){
    $stmtcategory->bind_param("is",$active,$language);
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm anteriormente este mismo proceso no me funciono, pero ahora hice una nueva tabla con los mismos datos y si funciona no comprendo que pudo suceder.