# PHP como agrupar este array por ID

Tags: php, mysql, array, php7

tengo una **consulta**:

```
require_once '../conexion.php';

$sql = "SELECT 
-- etiquetas_en_mensajes.id AS 'EM_id',
-- etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje AS 'EM_id_mensaje',
-- etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta AS 'EM_id_etiqueta',
 mensajes.id AS 'mensaje_id',
 mensajes.titulo AS 'mensaje_titulo',
 mensajes.contenido AS 'mensaje_contenido',
 mensajes.createAt AS 'mensaje_createAt',
 mensajes.creador AS 'mensaje_creador',
 mensajes.url_img AS 'mensaje_url_img',
 etiquetas.id AS 'etiqueta_id',
 etiquetas.nombre AS 'etiqueta_nombre'
FROM 
etiquetas_en_mensajes, 
mensajes,
etiquetas
WHERE 
etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje = mensajes.id 
AND 
etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta = etiquetas.id 



ORDER BY 
mensajes.id;

";

$mensajes = [];

$c = new Conexion();

$conexion = $c->conectar();

$result = $conexion->query($sql);

$mensajes = $result->fetch_array();


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo $row[0]. "<br>";
            echo $row[1]. "<br>";
            echo $row[2]. "<br>";
            echo $row[3]. "<br>";
            echo $row[4]. "<br>";
            echo $row[5]. "<br>";
            echo $row[6]. "<br>";
            echo $row[7]. "<br>";
            echo "------------------ <br>";
        }
```

Lo que me displayea lo siguiente :

```
ID MENSAJE = 140
TITULO MENSAJE = titulo mensaje 1
MENSAJE CONTENIDO = contenido mensaje 1
MENSAJE CREATEAT 2019-04-25 20:27:59
MENSAJE CREADOR = 1
MENSAJE URL IMG = 5cc1fc2f3462c0.37633589.png
ETIQUETA ID = 89
ETIQUETA NOMBRE = comun
------------------
ID MENSAJE = 141
TITULO MENSAJE = titulo mensaje 2
MENSAJE CONTENIDO = contenido mensaje 2
MENSAJE CREATEAT 2019-04-25 20:29:15
MENSAJE CREADOR = 1
MENSAJE URL IMG = 5cc1fc7ba0c713.37620569.png
ETIQUETA ID = 91
ETIQUETA NOMBRE = etiqueta_mensaje_dos
------------------
ID MENSAJE = 141
TITULO MENSAJE = titulo mensaje 2
MENSAJE CONTENIDO = contenido mensaje 2
MENSAJE CREATEAT 2019-04-25 20:29:15
MENSAJE CREADOR = 1
MENSAJE URL IMG = 5cc1fc7ba0c713.37620569.png
ETIQUETA ID = 89
ETIQUETA NOMBRE = comun
------------------
```

Todo perfecto, pero estoy intentando agruparlo por el **ID del mensaje** porque si os fijais cada **mensaje** tiene **varias etiquetas asociadas** y me lo muestra repitiendo varias veces el **id del mensaje**. COmo puedo agruparlo de forma que quede **todas las etiquetas asociadas** a una  **unica repeticion** de **mensaje id**

**Aclaracion:** Agrupado  dentro del **array** `mensajes[]`

**Actualizacion**
Estoy diseñando este array para guardar los mensajes, no se si es la mejor forma para implementarlo:

```
$mensajes = array(
    "id" => array(
        "titulo"=>"x",
        "contenido"=>"x",
        "createAt"=>"x",
        "creador"=>"x",
        "url_img"=>"x",
        "etiquetas"=>array(
            "id"=>"x",
            "nombre"=>"x"
        ),


    ),
);
```

Comment: ¿Quieres agruparlos en la visualización?

Comment: Si, imaginate algo como twitter, pero que en cada mensaje tenga abajo las etiquetas asociadas de ese mensaje, como los `#` de twitter. ahora voy a editar la pregunta y voy a añadir un array que estoy probando para ver si es funcional

Comment: Lo podrías hacer editando la consulta SQL, para que agrupe las etiquetas por su ID

Comment: Como dice @AlbertoMartínez, usando [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: He estado probando el `GROUP CONCAT()` pero lo que me hace es agruparlos y ya esta, no me agrupa de forma que diga, este `id_mensaje` tiene tantos `id_etiqueta` asociados . He comprobado a ver si la agrupacion que hacia es correcta, pero no. Me añade etiquetas a mensajes que no estan asociados realmente. Dejo la consulta con la que estoy probando

Comment: `SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(id_etiqueta), id_mensaje FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes;`

Comment: Tienes que poner los `JOIN`  correctos para que `GROUP_CONCAT` haga lo que necesitas: SELECT 
              mensajes.*,
              GROUP_CONCAT(etiquetas.id) AS 'etiquetas_ids',
              GROUP_CONCAT(etiquetas.nombre) AS 'etiquetas_nombres'
         FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes, 
        INNER JOIN mensajes ON mensajes.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje
        INNER JOIN etiquetas ON etiquetas.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta
        ORDER BY mensajes.id

Comment: Lo que pasa es que solo me saca un registro, no itera en la tabla para  hacerlo en todos los `id_mensaje` existentes en mi tabla de relaciones, a eso me refiero. Por cierto gracias por esa consulta

Comment: Perdón, le falta `            GROUP BY mensajes.id`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92898/discussion-between-fly-and-josanangel).

Comment: Como dicen los compañeros, `GROUP_CONCAT` es interesante para este tipo de sepraciones, incluso lo puedes combinar con `COALESCE` por ejemplo para hacer sub-separaciones entre grupos si fuera necesario. [Mira este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/179317/29967), donde se hace una agrupación muy parecida a la tuya. Se crea una agrupación por el separador `|` y dentro de cada una de ellas otro sub-grupo separado por `≠`, en aquel caso se requería crear un link para cada elemento. La clave está en la consulta, que agrupe bien los datos, y en tu modelo de datos por supuesto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agrupar directamente en la consulta, mediante [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) la consulta podría ser:

```
$sql = "
       SELECT 
              mensajes.id AS 'mensaje_id',
              mensajes.titulo AS 'mensaje_titulo',
              mensajes.contenido AS 'mensaje_contenido',
              mensajes.createAt AS 'mensaje_createAt',
              mensajes.creador AS 'mensaje_creador',
              mensajes.url_img AS 'mensaje_url_img',
              GROUP_CONCAT(etiquetas.id SEPARATOR '|' ) AS 'etiquetas_ids',
              GROUP_CONCAT(etiquetas.nombre SEPARATOR '|') AS 'etiquetas_nombres',
              COUNT(DISTINCT etiqueta.id ) as cantidad_etiquetas 
         FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes, 
        INNER JOIN mensajes ON mensajes.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje
        INNER JOIN etiquetas ON etiquetas.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta
        GROUP BY mensajes.id
        ORDER BY mensajes.id
";
```

Después, a la hora de mostrar puedes hacer un array con las etiquetas usando:

```
$etiquetas = explode('|',$row['etiquetas_nombres']);
```

Comment: Añadido `COUNT(DISTINCT etiqueta.id )` para saber la cantidad de etiquetas de cada registro

Comment: no me deja displayearlo para hacer la prueba, estoy usando el mismo bucle de antes y me arroja este **error** : `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Comment: La consulta era errónea, el `GROUP BY` va antes de `ORDER BY` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías almacenar todas las filas en un array

```
$table = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($table, $row);
}
```

y posteriormente ordenar tu array por ID

```
$helper = [];
foreach($table as $k=>$v){
    $helper[$k] = $v['id_mensaje'];
}
array_multisort($helper, SORT_DESC, $table);
```

y por ultimo imprimimos el array

```
foreach($table as $t){
    print_r($t);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero me interesa hacer mejor por consulta para no sobrecargar la pagina. Un saludo