# Sumar valores de un select dentro de un while

Tags: php, mysql

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es ir sumando los valores que se van seleccionando en los select, no se si mi metodo es correcto, pero si se puede solucionar se lo agradeceria, y si es mejor hacerlo de otra forma por favor espero me de una idea de como arreglarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Debes ser más claro en la exposición y además, debes mostrar lo que has intentado y qué error estás teniendo si quieres que te ayudemos. [Aquí hay un caso parecido al tuyo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967), pero debes trabajar tu código. Aquel te puede servir como orientación. En lugar de los `<li>` puedes poner un `checkbox` al lado de cada respuesta y recoger los resultados a través de un botón de validación vía Javascript. Controlando también que no se seleccione más de una respuesta por pregunta.

Comment: amigo cambiastes la preginta, mira... es mas facil que lo haces con un foreach ya que, lo que te esta devolviendo es un array, si quieres comprar que es lo que te esta devolviendo usa esta funcion: `dd($all_pregunta);`

Comment: Cristhian desde el punto de vista de la experiencia de usuario es mucho mejor que pongas todas las preguntas y debajo las posibles respuestas cada una con un checkbox al lado, donde el usuario podrá seleccionar en cada caso la respuesta que crea correcta. Luego mediante algo como un botón podrás validar todo el cuestionario recogiendo las respuestas que fueron marcadas. Colocar cada respuesta en un `select` obliga al usuario a ejecutar `n` acciones suplementarias por cada pregunta. Y si el usuario quiere, al final, hacer una revisión general de su cuestionario, se la hará muy difícil.

Comment: Este tipo de procedimiento es más viable realizarlo con javascript. Más o menos consistiría en crear un método de javascript que mediante una variable global vaya acumulando el puntaje de cada uno de tus select y luego este resultado lo asigne a un campo hidden. Luego la función la vinculas a cada select mediante el evento onchange. Finalmente envías el campo hidden como si se tratase de uno más del formulario y ya.

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberias crear tu formulario en el frontend, lo cual vas a tener varios label que dentro de ellos van a estar ya definidas con las preguntas que estas extrayendo de la consulta de tu DB un ejemplo seria:

```
<label><?php $question->description; ?>"</label>
```

eso seria en la parte del frontend para cada una de tus preguntas, en el lado del backend donde estas gestionando tus **route** tendrias que hacer la consulta sql a la base de datos que te traiga todas las preguntas y luego tendrias que ahcer un return de esa variable a tu vista, quedaria algo asi en tu route:

```
$questions = query("SELECT * FROM questions");
return ['questions' => $questions];
```

Aqui el te va a devolver un array asi que tienes que iterarlo algo asi>

```
<?php foreach($questions as $question):?>
    <label><?php $question->description; ?></label>
    <input type="text"/>
<?php endforeach ?>
```