# Consulta para contar registros en php

Tags: php

tengo un contador que me genera el resultado de la suma total de una consulta pero esta dentro del while no se si eso tenga que ver que ejecuto el programa y me genera en pantalla muchos resultados , no se que problema tiene pero la consulta no es , porque la probé y ya me genera lo que busco en el MySQL pero a la hora de llevarla al código php me genera el error mencionado anteriormente.

```
 $query = "SELECT proveedor.proveedor,proveedor.codproveedor,proveedor.nit,proveedor.contacto, planes.nombre,planes.idplanes,planes.estatus,planes.proveedor_id,proveedor.estatus,
                letras.valores ,letras.planes_id
                FROM planes INNER JOIN proveedor ON proveedor.codproveedor = planes.proveedor_id INNER JOIN letras ON letras.planes_id = planes.idplanes
                WHERE planes.estatus = 1 group by proveedor.proveedor
                LIMIT $desde, $por_pagina";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                while($mostrar_p = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                 ?>
                
                <tbody class="text-center">
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $mostrar_p['idplanes'] ?></td>   
                        <td><?php echo $mostrar_p['proveedor'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $mostrar_p['nombre'] ?></td>
                        <td>No.
                               <?php 
                                    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(letras.valores) as opciones,planes.nombre
FROM planes INNER JOIN proveedor ON proveedor.codproveedor = planes.proveedor_id INNER JOIN letras ON letras.planes_id = planes.idplanes
WHERE planes.estatus = 1 group by proveedor.proveedor";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                                    echo  $fila['total'];
                                    ?>
                        </td>      
                       <td class="text-center">
                          <a href="verproductos.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar_p['codproveedor']
                         ?>" class="edit ml-1" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hay dos consultas en tu código, ¿cuál es la que te da problemas? Precisamente, por qué lanzas dos consultas y no armas una sola con todos los datos que requieres?

Comment: @A.Cedano la segunda consulta que es la que tiene el No. y el count para hacer el contado, como podría realizarlo de una sola consulta?

Comment: Pues trasladando la lógica de la segunda consulta a la primera, creando así una sola. Puedes poner una al lado de la otra en un editor de texto cualquiera y analizar cada una, es relativamente fácil ver el modo de juntarlas. Y si necesitaras ciertos datos agrupados o lo que sea también es posible. La gran ventaja es que ejecutas una sola consulta, no `N` consultas y simplificarás también tu código.

Comment: @A.Cedano y como mostraría el resultado?

Comment: Leyendo la consulta y si hay datos que vienen en sub-grupos leyendo esos sub-grupos en forma de array o de otro modo. Todo depende de la estructura que necesitas construir, en base a eso, organizarías tus resultados del mejor modo para leerlos sin complicaciones.

Comment: y de paso, los dos querys, estan mal! mira por favor [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967). En aquel caso, la parte de `all_answers` sería más o menos lo que estás intentando en tu consulta interior (la segunda consulta). Escribiendo la consulta de otro modo podemos obtener todos los resultados en una sola consulta y luego trabajarlos en PHP. En el ejemplo se agrupan todas las respuestas en una sola columna con un separador y luego se usa `explode` para leerlas/mostrarlas de forma individual. Creo que es un ejemplo claro sobre como traer datos complejos en una sola consulta y luego trabajarlo por código.

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el error.

Comment: Creo que esta en el while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías subir una [tabla](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) con el resultado de la consulta, y por lo menos el código html de la tabla completo.

Hay un error dentro del while, cada vez que itera (o sea por cada fila de la consulta) estás creando un tbody `<tbody class="text-center">`. En cada iteración tenés que crear una fila con sus celdas, pero no el tbody. El tbody debe ir fuera del while, al igual que el thead y el tag table (que no aparecen en tu código).

Tus queries tampoco funcionan, hay columnas en el SELECT que no aparecen en la claúsula GROUP BY. Además podrías juntar ambas en una sola, quedaría algo así, pero no se si es el resultado que buscas:

```
SELECT 
      planes.idplanes,
      planes.nombre,
      proveedor.proveedor,
      proveedor.codproveedor,
      COUNT(letras.valores) as opciones

FROM planes 
INNER JOIN proveedor ON proveedor.codproveedor = planes.proveedor_id 
INNER JOIN letras ON letras.planes_id = planes.idplanes
WHERE planes.estatus = 1 
GROUP BY planes.idplanes,
      planes.nombre,
      proveedor.proveedor,
      proveedor.codproveedor
LIMIT $desde, $por_pagina
```

En el código haces `echo  $fila['total'];` y no hay ningún campo "total" en la query.

El código podría quedar algo así:

```
<tbody class="text-center">

<?php
$query = "SELECT 
      planes.idplanes,
      planes.nombre,
      proveedor.proveedor,
      proveedor.codproveedor,
      COUNT(letras.valores) as opciones

FROM planes 
INNER JOIN proveedor ON proveedor.codproveedor = planes.proveedor_id 
INNER JOIN letras ON letras.planes_id = planes.idplanes
WHERE planes.estatus = 1 
GROUP BY planes.idplanes,
      planes.nombre,
      proveedor.proveedor,
      proveedor.codproveedor
LIMIT $desde, $por_pagina";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                while($mostrar_p = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                 ?>
            
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $mostrar_p['idplanes'] ?></td>   
                        <td><?php echo $mostrar_p['proveedor'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $mostrar_p['nombre'] ?></td>
                        <td>No. <?php echo $mostrar_p['opciones'] ?></td>      
                       <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="verproductos.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar_p['codproveedor']
                         ?>" class="edit ml-1" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>

                </tbody>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era justo lo que necesitaba , el resultado es acertado, muchas gracias hermano!

Comment: De nada! Me alegra haberte ayudado.