# No está funcionando correctamente array_intersect

Tags: php, php7

Tengo los siguientes arrays:

**Array Uno:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["user_name"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(13) "Administrador"
    ["first_surname"]=>
    string(9) "Website"
    ["img"]=>
    string(46) "16176558231bbe3cbe07d8a7de630691fe6a4c10aa.png"
    ["user_status"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["user_name"]=>
    string(5) "usuario"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(11) "Usuario"
    ["first_surname"]=>
    string(3) "Comun"
    ["img"]=>
    string(46) "1617656340d10dc2bf75d49764796e4f3e67fb8a18.png"
    ["user_status"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

**Array Dos:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["user_name"]=>
    string(5) "usuario"
    ["user_friend"]=>
    string(11) "videoEditor"
    ["friendship_status"]=>
    int(1)
    ["friendship_paused"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Cuando intento hacerle un ***array_intersect_key*** me arroja solo el primero y como podéis verlo no coincide ninguna de las keys en el array. He estado leyendo y dicen que pruebe con ***array_intersect_assoc*** pero aún así nada.

Os dejo el código que no creo esté mal, porque ya os digo antes funcionaba y ahora no (Me quedo loco)

```
//  Si hay amistad se añade el metodo para chatear, si no para agregar
if(array_intersect_key($userData, $userFriendship)){
   foreach (array_intersect_key($userData, $userFriendship) as $key => $value) {
       $userData[$key] = array_merge($value, array('method' => 'window.location.assign(\'chat.php?user='. $value["user_name"] . '\')', 'friendship' => true));
   }
}
```

Aquí la función de *array_intersect*

```
var_dump(array_intersect_key($userData, $userFriendship))
```

**Este es el output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["user_name"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(13) "Administrador"
    ["first_surname"]=>
    string(9) "Website"
    ["img"]=>
    string(46) "16176558231bbe3cbe07d8a7de630691fe6a4c10aa.png"
    ["user_status"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

La verdad es que me está dando bastante dolor de cabeza y tampoco tengo mucha experiencia usando esta función. Gracias de antemano :-)

**Edit**

Explicación de lo que quiero hacer: 
Yo hago 2 consultas en la base de datos, obtengo los datos del usuario que quiero buscar y compruebo si existen con el término buscado (lo hago con LIKE). Me los devuelve y todo genial.
Si existe paso a buscar dentro de la base de datos si esas personas están relacionadas entre sí (si tienen amistad) y me devuelve los datos (también lo hago con LIKE) y esas 2 consultas estan bien ejecutadas.
**Quiero aclarar que ambas consultas están hechas con FetchAll**
Lo que quiero hacer es comparar los 2 arrays recibidos, el de los usuarios de la busqueda y que tienen amistad y comparar si por ejemplo:

1. Tanto si son amigos como si no concatenar a la parte correspondiente del usuario el estado de la amistad (true) y un método para javascript.

Me espero esta salida (Si son amigos):

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["user_name"]=>
        string(5) "usuario"
        ["first_name"]=>
        string(13) "Usuario"
        ["first_surname"]=>
        string(9) "Comun"
        ["img"]=>
        string(46) "1617656340d10dc2bf75d49764796e4f3e67fb8a18.png"
        ["friendship_status"]=>
        int(1)
        ["metodo_usuario"]=>
        string(46) "chatUser()"
      }
    }
```

Me espero esta salida (Si NO son amigos):

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["user_name"]=>
        string(5) "usuario"
        ["first_name"]=>
        string(13) "Usuario"
        ["first_surname"]=>
        string(9) "Comun"
        ["img"]=>
        string(46) "1617656340d10dc2bf75d49764796e4f3e67fb8a18.png"
        ["friendship_status"]=>
        int(1)
        ["metodo_usuario"]=>
        string(46) "addUser()"
      }
    }
```

Espero aclararme bien

Comment: Olvidaste explicar qué es lo que quieres lograr ¿?

Comment: Digo que quiero usar array_intersect, este devuelve un array de coincidencias, no creo que habria sido necesario especificar eso.... Pero si, quiero devolver las coincidencias.

Comment: Pues no se entiende la pregunta, y puede que PHP disponga de mejores formas de hacer las cosas por lo que es preciso que quienes van a responder entiendan lo que quieres y que pongas un ejemplo mínimo y verificable de tu código y un ejemplo de la salida que esperas. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Perfecto, disculpa me pongo

Comment: Ahí lo tienes, gracias..

Comment: **No se entiende el problema**.... Aunque leyendo lo de la consulta SQL se podría pensar incluso que esto se podría resolver desde la misma consulta. Sea como sea, lo más importante aquí es que el problema se entienda con claridad y con simplicidad. Por el momento te puedes olvidar de `array_intersec`, eso se verá más adelante, cuando se entienda el problema. Por experiencia muchos usuarios centran su problema en lo que están implementando para resolverlo, a veces esa implementación se convierte en otro problema añadido al problema original por eso insisto en que expliques el problema en sí.

Comment: Pero si lo estoy explicando, lo que quiero es obtener de los dos arrays que devuelven las consultas todos los campos del primero y concatenarle la llave y el valor del campo user_friendship del segundo, no entiendo que explico mal.

Comment: He hecho una ultima modificación y si no lo entiendes no se de verdad en qué me explico mal, me disculpo de veras y si puedes guiarme para poder hacerlo mejor encantado. Un saludo

Comment: Eso no queda tan claro en la pregunta. Aparte de eso, no es una buena práctica traer datos para luego desecharlos. Hay un serio problema de optimización en tu código, por que traes en el fondo datos duplicados. En la pregunta se lee que haces dos consultas. Todo esto podría resolverse **con una sola consulta** y los datos que traes para desecharlos podrían traerse agrupados bajo un solo usuario usando `GROUP_CONCAT` en la instrucción SQL. Como dije antes, aquí el código que estás usando se ha convertido en un problema adicional, pero no es realmente el problema, deberías **optimizar**.

Comment: No tengo los conocimientos necesarios para hacerlo con una sola consulta, soy un estudiante y recien estoy trabajando con SQL, no es un código para producción es para un trabajo de clase básico

Comment: [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967). Si observas la columna `all_answers` , los datos que hay en ella provienen de **varias filas**, y se usa un separador `|` para diferenciarlos, pero se **agrupan varias filas en esa columna**, así evitarías traer los mismos datos varias veces para luego desechar parte de ellos en PHP. Ahora bien, dado que es un ejercicio, a veces hay limitaciones sobre las funciones que debes usar ya eso es cuestión tuya. Sea como sea, debe entenderse con claridad el problema y el contexto para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Para futuras preguntas te recomiendo utilizar var_export en lugar de var_dump (en este caso para mostrar los arreglos), de esta manera nos es mas facil probar el código. Si quieres puedes publicar una nueva pregunta para resolver este mismo problema directamente con queries sql (te sugiero publicar la estructura de las tablas involucradas, así como datos de ejemplo, preferentemente los insert y el resultado deseado; puedes utilizar [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu tienes dos arreglos cuyos valores son otros arreglos (son arreglos multidimensionales), además los arreglos "internos" tienen llaves que no están presentes en el otro arreglo (como "friendship_status", "user_status", etc).

Una solución es hacer una función de comparación, para determinar cuando dos elementos son iguales y cuando no (al comparar los elementos del primer arreglo con el segundo).

Para ello puedes utilizar el método array_uintersect, al cual le pasas la función de comparación, y retornará todos los elementos del primer arreglo que también estan en el segundo arreglo (según dicha función).

Al parecer tu solo quieres comparar el campo "user_name", pero podrías comparar mas campos de ambos arreglos (podrías agregar un arreglo con los campos que quieres comparar y hacer un foreach dentro de la función de comparación).

```
$ai = array_uintersect($a1 , $a2, function($elemento1, $elemento2) {
        $llave = "user_name";

        if(! array_key_exists($llave, $elemento1) || ! array_key_exists($llave, $elemento2)
                || $elemento1[$llave] != $elemento2[$llave]) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
});
```

Con estos datos de ejemplo:

```
$a1 = array ( 0 => array ( 'user_name' => 'admin', 'img' => '16176558231bbe3cbe07d8a7de630691fe6a4c10aa.png', ), 1 => array ( 'user_name' => 'usuario', 'img' => '1617656340d10dc2bf75d49764796e4f3e67fb8a18.png', ));

$a2 = array ( 0 => array ( 'user_name' => 'usuario', 'img' => '1617656340d10dc2bf75d49764796e4f3e67fb8a18.png', 'friendship_paused' => 0, ));
```

Retorna:

```
$ai = array ( 1 => array ( 'user_name' => 'usuario', 'img' => '1617656340d10dc2bf75d49764796e4f3e67fb8a18.png', ));
```

Luego le deberás agregar los campos "metodo_usuario" y "friendship_status" según corresponda.

No conozco tu modelo de datos, pero seguramente podrías hacer lo mismo con una **query sql**, que te retorne la información directamente como la quieres.

Comment: Genial, es lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada @Alex! Me alegra haberte ayudado.