# Consulta multitabla desde php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 3 tablas (usuario - asignatura - nota), y la idea es que mediante un formulario valido el usuario y se carga una tabla con sus notas:

```
tbl_usuario = dni(PK), apellido;
tbl_asignatura = identificador(PK), nombre;
tbl_nota = id_usuario(FK),id_asignatura(FK), nota;
```

Para obtener todas las notas , lo hago con la siguiente consulta:

```
        SELECT u.apellido, u.dni, a.nombre,a.identificador, n.nota 
        FROM usuario u, asignatura a, nota n 
        WHERE u.dni=n.alumno AND a.identificador=n.asignatura
```

Solo necesito obtener el nombre de la asignatura y la nota de un usuario determinado, ya que al validar la idea es que se le muestre sus notas...

```
<table width="50%" align="center">
 <thead> <tr>
    <th class="primera_fila">ASIGNATURA</th>
    <th class="primera_fila">NOTA</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <?php foreach ($link->query('SELECT u.apellido, u.dni, a.nombre,a.identificador, n.nota FROM usuario u, asignatura a, nota n WHERE u.dni=n.alumno AND a.identificador=n.asignatura') as $row){ ?> 
 <tr>
<td><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nota'] ?></td>
<td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Gracias a todos

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la duda?

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema o error? Esto se podría resolver con una sola consulta, usando `GROUP_CONCAT`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967). Observa que en la columna `all_answers` se traen varios valores separados por `|`, esos valores están en varias filas en la tabla y son agrupados y traidos **con una sola consulta**. Imagina que esas son las notas del alumno, así traes todo en una sola consulta y no en  `N` consultas. Puedes anidar los grupos: `alumno>asignatura>notas` o `<alumno>semestre>asignatura>notas` o lo que sea preciso.

Comment: No queda claro claro lo que quieres, realmente!

Comment: Perdón por la confusión pero la duda está en que con la consulta obtengo todas las notas de todos los usuarios, y lo que necesito es solo el de un usuario determinado ya que al validar la sesión corresponde que solo veo su nota y no la del resto...

Comment: Entonces te hace falta un `where`

Comment: El where ya lo estoy utilizando  WHERE u.dni=n.alumno AND a.identificador=n.asignatura  y me muestra todos los usuarios que tienen notas, yo necesito solo el de el usuario que le loguea