# Obtener un array con datos de dos consultas

Tags: php, mysql, array

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un reporte en el que quiero obtener los créditos de una cartera de créditos y en cada crédito necesito saber si tiene cuotas pendientes. No tengo problemas con obtener las consultas sino en como formatear un arreglo para que cada  crédito lleve  la lista de cuotas vencidas. Básicamente como arreglos multidimensionales para pasarlo a la vista.
Les agradecería mucho si me indican una forma optima de hacerlo.

```
public function estadoCuentaPorCartera($idCartera){
$creditosCartera = $this->creditoModel->obtenerCreditosPorCartera($idCartera);
$data = [
    'creditos' =>'',
];

foreach($creditosCartera as $k => $credito){
    $data['creditos'] = $creditosCartera;
    $cuotas = $this->cuotaModel->obtenerCuotasPendientesPorIdCredito($credito->idCredito);
    if(!$cuotas){
        $data['cuotas'] = 'No tiene pagos pendientes';
    } else {
            foreach($cuotas as $key => $cuota){ 
                if(empty($cuota->id)){
                    $data['cuotas'] = 'vacia'; 
                } else {
                    $data['cuotas']= $cuota->id; 
                }
            }  
    }
}
    $this->view('carteras/estadoCuentaPorCartera', $data);
```

}

Comment: Hola, ¿estas usando un **framework** en particular? si es así deberías colocarlo en las etiquetas

Comment: No, solo uso el MVC y paso un array a la vista para luego recorrerlo y pintar los datos

Comment: Perfecto amigo, no hay problemas entonces :D

Comment: A tu pregunta le falta mucha información, ¿no? ¿Cuál es tu modelo de datos? ¿Qué hace el método obtenerCreditosPorCartera()? ¿Y el obtenerCuotasPendientesPorIdCredito()? Por otra parte, tu pregunta debería estar planteada sobre un ejemplo mínimo, ya encajarás la respuesta en el resto de tu programa... Modifícala y será un placer ayudarte

Comment: Bienvenido!!!. Solo comentarte que no se permite saludar ni suplicar. Te recomiendo que te pases por [ask]

Comment: Al parecer, de entrada hay un error de planteamiento: *"No tengo problemas con obtener **las consultas** sino en como formatear un arreglo para que cada crédito lleve la lista de cuotas vencidas".* No tiene sentido en este caso lanzar una consulta cada vez cuando existen funciones de agrupación/agregación que pueden traerte todos los datos que necesites optimizando así el código. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967), donde se resuelve de una forma óptima un problema parecido al tuyo mediante una sola consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Yo formatearía el arreglo de esta manera.

```
$data = [];
foreach($creditosCarteta as $k => $credito){
  $data[$credito->idCredito]['idCredito'] = $credito->idCredito;
  $data[$credito->idCredito]['nombreCredito'] = 'Nombre credito';// $credito->nombre;
  $data[$credito->idCredito]['campox'] = 'Valor x';// $credito->campox
  $cuotas = $this->cuotasModel->obtenerCuotasPendientesPorIdCredito($credito->idCredito);
  if(!$cuotas){
   $data[$credito->idCredito]['cuotas'] = [];
  }else{
   foreach($cuotas as $key => $cuota){
    if (empty($cuota->id)){// no lo veo necesario con el bloque del else me parece suficiente
     $data[$credito->idCredito]['cuotas'][] = 'vacia';
    }else{
     $data[$credito->idCredito]['cuotas'][] = $cuota->id;// o tambien podria ser $data[$credito->idCredito]['cuotas'][] = ['cuotaid' => $cuota->id, 'nombre' => $cuota->nombre];
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Luego en la vista lo recorrería de esta manera.

```
<?php foreach($data as $credito): ?>
 <h2>Id credito: <?= $credito['idCredito'] ?></h2>
 <h3>NOmbre credito: <?= $credito['nombreCredito'] ?></h3>
 <?php if(count($credito['cuotas']) > 0): ?>
   <?php foreach($credito['cuotas'] as $cuota): ?>
     <h5>cuota id: <?= $cuota ?></h5>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php else: ?>
   <h4>No tiene pagos pendientes</h4>
 <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Lo resolví con tu ejemplo. Gracias.