# Duda con tablas dinamicas, php, mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

///ACTUALIZACION DE PREGUNTA///
Doy mas detalles de lo que quiero conseguir ya que no lo estoy logrando y creo tiene más que ver con que no me he explicado bien.

Tengo el desarrollo de un sistema de menú de restaurante para un área de fastfood o foodcourt en el cual tengo que presentar el menú de varios restaurantes de forma digital en pantallas, hasta ahora todo en forma en como alimento la base de datos, como la actualizo y todo su funcionamiento en general, cada cliente va a poder cargar su menú de forma independiente en la misma base de datos que todos los demás, le implemente $_sessions[u_id] para que sea el elemento diferenciador en cada unas de las tablas ya que cuando cada restaurante graba algún elemento de su menú en alguna tabla por ejemplo content_pizza en la columna u_id se guarda el usuario que hizo login además de los datos que el esta cargando por ejemplo:

id|  u_id  |   nombre   |        descripcion       |cost1|cost2|cost3

8 |testuser|pizza veggie|Deliciosa pizza vegetriana|  85 | 130 | 180

No uso el id ya que realmente no tiene una correlación con el orden como se capturan las cosas y como los usuarios van a poder borrar elementos de su menú la numeración que esta en auto_increment pues no tiene una fiabilidad a menos que indexe y pues eso ya es resolver de una manera complicada algo que puede ser resuelto mas fácil.

Por tanto en la gestión de todo el sistema el dato primordial que viene en todos los WHERE es el u_id que filtra todos los resultados que hayan sido cargados o tengan que ver con el usuario  de dicho u_id.

Sea lo dicho tengo varias tablas donde yo prestablecí su estructura para varios tipos de cargas de productos ya sea si tienen 1, 2, 3 precios o se manejen por peso, por eso tengo varias tablas con diferentes estructuras a las cuales llamo siempre filtrando por u_id (la sesion actual)

content_bar

content_pizza

content_pizza2

content_pizza3

content_cat (tabla de la categorías)

Por ejemplo si un cliente carga un producto a su menú los datos que el ingresa son:

id (este se genera solo por el auto_increment)
u_id (este lo tomo de sessions)
Categoría (esto de un select que llamo de otra base que el cliente alimenta)
Nombre (el cliente lo escribe)
Descripción (el cliente lo escribe)
Precio1(el cliente lo escribe)
Precio2(el cliente lo escribe)

Ahora lo que requiero es que se presente la información llamando a todas tablas al mismo tiempo sin importar el usuario o tipo de negocio, consultando el u_id y la categoría por ejemplo si es un bar el cliente solo vende bebidas, pero estas bebidas a lo mejor el creo categorías de ron, brandi, refrescos y otras tantas mas, entonces cargo los datos en la tabla content_bar.
Pero si el cliente es un restaurante más en forma puede ser que el requiera por ejemplo la tabla de bar, general, general2 y categorías que esta ultima es la que en digamos encierra en grupos de correspondencia los productos.

Por tanto mi pregunta es si me pueden ayudar ya que intente de muchas maneras y no puedo hacer funcionar la consulta me da errores varios, estoy generando la consulta en la parte publica la que se vera en las pantallas por una URL fija index.php?u_id=testuser donde obtengo el u_id por un get y no por el session, (probando una consulta simple a las tablas ese no es el problema pues lo consigo prolijamente), he intentado con inner join, group by left join y muchas maneras y nada.

Me podrían ayudar con un ejemplo de como hacer la consulta el resultado esperado es este:

Filtra el u_id=RESTAURANTE 1

cat_name es la tabla donde vienen todas las categorías entonces la consulta debe de ir a cat_name buscar todas las categorías creadas por el u_id=RESTAURANTE 1 y mostrarlas

Después de eso la consulta buscara en todas las tablas declaradas los productos que contengan ese mismo u_id y categoría, mostrara de bajo de cada una de las categorías los productos que cumplan la regla.

En este ejemplo de como esperaría el resultado puede ser que cada categoría contenga productos de varias tablas por eso necesito que haga la consulta a todas las tablas al mismo tiempo y entregue el resultado así.

RESTAURANTE 1

```
Ron
u_id | cat_name (Ron) | Bacardi...
u_id | cat_name (Ron) | Matusalen...
u_id | cat_name (Ron) | Flor de caña...
u_id | cat_name (Ron) | Morgan...

Pizza
u_id | cat_name (Pizza) | Prod1...
u_id | cat_name (Pizza) | Prod2...
u_id | cat_name (Pizza) | Prod3...
u_id | cat_name (Pizza) | Prod4...

Carnes
u_id | cat_name (Carnes) | Prod1 ...
u_id | cat_name (Carnes) | Prod2 ...
u_id | cat_name (Carnes) | Prod3 ...
u_id | cat_name (Carnes) | Prod4 ...

Postres
u_id | cat_name (Postres) | Prod1 ...
u_id | cat_name (Postres) | Prod2 ...
u_id | cat_name (Postres) | Prod3 ...
u_id | cat_name (Postres) | Prod4 ...
```

Comment: Puedes usar `GROUP_CONCAT` combinado con `GROUP BY` para obtener lo que quieres. Pero OJO, los datos se obtienen en una sola fila, con separadores y luego por código PHP los puedes desglosar para mostrarlos como quieres. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967) puedes ver un ejemplo.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano sinceramente no lo consigo, he intentado toda la tarde de ayer con el ejemplo que me mandas, pero no se en que me estoy equivocando o si no me supe explicar y no aplica, voy a detallar mas lo que quiero conseguir a ver si me puedes dar un poco mas de retro

Comment: Leí toda la pregunta editada pero no logro entender cuál es el problema. En vez de tantas explicaciones dinos lo que tienes (cómo tienes diseñadas las tablas) y luego lo que quieres lograr, poniendo en la pregunta la consulta que estás intentando para ello. Parecería que necesitas normalizar más que otra cosa, creando un modelo de datos flexible que se adapte a los distintos requerimientos.