# Seleccionar productos por un valor dentro de la SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito hacer que solo me muestre los ítems que tienen 'heladera' como categoría...

Ya que el código que tengo me muestra todos los ítems de la base de datos y no me funciona como necesito

de la sql dejo solo 4 items para que se entienda lo que intento hacer

---

### SQL

```
INSERT INTO `Productos` (`codigo`, `categoria`, `descripcion`, `marca`, `submarca`, `oem`, `foto`) VALUES

    ('RC65', 'Heladera', 'Heladera chica para camion bivolt', 'Universal', '', '', ''),
    ('RC73', 'Heladera', 'Heladera medina para camion bivolt', 'Universal', '', '', ''),
    ('T011060091', 'Barreros', 'Barrero Randon', 'Randon', '', '', ''),
    ('T22561', 'Barreros', 'Barrero Volkswagen', 'Volkswagen', 'vw', '', '');
```

---

### PHP

```
                <?php foreach($productos as $producto){ ?>          
                    <!-- product -->
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                
                                <?php echo $producto->foto ?>
                                
                                <div class="product-label">
                                
                                    <span class="new">NUEVO</span>
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-body">
                                <p class="product-category"><?php echo $producto->categoria ?></p>
                                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#"><?php echo $producto->descripcion ?></a></h3>
                                <h4 class="product-price">COD: <?php echo $producto->codigo ?></h4>
                                <div class="product-btns">
                                    <button onclick="window.location.href='Categorias/Accesorios/Catracas'" class="quick-view"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="tooltipp">Ir a la categoria</span></button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            <div class="add-to-cart">
                            <!--
                                <button class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>VER</button>
                            
                                <div class="product-rating">
                                    <b style="color: white;">CAPACIDAD: 7.000 KG</b>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /product -->
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Puedes usar por ejemplo un `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT ... FROM ... GROUP_BY`, agrupando por categoría y luego trabajar el código PHP para mostrar cada grupo por separado. [Aqui tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967).

Comment: Lo leí varias veces, pero no logro encontrar la solución a mi problema, a lo que voy es que dentro de "categorias" tengo varias y si yo quiero que salga solo la categoría que contenga como tal la palabra "heladeras" no logra hacerlo

Comment: Realmente tu pregunta no es clara. Si lo que quieres es obtener las categorías que contengan la palabra `heladeras` entonces lo que necesitas es una consulta SQL con `LIKE`, algo así más o menos: `SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE laColumna LIKE '%heladeras%`. Sustituye cada cosa por su nombre real y prueba la consulta directamente en el SGBD.

Comment: Acabo de editar y simplificar lo que necesito realizar,
ya lo intente pero me da error de sintaxis 

SELECT * FROM productos WHERE categoria LIKE '%heladera%

Comment: Perdón, me faltó la comilla al final de la sentencia. Prueba así: **`SELECT * FROM productos WHERE categoria LIKE '%heladera%'`**, es decir, el criterio del LIKE, wildcards incluidos, debe ir entre comillas: `'%heladeras%'`

Comment: Eso no fue el problema, vi el tema de la comilla y se lo agregue, pero simplemente tira error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Productos' (T_STRING)

Comment: ¿Dónde tira el error? Prueba primero la consulta en la base de datos directamente y luego si con ella obtienes los datos que quieres la implementas en PHP.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, no me di cuenta tenia la sentencia mas arriba, simplemente le agregue --- WHERE categoria LIKE '%heladera%'; -----

Comment: `LIKE` tiene muchos usos, para buscar de diferentes formas, según los wildcards que pongas y como los pongas. Aquí al poner un texto entre dos `%` te buscará todo lo que contenga ese texto. Pero, si lo necesitaras, puedes buscar otros tipos de coincidencias. Para más detalles, [revisa el MR de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html). Y, hay una versión aún más poderosa que usa expresiones regulares.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, con eso me di cuenta que realmente ya tenia el `SLECT` puesto mas arriba y que simplemente le faltaba el `WHERE` con sus condiciones, por eso al querer agregarle otro `SELECT` me daba el error