# No puedo obtener todos los valores recorridos con el bucle while

Tags: php

estoy intentando hacer una consulta que me permita obtener los permisos que tienen el/los grupos a los que pertenece un usuario determinado, ya casi lo he conseguido, el problema esta en que despues de recorrer todos los permisos solo se valida el ultimo permiso, es decir, si un usuario tiene los permisos de eliminar,editar,pacientes y grupos de usuarios, solo se valida la condicion con el permiso grupo de usuarios por ser el ultimo permiso que tiene asignado..

Por favor, me gustaria que alguien pudiera ayudarme a ver en que estoy fallando!

```
<?php

include("php/verificarSesion.php");

//$verificarGrupo = " SELECT u.id, u.nombre, u.apellidos, pg.id_personal, pg.id_grupo FROM personal u INNER JOIN personal_grupo pg ON u.id = pg.id_personal WHERE id_personal = '".$id_user."' ";

$verificarGrupo = " SELECT u.id as id_usuario, u.nombre as nombre_usuario, u.apellidos, pg.id_personal, pg.id_grupo, g.id as id_group, g.nombre as nombre_grupo, 

pm.id as id_permissions, pm.nombre as nombre_permisos, ta.id as id_hasasigned, ta.id_grupo, ta.id_permisos FROM personal u

INNER JOIN personal_grupo pg ON u.id = pg.id_personal

INNER JOIN grupo_usuarios g ON pg.id_grupo = g.id

INNER JOIN tiene_asignado ta ON g.id = ta.id_grupo

INNER JOIN permisos pm ON pm.id = ta.id_permisos


WHERE  u.id = $id_user ";
```

**$id_user** es el que almacena el id del usuario al iniciar sesion, se encuentra en la pagina verificarsesion.php que he incluido al principio del codigo

```
$resultadoGrupo = $conexion->query($verificarGrupo);



if ($resultadoGrupo->num_rows > 0) {

    while($filas = $resultadoGrupo->fetch_array()){

    
    $permiso = $filas['nombre_permisos'];
    $nombre = $filas['nombre_usuario'];
    $grupo = $filas['nombre_grupo'];
    

}
```

No he querido incluir el texto de la pagina que debe ver el usuario dentro del **bucle WHILE** porque se repetiria sin parar solo lo he usado para recorrer todos los grupos y permisos que tiene asignado el usuario

```
            if ( $permiso == 'pacientes') { ?>


                // Aqui iria el codigo de la pagina que puede ver el usuario

                  <h2>Listado de pacientes</h2>
                <p>Aquí puede consultar la lista de los pacientes registrados en el sistema</p>

                

    <?php       } else { //FIN DE if($permiso=='pacientes') 


        echo "No tiene acceso a esta pagina";

        ?>
                

                
        <?php   }?>
            
        
    <?php       } else { //Fin del primer if


        echo "NADA";

        ?>
                

                
        <?php   };?>
```

Comment: En el `while` asignas tres variables, pero al final cada una se quedará con el valor del último elemento que haya en el bucle. No se entiende con claridad qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente. Si quieres todos los elementos, muéstralos desde dentro del bucle o recógeles en un array o concaténalos.

Comment: Tratando de comprender la lógica de tu programa, parecería que sólo te interesa saber si el permiso es igual a `pacientes`¿? Si es así, pon ese filtro en la consulta SQL, de modo que no traigas datos innecesarios. De ese modo, podrás  mostrar todos los registros que traiga la consulta desde dentro del `while`

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola, cada usuario puede pertenecer a uno o a varios grupos los cuales tienen asignados a su vez varios permisos. Lo que quiero conseguir son los grupos a los que pertenece el usuario y los permisos que tienen asignados estos grupos, en caso de que el nombre de uno de los permisos sea **pacientes,** que le permita ver la interfaz de la pagina de pacientes. No se si me explico

Comment: @A.Cedano Precisamente lo que quiero evitar es que las tres variables que he asignado dentro del bucle se queden con el ultimo valor, necesito que cada variable me almacene todos los valores, por ejemplo, que la variable $permiso me almacene todos los permisos

Comment: Como te dije, las variables se sobre-escriben en el bucle, por tanto, necesitas irlas guardando en un array o algo así. De todos modos, esto lo puedes resolver a nivel de consulta SQL, trayendo los datos agrupados, es decir, cada usuario agrupado con sus permisos, así al leer el usuario verificas qué permisos tiene pero para eso tienes que modificar tu instrucción SQL, usando `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP BY`

Comment: [Mira aquí un ejemplo de lo que digo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967). En ese ejemplo son preguntas que vienen asociadas a sus respuestas, imagina lo mismo en tu contexto: cada usuario con sus permisos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user, como dice Cedano... quizá el `$nombre` y `$grupo` coincidan para todas las filas, pero los permisos los deberías tratar como un array. Si todo lo demás funciona (la consulta está bien realizada, tiene los resultados correctos con una fila para cada permiso del usuario, etc.) puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
while($filas = $resultadoGrupo->fetch_array()){
    $permisos[] = $filas['nombre_permisos'];
}
$nombre = $filas['nombre_usuario'];
$grupo = $filas['nombre_grupo'];
```

Al salir de ahí, se entiende que tendrías en `$permisos` un array con todos los que corresponden a ese usuario. Y luego, en el otro tramo de código...

```
if (in_array('pacientes',$permisos)) { ?>
    // Aqui iria el codigo de la pagina que puede ver el usuario
    [...]
```

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado!!!