# Duda sobre diseño de tablas relacionadas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

haber diseñe la siguiente estructura de tablas en una BD para una clinica:

```
persona(id,nombre,apellidos)
persona_documento(id,id_persona,id_tipo_documento,numero_doc)
tipo_doc(id,detalle_tipo_doc)
ingreso(id,fecha_atencion,id_persona)
comprobante(id,fecha_comprobante,id_persona,serie_comp,numero_comp)
```

Estará bien la estructura?

con ello tendre la siguiente información:

```
persona(1,juan,perez)
tipo_doc(1,RUT)
tipo_doc(2,PASAPORTE)
persona_documento(1,1,1,12345677)
persona_documento(2,1,2,88888888)
```

ahora supongamos que realizo un registro en la tabla ingreso, ya se registrara el ID de la persona, hasta ahí todo correcto, ahora que pasaria si la persona registrada tiene 2 tipos de documentos(rut y pasaporte), y al momento de hacer la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT * from ingreso
INNER JOIN catalogo.personaon on persona.id_persona=persona.id
INNER JOIN catalogo.persona_documento on persona_documento.id_persona=persona.id
where ingreso.id=1
```

me retornara un error por que en persona_documento existe 2 documentos.

ahora la posible solución seria que en la tabla ingreso quede de la siguiente manera

```
ingreso(id,fecha_ingreso,id_persona,TIPO_DOC_PER)
```

Pero seria algo tedioso, imaginando que tengo 20 tablas en mi DB donde referencie a la persona, tendría que agregar ese campo en esas 20 tablas, seria id_persona y id_doc.

Sera una buena practica como planteo al inicio?, alguna idea amigos, para hacer de otra manera.

Comment: El planteamiento es bastante claro al principio, pero al final me perdí. ¿Cuál es la función de la tabla `ingreso`? ¿No sé lo que quieres decir con lo de las 20 tablas? ¿Los ingresos están ligados a la persona o al tipo de documento de la persona? No sé entiende cuál es la finalidad de la consulta que pones de ejemplo...

Comment: Hola #A. Cedano, gracias por responder, haber suponiendo que es una DB de una clinica, la tabla seria esto INGRESO(id, fecha_atencion,id_persona), ahora lo de las 20 tablas es algo que podría tener en mi BD, por ejemplo COMPROBANTE(id,id_persona,numero_comp,serie_compro), te das cuenta siempre voy a reutilizar a la tabla persona, ya sea para seleccionar clientes, pacientes, etc. no se si sea una buena practica, para no registrar los datos de la persona en cada tabla que necesite datos de personas.

Comment: Es una práctica correcta referenciar a las personas por su id en la única tabla `persona`... así tengas 20 ó 1000 tablas, según las necesidades de tu diseño. Generalmente ayuda pensar las tablas como entidades bien diferenciadas que representan algo único. Por ejemplo: `persona` es una entidad, `ciudad` es una entidad, `pais` es otra entidad. Cada una de ellas sería una tabla en la BD y a su vez puede usar referencias de otra(s) tabla(s) y referencias escalonadas. Por ejemplo, para saber en que país nació una persona, sólo necesitarías un `id_ciudad` en la tabla `persona`.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, si de hecho así lo tengo mis demás entidades, pero el pequeño detalle es como explico, suponiendo que la persona JUAN PEREZ tiene 2 tipos de documentos registrados, al momento de hacer el join a persona me retornará los 2 N° documentos y obviamente me retornara error y para evitar ello, lo tendría que agregar un campo tipo_doc_persona a la entidad INGRESO? y asi sucesivamente en las demás donde utilice a la entidad persona.

Comment: Es que creo que te estás liando con eso del tipo de documento. Te lo preguntaba más arriba pero no me has respondido: **¿con quién tiene que relacionarse la tabla `ingreso`**?, si es con `persona` no veo para qué necesitas el tipo de documento (hablando de la tabla `ingreso`)? ¿O es que en `ingreso` **debe constar el tipo de documento que se usó para registrar el ingreso o algo así**?

Comment: Haber la entidad **ingreso** se debe relacionar con **persona**, lo hablo del tipo_doc en la entidad **ingreso** por que suponiendo que deseo obtener listado de pacientes con la siguiente estructura(RUT, 12345678, JUAN,16/2/2018, etc.) pero que sucederia si la persona JUAN tiene registrado mas de 1 doc. y cuando realice el join a la entidad **persona** encontrara 2 registros  por lo cual me retornara error, a ello me refiero, como que siempre voy a necesitar mostrar el tipo de documento de la persona para mostrar los listados de personas.

Comment: No. En ese caso, si quieres el `RUT` por ejemplo, le puedes poner un `WHERE tipo_doc.id=1` en la consulta, de ese modo, te filtrará sólo usando el `RUT`.  O en el `SELECT` puedes poner un condicional, diciendo que si no tiene `RUT` te dé el pasaporte o viceversa. O puedes implementar un `GROUP_CONCAT` con un separador para que te de en una sola columna los números de documento y su tipo si fuera necesario, en ese caso tendrías que agrupar por el id de `persona`
. Es decir, hay varias maneras de resolver esto obteniendo una sola fila por cada persona.

Comment: [Mira este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967). Si observas el último resultado, imagina que `emitter` es el id de cada persona, y en la columna `recivers` tienes esto: `1|2|3` realmente esos números son tres filas de una tabla que se presentan en una sola fila/columna con un separador. O sea, como si el `1` fuera el `RUT`, el `2` fuera el `pasaporte` y el `3` fuera el `DNI`. Eso se hace con `GROUP_CONCAT`... [Este es otro ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967) con **tablas relacionadas** e implementación de código en PHP.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tus comentarios y ayuda A. Cedano, voy a revisar GROUP_CONCAT, esta mas claro ahora, entonces de momento esta bien las relaciones de las entidades cierto?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor que podrías hacer es juntar ingreso con persona, creo que no tiene mucho caso que estén en tablas distintas. Posteriormente para obtener todo lo registrado de esa persona podrías realizar una consulta sencilla:

SELECT c.nombre, c.apellidos, c.fecha_ingreso, b.detalle_tipo_doc
FROM persona_documento as a
INNER JOIN tipo_doc as b ON a.id_tipo_documento = b.id
INNER JOIN persona as c ON a.id_persona = c.id;

Espero te ayude, saludos!

Comment: Hola @Othon gracias por responder, haber suponiendo que es una DB de una clinica, la tabla seria esto INGRESO(id, fecha_atencion,id_persona), ahora lo de las 20 tablas es algo que podría tener en mi BD, por ejemplo COMPROBANTE(id,id_persona,numero_comp,serie_compro),etc. te das cuenta siempre voy a reutilizar a la tabla persona, ya sea para seleccionar clientes, pacientes, etc. no se si sea una buena practica, para no registrar los datos de la persona en cada tabla que necesite datos de personas