# Mostrar JSON en tabla con js desde php

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero mostrar los datos que recibo de una consulta hecha en un fichero php, en un html con una tabla, suena sencillo, pero necesito agrupar por uno de los campos que tengo en el json.

La cosa sería, tengo este json:

```
[{"id_order":"1","id_order_state":"1","date_add":"2013-02-27 16:24:30"},
{"id_order":"2","id_order_state":"3","date_add":"2013-04-08 12:47:34"},...
```

Que es infinito digamos.

Lo que quiero hacer es agrupar en una tabla las ordenes(id_order) según los diferentes estados por los que hayan pasado( id_order_state). Como para un mismo id_order, existen diferentes estados me come un poco el coco como agruparlos correctamente.

Busco que me quede una tabla de este estilo:

`ESTADO INICIAL | ESTADO FINAL| NUMERO DE ORDENES(suma de id_order)`

Comparto el código:

```
    <?php
$mysql = new mysql("192.168.0.20", "root", "1234", "prueba");
if ($mysql->connect_errno) {
    $arrayData=array("error"=>"Conexión fallida: ".$mysql->connect_error);
}else{
     $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
     $consulta = "SELECT id_order, id_order_status, data_add FROM ps_order_history limit 100";
     if ($resultado = $mysql->query($consulta)) { 
        //creo que esto me podria sobrar. 
        $arayData=array();
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arrayData[]=$fila;
        }
        $resultado->free();
     }else{
        $arrayData=array("error"=>"Error");
     }
    $mysql->close();
}
$json = json_encode($arrayData);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo $json;
?>
```

Y mi codigo HTMl: (Esta tabla la hice de prueba para ver si podia pintarla pero no me funciona).

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="table table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>IdOrderHistory</th>
          <th>IdEmployee</th>
          <th>IdOrder</th>
          <th>IdOrderStatus</th>
          <th>DateAdd</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableBody">

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    function update() 
    { 
        var request = $.ajax
            ({
                url: "consulta.php", 
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json"

                success: function(data) {
                  //console.log(data);
                   var valor = ''
                   data.forEach(product => {
                    valor += "<tr>"+
                    '<td>' + data.id_order_history + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data.id_employee + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data.id_order + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data.id_order_state + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data.date_add + '</td>' +
                    '<td><button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash"></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil"></button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                  $("#tableBody").html(valor);
                }
            });
    }

});
</script>
```

Tengo los datos dentro del json, pero me gustaría saber, como pintarlos en una tabla, haciendo la agrupación que comento.

Espero haberme explicado bien y que me puedan echar una mano. Ya que tras conseguir organizar este json, quiero realizar una gráfica con SigmaJS.

Si me pudieran explicar un poco como va sigma he conseguido realizar alguna gráfica pero no pasándole datos.

Un saludo y gracias por su atención.

Edito:

Agrego la consulta sql con la que estoy intentando realizar la consulta:

```
SELECT id_order,id_order_state,date_add 

FROM ps_order_history
GROUP BY id_order
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿si sólo necesitas unos datos específicos, por qué los traes todos en vez de filtrar la consulta en el servidor (mediante `GROUP BY` por ejemplo)? Estás sobrecargando la comunicación entre cliente/servidor trayendo datos que no necesitas. Eso es una mala práctica de programación. Es como irte de viaje con 10 maletas de ropa cuando sólo vas a necesitar una. Hoy día te cobran US$ 50 por cada maleta adicional, ese es el precio que estás pagando por no optimizar.

Comment: Como aqui no me cobran por traer datos... jejej Pues simplemente hice un "select * " pero vamos, que realmente solo necesito los ultimos 3 campos, puedo filtrarlos perfectamente, ese no es mi problema. Mi problema viene cuando intento agruparlos, partiendo de que existen 2 columnas de una misma de la bd.. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Bueno, pero en las aplicaciones los recursos cuentan y pasan factura. No es lo mismo consultar y mandar al cliente 2 datos que mandarle 100. Cuando te hagas famoso y tu aplicación tenga millones de usuarios, notarás la diferencia. Y cuando la app empiece a ser lenta empezarás a perder usuarios, el servidor se caerá, etc. Si por ejemplo en la consulta usas un `GROUP BY` podrás obtener los datos agrupados como quieres y devolverlos al cliente para que este los presente en pantalla. No sé si me explico: en el `SELECT` usa una agrupación, y selecciona solamente las columnas que necesites.

Comment: En tu caso creo que sería interesante un uso combinado de `GROUP_CONCAT` y de `GROUP BY`. Podrías agrupar los resultados agrupados con un separador y luego desglosarlos con algo como `split`. Si observas el [segundo resultado de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967) podrás ver lo que produce esa combinación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus sugerencias, voy a intentar realizarlo a ver si soy capaz, Gracias @A.Cedano por la "miniclase" probare esto y de lo que sea ya posteo. un saludo :)

Comment: Lo he probado para hacer la consulta primero que nada, y no consigo sacar los datos, porque alguna de las columnas es dependiente de las otras, o como decia antes, hay varios id_orders con diferentes id_order_state. El error que saco de mysql es: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'krackonline_16.ps_order_history.id_order_state' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.
Por eso lo que queria era transformar el array que ya tengo en uno que me interese a mi.

Comment: El error es porque tu consulta viola una regla importante de las funciones de agregación. Esto se puede desactivar, pero no es recomendable hacerlo, la regla existe por algo y es para que la consulta quede optimizada. Si editas la pregunta poniendo la consulta que has escrito quizá podamos revisarla y sugerirte algún modo de evitar ese error. Eso sí, indica en el `SELECT`  **únicamente las columnas que necesitas**, no todas las columnas de la tabla(s).

Comment: Eso he hecho, edito el post y pongo la consulta que estoy probando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias A.Cedano, lo he conseguido solucionar de la siguiente manera:

Para la consulta he utilizado esta sentencia:

```
$query = "SELECT id_order, id_order_state, date_add FROM ps_order_history order by date_add asc";
```

Despues para conseguir el array deseado, he hecho una serie de bucles:

```
    $array_nodos = array();
$array_relaciones = array();
foreach ($array_ordenado as $pedido){
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($pedido as $estado){
        if (isset($array_nodos[$estado['id_order_state']])){
            $array_nodos[$estado['id_order_state']]++; 
        }
        else $array_nodos[$estado['id_order_state']] = 1;


        if (isset($pedido[$i+1])){
            if (isset($array_relaciones[$pedido[$i]['id_order_state']][$pedido[$i+1]['id_order_state']])){
                $array_relaciones[$pedido[$i]['id_order_state']][$pedido[$i+1]['id_order_state']]++;
            }
            else $array_relaciones[$pedido[$i]['id_order_state']][$pedido[$i+1]['id_order_state']] = 1;
        }

        $i++;
    }
}
```

Un poco lioso, pero así obtengo el array como lo necesito para tratarlo en sigma. Muchas gracias por sus aportaciones, no lo habría logrado sin ellas.

Un saludo.