# Obtener consulta de varios resultados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy creando con php y mysql una consulta a una tabla en la que con un mismo id de usuario existen varios id de producto.
Ya he conseguido que no me muestre el id de producto repetido, pero no se como obtener los resultados si no es mediante un array.
He hecho esto:

```
$sql2=$db->prepare('SELECT id_user,id_product FROM contracts WHERE id_user=:id_user GROUP BY id_product');
$sql2->execute(array(
        ':id_user'=>$id_user
));
$id_product=$sql2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
foreach($id_product[2] as $value){
        $valueInt=(int)$value;
        $array=array_map('intval',str_split($valueInt));//=>array=[1,3]
}
```

Mas abajo, llamo al id_product especifico asi:

```
if($array[0]==1){
    $id_product==1;
    echo "<p>Cuenta corriente Básica:</p>";
    echo "<a href='products/cuentas/cuenta_corriente.php?id_product=".$array[0]."'>Ir a mi cuenta básica</a>";
}
```

Y así otras dos veces más, ya sea el id_product el 2 o el 3:

```
if($array[0]==2){
```

o

```
if($array[0]==3){
```

De esta manera solo he conseguido que me muestre en el caso de que sea 3, es decir, el último.

Comment: Una opción interesante para este caso podría ser `GROUP_CONCAT`. Obtendrías una columna con valores así por cada grupo: `1|3`, separados por `|` u otro símbolo. Luego por programación haces un `explode` obteniendo los valores como un array. [En esta respuesta (ver segundo resultado)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967) puedes ver un ejemplo contextualizado. Por otra parte, no logro entender del todo tu pregunta. Quizá convendría que expliques el uso final que quieres dar a tus resultados.

Comment: Pon la condición dentro del ciclo, `foreach($id_product as $value){ if($value==1){ //tu condición} } `

Comment: He editado la pregunta actualizandola al estado actual.

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla he actualizado la respuesta, échale un ojo!

Comment: me sigue saliendo solo el último registro

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer con los resultados?, no logro entenderlo. Supongamos que tienes los ids así: `1|2|3|4` , ¿qué necesitas hacer luego con esos datos?

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo arregle, modificando la idea que me dio itsnesky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres obtener los dígitos `1` y `3` por separado podrías pasar tu variable a un array y operar con los números por separado.

```
$array = [];

foreach($id_product[2] as $value) {
     $array  = array_map('intval', str_split($value)); //=> array = [1, 3]
     ...
}

if($array[0] == 1) { //=> array[0] = 1, la condición se cumple
     ...
}
```

**@EDIT**

Como te he mencionado antes, ahora mismo tienes en un `array` todos los `id` de los productos asociados a ese usuario.

Si quieres añadir tantos enlaces como productos tenga un usuario no tienes que hacer condicionales según el tipo de `id`, te valdría con imprimir los enlaces personalizados para cada producto modificando su respectivo `id`.

Tal que así:

```
$array = [];

foreach($id_product[2] as $value) {
     $array  = array_map('intval', str_split($value)); //=> array = [1, 3]
}

/*
 * Siguiendo el ejemplo que has puesto (array = [1, 3]):
 * 
 * Para la primera iteración la url sería:
 * products/cuentas/cuenta_corriente.php?id_product=1
 *
 * Para la segunda iteración la url sería: 
 * products/cuentas/cuenta_corriente.php?id_product=3
 */

foreach($array as $id) {
         echo "<a href='products/cuentas/cuenta_corriente.php?id_product=".$id."'>Ir a mi cuenta básica</a>";
}
```

Comment: Gracias @itsnesky, pero tampoco es la solución. No me reconoce el primer elemento y el segundo lo muestra mal: Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: En el caso de que `$value` sea una variable de tipo `string` primero debes pasarla a `int` para hacer la conversión a array. Se haría de la siguiente manera:    `$valueInt = (int)$value;` y ahora en vez de pasar la variable `$value` al `array_map`, le pasaríamos `$valueInt`.

Comment: vale se fue el error y la opción del 3 sale bien, pero la del primero, que es el 1, no me aparece por ningun lado

Comment: ¿Tienes hecha la condición? Ten en cuenta que ahora tienes un array con los números por separado, si quieres acceder a cualquiera de ellos tan solo tienes que cambiar el índice con el que accedes al array. ¿Puedes ser más específico y editar tu pregunta añadiendo código nuevo? Gracias!