# Almacenar una lista de usuarios en un campo de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una web en la que tu puedes seguir a otros usuarios, al pulsar el botón "seguir" lo que debería hacer mi programa es añadir el nombre de usuario de la persona a la que quiero seguir a un array de nombres a los que esa persona sigue, pero no se como almacenar un array en MySQL.

La consulta PHP sería algo así:

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
$result = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT seguidos FROM users WHERE username = $username");
$array_usuarios_seguidos = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
//Esto devolvería un array algo así: ["rmggames", "user2", "user3"]
$arrayNuevo = $array_usuarios_seguidos // + el usuario al que se quiere seguir
$sql = "UPDATE users SET `lista_de_seguidos`='$arrayNuevo'"
```

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer no es una muy buena idea. Las bases de datos son *relacionales* y si luego quieres hacer consultas donde se haga `JOIN` que necesiten esos usuarios, será harto complicado al tenerlos guardados en forma de lista. Por esto lo que se suele hacer para estos casos es crear una especie de tabla asociativa donde se exprese **por medio del ID de cada usuario** quién es amigo de quien. Sea como sea, si la finalidad de esto no es otra que tener una lista, lo puedes guardar en una columna VARCHAR separados por coma y en PHP usar `explode()` para diferenciarlos.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967) y el ejemplo que hay en el enlace al final. Verás que en las tablas se guarda una fila por cada mensaje, con su emisor y su receptor. Esto facilitará situaciones como saber: *cuántos amigos tiene el usuario X*, *quién es amigo de X y de Y*, *quién no es amigo de X pero sí es amigo de Y y de Z*... etc. Si tú tienes los usuarios en una lista hacer cualquiera de estas cosas será harto complicado, cuando no imposible. Es por eso que las bases de datos son **relacionales**. Implica optimizar, aprovechar indices, etc.