# Eliminar ultimo caracter de consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de eliminar el ultimo caracter de una colsulta en PHP y Mysql
tengo una base con la siguiente estructura

```
   +------------+------------+---------+
   |   centro   | zona_carga |   pml   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   |    NORTE   |  Acapulco  |    10   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   |    NORTE   |  Aguas     |    13   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   |    SUR     |  VER       |    15   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   |    NORTE   |  Oaxaca    |    66   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   |  ORIENTE   |  Puebla    |    10   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
```

cuando hago una consulta

```
   $sql = "SELECT zona_de_carga from nodosp where centro_control ='NORTE' group by zona_de_carga;";
  $fire = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
  echo "'"; 
  echo $consulta_zona= $result['zona_de_carga']."',";
  }
```

Me arroja el siguiente resultado

> ```
> > 'Acapulco','Aguas','Oaxaca',
> ```

Lo que intento hacer es quitar la ultima coma de ese resultado pero he intentado con

```
>   echo substr($consulta_zona,  0, -1);
```

Pero el resultado no es el que requiero ya que me elimina todas las , del resultado

```
> 'Acapulco''Aguas''Oaxaca'
```

Lo mismo sucede cuando utilizo

```
 echo rtrim($consulta_zona, ", ");
```

el resultado lo trae sin comas.

> 'Acapulco''Aguas''Oaxaca'

Que estare haciendo mal, si alguien me puede orientar?

Comment: Podrías usar `GROUP_CONCAT`  en la consulta SQL directamente, obteniendo así los datos agrupados y separados por coma. [Ver aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967), el separador por defecto es la coma, pero puedes usar otro separador si fuera preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en el codigo cuando asignas la variable `$consulta_zona`, pues no estas incluyendo la primera comilla (o apóstrofe) `'` en ella, solo lo muestras en la salida durante el `echo`.

Fíjate en este trozo:

```
echo "'"; 
echo $consulta_zona= $result['zona_de_carga']."',";
```

Eso claro que te muestra lo siguiente:

```
'Acapulco','Aguas','Oaxaca',
```

pero realmente la variable `$consulta_zona` contiene esto cada vez que se cumple un ciclo:

```
Acapulco',   <- Primer ciclo
Aguas',      <- Segundo ciclo
Oaxaca',     <- Tercer ciclo
```

lo que ocurre es que con los `echo` que has puesto parece que vayan todos seguidos.

Además, es confuso lo que dices después que haces:

```
echo substr($consulta_zona,  0, -1);
```

o bien

```
echo rtrim($consulta_zona, ", ");
```

porque todos hemos querido entender que lo hacias despues del `while` pero ahora comprendo que lo has metido dentro tambien y te has reafirmado en que no funcionaba de nuevo.

Es decir, que tu código actual con todo metido debe ser asi más o menos:

```
$sql = "SELECT zona_de_carga from nodosp where centro_control ='NORTE' group by zona_de_carga;";
$fire = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
    echo "'"; 
    echo $consulta_zona= $result['zona_de_carga']."',";
    echo substr($consulta_zona,  0, -1);
    // o este otro
    // echo rtrim($consulta_zona, ", ");
 }
```

Lo cual ahora se puede ver mucho más claramente los errores cometidos.

Mi proposición de código correcto es este (mira los comentarios en el propio código para ver su explicación):

```
$sql = "SELECT zona_de_carga from nodosp where centro_control ='NORTE' group by zona_de_carga;";
$fire = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$consulta_zona = '';  // inicializo la variable
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
    $consulta_zona .= "'".$result['zona_de_carga']."',";  // entrecomillo el resultado
                                                          // terminando en coma y 
                                                          // lo agregro a la variable con el operador .=
}
// ahora que ha juntado todos los valores de todos los ciclos...
$consulta_zona = rtrim($consulta_zona, ", "); // sustituyo el valor de la variable 
                                              // quitándole la coma final
echo $consulta_zona;
```

Esto debe darte el resultado deseado, que es:

```
'Acapulco','Aguas','Oaxaca'
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, el error es mas que nada mi inexperiencia, muchas gracias ahora el concepto en general de arreglos me ha quedado mas claro.

Answer (score 3):

Mira esta alternativa en la que lo que se hace es anteponer la `,` en vez de postponerla, y usar una variable `$sep` que en la primera iteración es cadena vacía y las demás es `,`:

```
$sql = "SELECT zona_de_carga from nodosp where centro_control ='NORTE' group by zona_de_carga;";
$fire = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$sep = '';
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
    echo $sep . "'" . $result['zona_de_carga'] . "'";
    $sep = ',';
}
```

Nota: He quitado la variable `$consulta_zona` porque no le veo sentido.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo muy claro porque no te funciona el [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php), pero siempre puedes hacer algo como:

```
$str = "'Acapulco','Aguas','Oaxaca',";
$str_c = "";
for ($i=0;$i < strlen($str);$i++){
    if ($i < strlen($str)-1) {
        $str_c = $str_c . $str[$i];
    }
}
echo $str_c;
```

Comment: Hola te paso mi consulta $sql = "SELECT zona_de_carga from nodosp where centro_control ='$zona' group by zona_de_carga;";
  $fire = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
  echo "'"; 
 $str= $result['zona_de_carga']."',";
  $str = "'Acapulco','Aguas','Oaxaca',";
$str_c = "";
for ($i=0;$i < strlen($str);$i++){
    if ($i < strlen($str)-1) {
        $str_c = $str_c . $str[$i];
    }
}
echo $str_c;
  
  } me arroja asi el resultado 'CENTRO ORIENTE''CENTRO SUR''LAZARO CARDENAS''VDM CENTRO''VDM NORTE''VDM SUR' desaparecen las ,

Comment: ¿Después del while, la variable string $str que contenido tiene?

Comment: cuando le hago echo a $str sale 'ENSENADA','MEXICALI','SANLUIS','TIJUANA',
despues ese $str lo paso como en tu ejemplo, pero el resultado es que le borra todas las comas a la consulta

Comment: Si $str = "'ENSENADA','MEXICALI','SANLUIS','TIJUANA', " todos los métodos que hemos visto deben funcionar y quitar la coma final.

Comment: @Vicent date cuenta de que no construye la cadena completa, sino que la va pintando, por es no le funciona el `substr` ni nada para quitar la última coma, en realidad estaría quitando todas las comas.

Comment: Cierto José Carlos, lo que quería expresar, es que una vez construida la cadena y fuera del while, podría aplicar cualquiera de los métodos.