# ¿Cómo mostrar filas de resultados de forma segura utilizando mysqli orientado a objetos?

Tags: php, mysqli

> A. Cedano dijo en un comentario que particularmente no me gusta `num_rows` para saber si hay filas en un resultado, a veces no es seguro, y hay otras formas mejores de saberlo... pero esto no viene al caso ahora ¿o quizás sí?

Existe una pregunta y una [respuesta AQUÍ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81028/consultar-y-leer-datos-mysql-mediante-pdo-de-forma-segura-y-eficiente/81029#81029) pero en PDO

> Tengo dos ejemplos donde utilizo `num_rows` basándose a la seguridad que A. Cedano menciona y de que existe otras formas de saberlo.

Como puedo mostrar filas de resultados de una forma segura utilizando ***mysqli orientado a objetos***

¿Cuál son las otras formas mejores de saberlo?

**Ejemplos**

En el siguiente código utilizo un `num_rows;` para comprobar si existe registro o no para insertar o actualizar.

```
  $result = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM failed_attempt WHERE ip=? AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()");

  $result->bind_param("s",$addres);
  $result->execute();
  $result->store_result();

  //Variable para saber si existe registro o no para insert o update.
  $check_result = $result->num_rows;
  if ($result->num_rows===1) { 
    //Obtenemos datos para comparar intentos y para resetear intentos por su ultimo fecha.
    $result->bind_result($failed_login_attempt);
    $result->fetch();
    $result->close();
  } else {
    $result->close();
    $failed_login_attempt=0;
  }
```

En el siguiente código busco el usuario ingresado, y también utilizo un `num_rows;`

```
  if(count($_POST)>0 && $captcha == true) {
    $username = $_POST["username"] ?: '';
    $password = $_POST["password"] ?: '';    
//Buscar usuario ingresado - INICIO
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT id_user,username,password,logindatetime, CASE WHEN logindatetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 2 MINUTE ) AND NOW() THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as logueado FROM users where username=? AND active=? LIMIT 1");
$sql->bind_param("si",$username,$active);
$active=1;
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
if ($sql->num_rows===1) {
    $sql->bind_result($id_userBD,$usernameBD,$passwordDB,$logindatetime,$activeBD);
    if ($sql->fetch()){
        if (password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
            $check_password = true;
        } else {
            $check_password = false;
        }
    } $sql->close();
  } else {
    $sql->close();
    $check_password = false;
  }
```

Comment: @A.Cedano amigo Ud sabe muy bien sobre este tema espero de su aporte :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si buscas una alternativa, para evitar `num_rows`, podrías usar `fetch()`.

### Un ejemplo alternativa:

```
//Sentencia.
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM failed_attempt WHERE ip=? AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW() LIMIT 1");
$result->bind_param("s",$addres);
$result->execute();
//Vincula variables a una sentencia preparada para el almacenamiento de resultados
$result->bind_result($failed_login_attemptBD);
//Obtiene los resultados de una sentencia preparadas en las variables vinculadas.
if ($result->fetch()) {
    //Iniciamos variable existe fallo.
    $check_result=1;
    //Obtenemos datos para comparar intentos y para resetear intentos por su ultimo fecha.
    $failed_login_attempt = $failed_login_attemptBD;

} else {
    //Reseteamos fallos.
    $check_result=0;
    $failed_login_attempt=0;
 }
 $result->close();
```

> **Nota:** en cuanto a seguridad, no sé si hay alguna diferencia o si es mejor `num_rows` o `fetch()`

### Segundo ejemplo:

Ahora bien, si te fijas bien en tu sentencia al final pone `LIMIT 1`, es decir, el número de registros a devolver, en su caso solo puede ser `0` o `1`.

> **LIMIT**: se usa para limitar selecciones de datos de una base de datos `MySQL`.

Si sólo necesita un número especificado de filas de un conjunto de resultados, utilice una cláusula `LIMIT` en la consulta, en lugar de buscar el conjunto de resultados completo y descartar los datos adicionales.

La cláusula `LIMIT` facilita el código de múltiples páginas de resultados o paginación con `SQL`, y es muy útil en grandes tablas. Devolver un gran número de registros puede tener un impacto en el rendimiento.

Conclusión, en principio no debería darte problemas `if ($result->num_rows===1) {` ya que usas como limite 1 registro en tu sentencia.

[Manual lIMIT Query Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html)

*Lógica:*

Si fuera por lógica, en tu sentencia `users` que no utiliza `LIMIT 1`, que yo personalmente si la añadiría, en tu sentencia compraras donde tu `username` (`FROM users where username=?`), si tu `Base de datos` esta creado correctamente, dicha campo debería ser `unique`, es decir, único, no pueden existir más de dos, en principio tu `num_rows` tampoco debería de fallar, ya que tu comparación debe comprobar un campo único y difícilmente va encontrar dos registros iguales, igual cuenta para correo electrónico (email), debería ser `unique`.

Answer (score 2):

En efecto, el comentario:

> no me gusta num_rows para saber si hay filas en un resultado, a veces
>   no es seguro, y hay otras formas mejores de saberlo...

es de mi autoría.

Quizá haya una confusión con el término *seguro* usado en mi comentario, el cual en ese contexto, significa que `num_rows` no informa siempre sobre la cantidad de filas reales que hay en un conjunto de resultados. Es decir, **no es seguro que el valor devuelto por `num_rows` sea exactamente el total de filas.** Ahora comprendo que debí usar el término **no es exacto** en lugar de *no es seguro*.

Mi afirmación en ese caso no se refiere a la vulnerabilidad del código, la cual no depende del uso de `num_rows`, sino de la forma en que se envía la consulta a la base de datos.

---

## ¿Por qué `num_rows` no es seguro, es decir, por qué no es exacto?

Los tres puntos en los que me apoyo son afirmados en el mismo [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

1. Porque depende de si se utilizan resultados con o sin bufer

> El comportamiento de `mysqli_num_rows()` **depende** de si es que se
>   utilizan resultsets con o sin buffer. En caso de emplearlos sin buffer
>   `mysqli_num_rows()` no retornará el número de filas correcto hasta que
>   todas las filas del resultado hayan sido recuperadas.

Si verificamos [el código fuente](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/121331b2ce6254d8b640bcc14ebc57d4ef558060/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c#L1688) veremos que es así:

```
if (mysqli_result_is_unbuffered_and_not_everything_is_fetched(result)) {
    php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Function cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULT");
    RETURN_LONG(0);
}
```

2. Porque el tipo de retorno (entero o cadena) depende de la cantidad de filas retornadas

> Si el número de filas es mayor al máximo valor de `PHP_INT_MAX`, el
>   número será retornado como un string.

3. Según [este comentario del Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#121078)

No funciona cuando se usa junto con `LIMIT` y `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

---

## ¿Qué alternativas hay para `num_rows`?

### Alternativa 1

Si lo único que se necesita es saber el número de filas que hay, la  mejor forma es hacer esta consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla WHERE condicion;
```

### Alternativa 2

Si aparte de conocer la cantidad de filas necesitas la información de las columnas puedes hacer la consulta normal:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tabla WHERE condicion;
```

Luego, almacenas los resultados en un arreglo asociativo y cuentas las filas aplicando `count` sobre el arreglo obtenido.

---

## Código de prueba

Veamos un código de prueba con parte de lo afirmado.

Leyendo los `var_dump` y los resultados, veremos que `num_rows`  no siempre es exacto.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/txnp-a5ib)**</kbd>

```
<?php
/**
* Ejemplo con Mysqli 
* 
* Notas:
*    1.  Los require son propios de este ejemplo 
*    2.  Todo lo relativo a  la base de datos en sí y la consulta son propios de este ejemplo
*/
require_once "dBug!.php";
require "util/public_db_info.php";
$db = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);

/*Esta es la mejor forma si lo único que se quiere es el total de filas*/
$sqlMejor="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM books";
$resMejor = $db->query($sqlMejor);

echo "<pre>";

if ($resMejor)
{
    while($row = $resMejor->fetch_object())
    {
        $intTotal = $row->total;
    }

    echo "SI SÓLO QUEREMOS EL TOTAL DE FILAS:\n\n";
    echo "El var_dump se muestra  así:\n\n";
    var_dump($resMejor);

    echo "\nTotal filas usando COUNT(*): " .$intTotal."\n";
}
/* Consulta */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books";   

/* Se envía la consulta y se almacena en variables */
$resConBuffer = $db->query($sql);
$resSinBuffer = $db->query($sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);





if ($resConBuffer)
{
    echo "\nCONSULTA SIN BUFFER:\n\n";
    echo "El var_dump se muestra  así:\n\n";
    var_dump($resConBuffer);
    echo "\nTotal filas usando num_rows antes de leer: ".$resConBuffer->num_rows."\n";

    while($row = $resConBuffer->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $arrConBuffer[] = $row;
    }
    echo "Total filas usando num_rows después de leer: ".$resConBuffer->num_rows."\n";
    echo "Total filas contando los datos mismos: ".count($arrConBuffer)."\n";

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    $resConBuffer->free();
}

if ($resSinBuffer)
{
    echo "\nCONSULTA CON BUFFER:\n";
    echo "El var_dump se muestra  así:\n\n";
    var_dump($resSinBuffer);
    echo "Total filas usando num_rows antes de leer: ".$resSinBuffer->num_rows."\n";

    while($row = $resSinBuffer->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $arrSinBuffer[] = $row;
    }
    echo "Total filas usando num_rows después de leer: ".$resSinBuffer->num_rows."\n";
    echo "Total filas contando los datos mismos: ".count($arrSinBuffer)."\n";

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    $resSinBuffer->free();

}
echo "</pre>";

/* cerrar la conexión */
$db->close();    
?>
```

**Resultado:**

```
SI SÓLO QUEREMOS EL TOTAL DE FILAS:

El var_dump se muestra  así:

object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}

Total filas usando COUNT(*): 51

CONSULTA SIN BUFFER:

El var_dump se muestra  así:

object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(5)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(51)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}

Total filas usando num_rows antes de leer: 51
Total filas usando num_rows después de leer: 51
Total filas contando los datos mismos: 51

CONSULTA CON BUFFER:
El var_dump se muestra  así:

object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(5)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(1)
}
Total filas usando num_rows antes de leer: 0
Total filas usando num_rows después de leer: 51
Total filas contando los datos mismos: 51
```

Comment: Lo siento si mal entendí puedes editar mi pregunta para aclararla correctamente amigo un +1 gracias :)

Comment: @A.Cedano buen aporte +1.

Answer (score 1):

Veamos más al detalle las **consultas almacenadas** y **no almacenadas en buffer**:

> Las consultas usan el modo de almacenamiento en buffer por omisión.
>   Esto significa que los resultados de las consultas son transferidos
>   inmediatamente del Servidor MySQL a PHP donde luego se mantienen en la
>   memoria del proceso de PHP. Esto permite operaciones adicionales como
>   la cuenta del número de filas y mover (buscar) el puntero actual del
>   resultado. También permite emitir más consultas en la misma conexión
>   mientras se trabaja con el conjunto de resultados. El lado negativo
>   del modo de almacenamiento en buffer es que los conjuntos de
>   resultados grandes requieren bastante más memoria. La memoria se
>   mantendrá ocupada hasta que todas las referencias al conjunto de
>   resultados sean desestablecidas o se libere explícitamente el conjunto
>   de resultados, lo que automáticamente ocurrirá durante la finalización
>   de la última petición. La terminología "resultado almacenado" también
>   se usa para el modo de almacenamiento en buffer, ya que el conjunto de
>   resultados completo se almacena de una vez. (...)

> ... las consultas almacenadas en buffer deberían usarse en casos donde se espera 
>   solamente un conjunto de resultados limitado o se necesite conocer la
>   cantidad de filas devueltas antes de leer todas las filas. El modo de
>   no almacenamiento en buffer debería usarse cuando se esperan
>   resultados grandes.

Esto implica o explica la duda si el resultado es **exacto** o **no**:

> El comportamiento de `mysqli_num_rows()` depende de si es que se
>   utilizan resultsets con o sin buffer. En caso de emplearlos sin buffer
>   `mysqli_num_rows()` no retornará el número de filas correcto hasta que
>   todas las filas del resultado hayan sido recuperadas.

Entonces en tu caso estás en el lado *seguro*, ósea **exacto**, ya que usas por omisión el *resultado almacenado*.

Si optas por no tener *resultados almacenado* **no te serviría de nada ¡`num_rows`!**

Veamos ahora el **rendimiento**:

Un ejemplo, si tienes una tabla con muchas filas `(rows)` entonces lo que haces con `num_rows` es pasar todas esas filas sacada de la consulta (buffer) una vez más a la memoria de `PHP`, si usas `COUNT()` en tu consulta pasas solo **1** resultado a `PHP`.

Benchmark **consultas almacenadas** y **no almacenadas en buffer** con y sin `COUNT()`:

Entorno de prueba:

```
iMac: (27 pulgadas, finales de 2012)
Processador: 3,4 GHz Intel Core i7
Memoria: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

PHP version: 7.1.3
MySQL version: 5.7.17
Tabla con más de 30.000.000 registros
```

Código de pruebas (simplificado):

**test_mysqli_con_buffer**:

```
function test_mysqli_con_buffer( $count = 1000 ) {          

    $time_start = microtime( true );        

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {

        $r = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM dummy_data WHERE id < 1000;" );
        $r->fetch_all();                
    }       

    return number_format( microtime( true ) - $time_start, 3 );
}
```

**test_mysqli_sin_buffer**:

```
function test_mysqli_sin_buffer( $count = 1000 ) {          

    $time_start = microtime( true );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {

        $r = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM dummy_data WHERE id < 1000;", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT );              
        $r->fetch_all();                
    }           

    return number_format( microtime( true ) - $time_start, 3 );
}
```

**test_mysqli_count_con_buffer**:

```
function test_mysqli_count_con_buffer( $count = 1000 ) {            

    $time_start = microtime( true );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {

        $r = $db->query( "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM dummy_data WHERE id < 1000;" );
        $r->fetch_all();            
    }

    return number_format( microtime( true ) - $time_start, 3 );
}
```

**test_mysqli_count_sin_buffer**:

```
function test_mysqli_count_sin_buffer( $count = 1000 ) {            

    $time_start = microtime( true );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {

        $r = $db->query( "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM dummy_data WHERE id < 1000;", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT );
        $r->fetch_all();
    }

    return number_format( microtime( true ) - $time_start, 3 );
}
```

**And the winner is....**

```
--------------------------------------
|        PHP BENCHMARK SCRIPT        |
--------------------------------------
Start : 2017-09-27 11:12:48
Server : localhost@127.0.0.1
PHP version : 7.1.3
Platform : Darwin
--------------------------------------
test_mysqli_con_buffer       : 2.859 sec.
test_mysqli_sin_buffer       : 3.136 sec.
test_mysqli_count_con_buffer : 0.419 sec.
test_mysqli_count_sin_buffer : 0.414 sec.
--------------------------------------
Total time:                  : 6.828 sec.
```

Fuentes:

- [php.net - Consultas almacenadas y no almacenadas en buffer](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)
- [php.net - mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)
- [PHP Benchmark Performance Script](http://www.php-benchmark-script.com)

Comment: esperemos y llegué un comentario de A. Cedano

Comment: @A.Cedano la duda se me presentó a su comentario siempre es bueno saber estos temas :)

Comment: ya existe una pregunta de Cedano esta pregunta se baso a un comentario suyo puedes analizar su respuesta y sacar tus propias conclusiones quizas para aclarar ciertas cosas o mejorar la pregunta no se o algo.

Comment: @J.Mick - No se a que te refieres: _sacar tus propias conclusiones_ :) ... Haz obtenido tres respuestas diferentes escoge la que más se adapte a tu duda ... y respecto a tu pregunta no hay que mejorar nada en mi punto de vista... saludos

Comment: me refiero a lo que mencionas en tu respuesta ***"Como ya no se puede ver ese enlace te tengo que decir que dudo que sea el tema sobre seguridad."***

Comment: @J.Mick - Respuesta editada... me he concentrado en el tema del rendimiento