# num_rows me devuelve 0 en MySQLi / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select

Tengo el siguiente SELECT de PHP donde intento contar la cantidad de registros que hay, pero siempre me devuelve 0.

Código PHP:

```
$sname = "localhost";
$uname = "t**********ub";
$upass = "b&**********Vr";
$dbname = "t**********ub";

$conn = new mysqli($sname, $uname, $upass, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user FROM users_links");
$stmt->execute();

echo $stmt->num_rows;
```

Imágenes que muestran el nombre de la tabla, la columna que se selecciona y que sí hay registros:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

solo estas `ejecutando` debes almacenar los resultados con: `$stmt->store_result();`

```
$sname = "localhost";
$uname = "t**********ub";
$upass = "b&**********Vr";
$dbname = "t**********ub";

$conn = new mysqli($sname, $uname, $upass, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user FROM users_links");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
```

Comment: ¿Alguien sabe qué diferencia hay entre prepare y execute y directamente query? ¿En ambos casos sería necesario un store_result? ¡Gracias!

Comment: puedes ver el manual en [php prepare](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Pues el manual me ha dejado como estaba... :( Investigaré cuál es la diferencia entre preparar y ejecutar una consulta... Porque del query dice que realiza una consulta.

Comment: @David realmente el funcionamiento de `num_rows` en mysqli es precario en el sentido de que depende de otra configuración. O sea, depende de si está o no configurado para meter los resultados en el buffer o no (uses `query` o `prepare`). Por defecto mysqli no viene configurado para meter los resultados en el buffer (así es más ligero), por eso es necesario el uso de `store_result` para meterlos en el buffer y entonces saber cuántas filas hay. Yo traté el tema con más detalles [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105177/29967), aportando además ejemplos basados en código real.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes problemas con num_rows, debes declarar ->store_result() primero:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "tables");

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1");
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();

$rows = $query->num_rows;

echo $rows;

?>
```