# ¿Cómo usar PDO para los select en PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Utilizo PHP y Postgres para hacer consultas, me funciona muy bien pero quiero darle un toque de calidad y profesionalismo a mi código. hacerlo de la mejor manera para tener seguridad, evitar lo más posible inyecciones S_Q_L  y pérdida de información, este es mi código:

Clase database.php

```
class Database {

    private static $cont = null;

    public function __construct() {
        exit('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function getCadena() {
       $ini = parse_ini_file('C:\credenciales.ini', true);
       return "host='" . $ini['server']['host'] . "' port='" . 
       $ini['server']['port'] . "' dbname='" . $ini['server']['database'] . 
       "' user='" . $ini['server']['user'] . "' password='" . $ini['server'] 
       ['pass'] . "' ";
    }

    public static function connect() {
         $ini = parse_ini_file('C:\credenciales.ini', true);
         if (null == self::$cont) {
            try {
               self::$cont = new PDO("pgsql:host=" . $ini['server']['host'] 
               . ";port=" . $ini['server']['port'] . ";" . "dbname=" . 
               $ini['server']['database'], $ini['server']['user'], 
               $ini['server']['pass']);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
              die($e->getMessage());
            }
          }
          return self::$cont;
       }

       public static function disconnect() {
           self::$cont = null;
       }
```

Luego en otra clase, después de pasar por JQUERY y AJAX llego a este método:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
    $nombrefiltrar = strtoupper($_POST['nombreconductorfiltro']);
    $sql = " SELECT c_cedula, c_nombre, c_activo FROM conductor WHERE c_nombre LIKE '%" . $nombrefiltrar . "%' 
            ORDER BY c_nombre ASC";
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['c_cedula'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['c_nombre'] . '</td>';
        if ($row['c_activo'] == TRUE) {
            echo '<td> ACTIVO </td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td> INACTIVO </td>';
        }

        $conductor = "javascript:verEditarConductor(" . $row['c_cedula'] . ", '" . $row['c_nombre'] . "', " . $row['c_activo'] . ")";
        echo '<td><a href="' . $conductor . '" class="btn" style="background-color: #004D27" ><img src="png/edit.png"  alt="x" title="Ver" style="background-color: #004D27" /></a>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    Database::disconnect();
    echo '</tbody>
            </table>';
    break;
```

Cómo podría utilizar apuntadores para los SELECT con parámetros que tengo y hacer este tipo de consultas lo más segura posibles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del uso de *PDO* se recomienda utilizar marcadores de nombre, de este modo

Marcador de nombre

```
:nombre
```

De tal modo que tienes una variable así

```
$nombrefiltrar = strtoupper($_POST['nombreconductorfiltro']);
```

Tu `SELECT` debería quedar así

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT c_cedula, c_nombre, c_activo FROM conductor 
                       WHERE c_nombre LIKE :nombreFiltrar 
                       ORDER BY c_nombre ASC");
```

Usa el método `prepare()` para acceder a preparar tu consulta

Ahora como estas pasando un marcador de nombre, necesitas indicar el valor que será cambiado por medio de una variable, de este modo

```
$sql->bindParam(":nombreFiltrar", $nombreFiltrar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Ahora si ya estas trabajando con *PDO* deberías al final usar `execute()` para ejecutar tu consulta

```
$sql->execute();
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1**

Si necesitas pasar múltiples marcadores de nombre, hazlo del modo siguiente, a través de un array asociativo

```
$sql->execute(array(":valorUno" => $valorUno, ":valorDos" => $valorDos, 
                    ":valorTres" => $valorTres));
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2**

Para iterar los datos puedes hacerlo del modo siguiente

```
$resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($resultado as $value)
{
    echo $value["nombreColumna"];
}
```

**ACLARACIONES**

1. `fetchAll()` devuelve un *array* con todos los datos de las filas extraídas
2. `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` permite convertir los datos a un array asociativo, de tipo `clave => valor`
3. Usando un `foreach` recorro los valores
4. La nueva variable que contiene el valor en cada iteración `$value` ahora puede imprimir cada valor de cada columna, por medio del nombre de esta última de este modo `echo $value["nombreColumna"];`
5. `nombreColumna` es el nombre que vas a colocar de cada columna que deseas imprimir, necesitas poner tantos echos como columnas desees mostrar

Comment: En el caso que necesite pasar varios parámetros ¿Puedo hacer esto?

$sql->bindParam(":nombreFiltrar", $nombreFiltrar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":apellidoFiltrar", $apellidoFiltrar, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: te agrego como hacerlo en la misma respuesta @DiegoMartinez

Comment: Por favor de paso el foreach, please...

Comment: ya te respondí la primer duda, dame 5 min y pongo sobre el foreach @DiegoMartinez

Comment: OK. Es recomendado que lo haga de esta manera?

$registros = $sql->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

Si quiero recorrerlo?

Comment: listo, espero te sirva la respuesta @DiegoMartinez

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Pero ojo, si quiere un `LIKE` con el comodín `%`, como puede intuirse en la pregunta, tiene que poner el parámetro así:  `$nombrefiltrar = "%".strtoupper($_POST['nombreconductorfiltro'])."%";` O sea, los comodines *viajan*  con el dato que se pasa luego a través de `execute` o de uno de los métodos `bind` ([ver el apartado **2.6 Consultas preparadas y cláusula `LIKE`** de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81029/29967)).