# Consulta preparada PDO

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

Tengo la siguiente consulta preparada, uso PDO. La suma del campo consumofac se guarda en suma, lo que quiero es que me devuelva el resultado de esa suma. La consulta lo hago a traves de ODBC.

```
$consulta="select sum(c.consumofac) as suma from cabfacturacion c;";
            $consulta.="inner join cabfacturacionclie cl;";
            $consulta.="on (cl.codcliente=c.codcliente);";
            $consulta.="where c.anio='?';";
$sql=$dbh->prepare($consulta);

try {   
  $sql->bindParam(1, $anio, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4);
  $sql->execute();
             --resultado de la suma--
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error  en la consulta...!!!' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

Gracias por tu respuesta, he probado tu sugerencia:
    $total=$sql->fetchColumn();
    print("total = $total");

Solo imprime total=

La petición lo hago con ajax, y en el archivo donde recibo estas peticiones al hacer var_dump($_POST) me devuelve esto; estoy array (size=1) 'anio' => string '2019' (length=4), si está llegando el dato correcto, sin embargo el total de la suma no me muestra.

```
    require_once "../conecta/conexion.php";
    try
    {
        //var_dump($_POST);
       $anio = $_POST['anio'];
       $consulta="select sum(c.consumo) as suma from cabfacturacion c "; 
        $consulta.="inner join cabfacturacionclie cl "; 
        $consulta.="on (cl.codcliente=c.codcliente) "; 
        $consulta.="where c.anio=?";

        $sql=$dbh->prepare($consulta);
        $sql->bindParam(1, $anio, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4);

        $sql->execute();
        $total=$sql->fetchColumn();

        $msg=($total===false) ? "No hay filas" : sprintf("Suma: %d",$total);
        echo $msg;

        $dbh = null; 
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Error  en la consulta...!!!' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

?>

```
Datos de la conexion:

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING,
    PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING, 
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
];

try {
        $dbh = new PDO("odbc:driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};Server=$host;
        Port=$puerto;Database=$bd",$usuario,$clave,$options);
    } 
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Error al intentar conectar al servidor ...!!!' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106142/discussion-on-question-by-jimmorrison-consulta-preparada-pdo).

Answer (score 1):

Tienes **errores de sintaxis** en la consulta, porque cada fila la terminas con `;`, no debe ser así, dado que estás concatenando. Y cuando concatenas cuida de dejar un espacio en blanco al final para que no se junte todo y se produzca una consulta errónea...

Además, **los marcadores `?` no se ponen entre comillas** ni simples ni dobles, pues sirven simplemente para indicar que ahí va un valor que luego pasarás con `bindParam` o de otro  modo.

Conviene también que hagas el **`prepare` dentro del `try`**, así te capturará los errores relativos a la preparación.

Y, para este tipo de consultas puedes usar [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) para obtener el dato, ya que tu consulta **devolvería una sola fila/columna**. Dado que `fetchColumn()` retorna `false` si no hay filas, puedes hacer una comprobación mediante un ternario.

```
/*
    Usamos un ternario para verificar si hay datos en anio
*/
$anio = !empty($_POST['anio']) ? $_POST['anio'] : NULL;
if ($anio) {

    try{    
            $consulta="select sum(c.consumofac) as suma from cabfacturacion c ";
                        $consulta.="inner join cabfacturacionclie cl ";
                        $consulta.="on (cl.codcliente=c.codcliente) ";
                        $consulta.="where c.anio=?";
            $sql=$dbh->prepare($consulta);
            $sql->bindParam(1, $anio, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4);
            $sql->execute();
            $mData=$sql->fetchColumn(); #En $mData tendrás el resultado
            $msg=($mData===false) ? "No hay filas" : sprintf("Suma: %d",$mData);
        }


    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Error  en la consulta...!!!' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}else{
    $msg="No se postearon datos para año, revise la petición Ajax";
}
echo $msg;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he probado tu sugerencia:  
 $total=$sql->fetchColumn();
 print("total = $total");    Solo imprime total=

Comment: @JimMorrison revisa la respuesta y el código actualizado.

Comment: Muestra: Suma: 0 he probado con var_dump($total) y muestar null, la variable $anio que recibo en esta pagina ($anio = $_POST['anio'];) lo envío desde otra con ajax. El campo anio de mi consulta es de tipo caracter.

Comment: Debes revisar si hay datos con ese año o si estás recibiendo bien el dato desde Ajax. Si pasa una u otra cosa es lógico que la consulta no te devuelva nada.

Comment: Si hay datos con ese año, probé la consulta en el mismo gestor de BD.  Este es patte del codigo que enví con ajax: var anio = $('#anio').val();   $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax/fact-cob-ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:"html",
                     
                    data:"&anio=" + anio,     y en el archivo que hago lo suma recepciono el campo enviado $anio = $_POST['anio'];

Comment: @JimMorrison no se puede verificar una petición Ajax en un comentario. Verifica en PHP que es lo que estás recibiendo haciendo un `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Esto estoy recibiendo: array (size=1)
  'anio' => string '2019' (length=4)

Sin embargo el la suma me da cero. Suma: 0

Comment: @JimMorrison edita tu pregunta poniendo el código donde recuperas los datos del `$_POST`, pues según el `var_dump` los datos están llegando bien.

Comment: Leí tu artículo https://wikipedia.redcomani.org/es.stackoverflow.com_spa_all_2018-08/A/question/81028.html alguna experiencia con maracdores de posicion (?)  cuado se realiza una suma en base a una condcion en mi caso el campo año que es de tipo caracter. Parace que hay una extraña incompatibilidad cuando se usa marcadores de posicion cuando el campo es de tipo caracter. Algo parecido a mi caso encontré aquí:   https://steakrecords.com/es/610860-pdo-prepared-statement-over-odbc-sybase-ldquoparam-datastreamrdquo-error-php-pdo-odbc-sybase-ase.html

Comment: @JimMorrison la pregunta/respuesta original [es esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81028/29967), aunque no se pudo completar debido a que por su extensión no se adaptaba al formato se Stackoverflow. En cuanto al tema que nos ocupa, si has constatado que el uso de marcadores de posición da problemas, puedes usar marcadores de nombre.

Comment: Tambié lo hice con marcadores de nombre y llego a lo mismo que con el otro marcador (?).