# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: php, pdo

estoy intentando validar un login mediante php PDO y me genera el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':correo AND clave=4d3265d618704ab7222e7db516d4d67c9670052a' at line 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\php\loguear.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\php\loguear.php(8): PDO->query('select * from u...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\php\loguear.php on line 8

El campo clave al momento del registro se almacena usando la función  SHA1. gracias de antemano

```
1<?php 
2 //session_start();
3 include "./conexion.php";
4 if(isset($_POST['correo']) && isset($_POST['clave']) ){
5
6  $sql = $conexion->query("select * from usuario where 
7  correo= :correo AND 
8  clave=".sha1(":clave"))or die($conexion->errorInfo());
9  $resultado=$conexion->prepare($sql);
10 $correo=htmlentities(addcslashes($_POST['correo']));
11 $clave=htmlentities(addcslashes("'".sha1($_POST['clave'])."'"));
12 $resultado->binValue(":correo", $correo);
13 $resultado->binValue(sha1(":clave"), $clave);
14 $resultado->execute();
15 $datos_usuario=$resultado->rowCount(); 
16 
17  if($datos_usuario!=0){
18    $nombre = $datos_usuario[1];
19    $id_usuario = $datos_usuario[0];
20    $correo = $datos_usuario[3];
21    //$imagen_perfil = $datos_usuario[5];
22    $id_nivel_usuario= $datos_usuario[8];
23    $_SESSION['datos_logueo']= array(
24        'nombre'=>$nombre,
25        'id_usuario'=>$id_usuario,
26        'correo'=>$correo,
27        //'imagen'=>$imagen_perfil,
28        'id_nivel_usuario'=>$id_nivel_usuario
29
30    ); 
31    header("Location: ../planes.php");
32
33    }else{
34    header("location: ../login.php?error=Datos incorrectos");
35    }
36
37    }
38
39   ?>
```

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo no entendí la edición

Comment: Sólo le di formato a la pregunta para que sea un poquitito más fácil leer el mensaje de error. De resto, no tengo nada que añadir. Tan no tengo nada que añadir que la voté positiva porque está bien formulada :)

Comment: Tienes una mezcla terrible en tu código: consultas preparadas con marcadores de `:nombre` y al mismo tiempo intento de poner valores en las consultas **directamente**, que es justo lo que se quiere evitar cuando se usa consultas preparadas. Es muy sencillo el asunto de las consultas preparadas, en ellas sólo escribes los marcadores (de posición o de nombre, lo que elijas) y los valores los pasas con `bindValue` o con `bindParam` . Otra cosa es que si los datos del POST no van a ser mostrades en pantalla no necesitas filtrarlos. Lo digo porque quizá estás abusando de los filtros.

Comment: Además de lo dicho más arriba, estás llamando a `query()` y luego a `prepare()` y luego a `execute()`. Generalmente deberías llamar **únicamente** a `query()` si **NO** es una consulta preparada, en cuyo caso deberías llamar a `prepare()`  y a `execute()` y hacer los bind, por supuesto. Otra cosa más y perdona que sea pesado, [el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sha1.php) dice claramente que se evite el uso de `sha1()`, porque no crea contraseñas seguras. Considera usar `password_hash()` / `password_verify()` en su lugar. Con esas sugerencias podrás encaminar el código.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ok ese código lo construí en base a un tutorial de consultas preparadas con marcadores. Lo único que no coloque igual en base a lo visto en el tutorial fue esta línea de la consulta  $sql = $conexion-> y esta or die($conexion->errorInfo()); ya que en el tutorial la consulta se guarda en una variable $sql = consulta sin más. De la línea 9 hasta la 17 está tal cual solo que en el tutorial no trabajan con un campo encriptado ahora bien independientemente de si use SHA1 ó password_hash() ó password_verify()...... (1/2)

Comment: @A.Cedano ya que la función iría prinicipalmente en el registro de el usuario que es donde almacena la contraseña encriptada a la bd mediante el uso de cualquiera de las funciones antes mencionada, entonces pregunto ¿cómo consulto un campo encriptado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya te decía en comentarios, en tu código hay varios errores y malas prácticas.

Veamos:

1. No puedes usar `query()` (línea 6) y `prepare()` (línea 9) sobre **una misma consulta**. Son dos cosas totalmente distintas, `query()` se usaría para consultas que no necesiten ser preparadas, por ejemplo, consultas que no incluyen datos proporcionados por el usuario o tomados de fuentes externas y no se repiten mucho (`prepare()` podría usarse aunque la consulta no use datos externos, porque las consultas preparadas en esos casos son más rápidas, pero dejemos eso porque no viene al caso ahora).
2. Hay varias cosas mal hechas en la línea 8. Tú **no puedes pasar valores en las consultas preparadas**, eso debe quedar claro. Una consulta preparada tiene unos marcadores con los cuales le dices al SGBD: *donde estoy poniendo este marcador va un dato, el cual te pasaré luego, por otra vía, para que verifiques si no están intentando engañarte*. Si no entiendes eso con claridad, pronto estarás perdido en tu propio código sin entender realmente cómo funcionan las consultas preparadas.
3. En esa misma línea tienes un `die()` invocando a `errorInfo()`. Primeramente, lo que devuelve `errorInfo()` es un array, por lo que no puedes tratarlo como una cadena. Luego, el uso de `die()` generalmente no se recomienda, es mejor controlar tu código. Tampoco se recomienda, en fase de producción, mostrar errores internos del manejador. Conviene cambiar esos mensajes por mensajes personalizados o implementar tu propio manejo de errores.
4. Puede que estés abusando de filtros usando tanto `htmlentities()` como `addcslashes()`. Generalmente los filtros se aplican según la necesidad y el contexto donde vayas a usar/mostrar los datos. En este caso, si esos datos están destinados solamente al contexto de una consulta preparada, **no hace falta ningún otro filtro**, porque quien va a revisar (filtrar) los datos es la API, cuando pases los datos al método (`bindValue()`) en este caso.
5. La documentación dice claramente que no debería confiarse en `sha1()` para generar claves. Pero eso lo dejo bajo tu responsabilidad. Es más recomendable usar `password_hash()` combinado con `password_verify()`
6. La documentación dice claramente que no se debe confiar en `rowCount()` en consultas del tipo  `SELECT`, porque en muchos contextos este método no devuelve el total de filas de una consulta `SELECT`. Aparte de eso, `rowCount()` no es un método `fetch`. En tu código se aprecia que asignas `$datos_usuario` al resultado de `rowCount()` y que luego intentas lecturas como esta: `$datos_usuario[1]` a partir de la línea 18. Con suerte, `rowCount()` te devolverá simplemente la cantidad de filas que trajo esa consulta, pero nunca sus datos. **Para obtener los datos [PDO tiene varios métodos `fetch`  que deberías revisar en la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)**. Si lo que aplicas en tu código era explicado en un tutorial, deberías banear ese tutorial e incluso indicar a su autor de que está desorientando a la gente. Es imposible hacer una lectura de datos de ese modo.

Dicho todo lo anterior, podemos corregir el código del siguiente modo:

```
<?php
    //session_start();
    $correo=!empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;
    $clave=!empty($_POST['clave']) ? $_POST['clave'] : NULL;
    if($correo && $clave ){
        include "./conexion.php";
        $sql = "select * from usuario where correo=:correo AND clave=:clave LIMIT 1";
        if( $stmt=$conexion->prepare($sql) ) {
            $hash=sha1($clave);
            $stmt->binValue(":correo",$correo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->binValue(":clave",$hash,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            /*
             *Para obtener los resultados hay que usar fetch()
             *Es fundamental que entiendas este punto,
             *porque si no tu código se complica
             *Cuando usas fetch() con el parámetro PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, se crea
             *un array asociativo que incluye los nombres de columna de la tabla
             *asociados con sus valores. Haciendo esto, no necesitas luego
             *asociar un array en la variable de sesión, como haces a partir de
             *la línea 23. Es algo que fetch ya hace sólo.
             *Aquí he asumido que las columnas en la tabla se llaman
             *nombre, id_usuario, correo, id_nivel_usuario ... etc
             *si no se llaman así, y te interesa que en la variable de sesión
             *se guarden así, puedes ponerlo como alias en la instrucción SQL
            */

            $mData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            /*
             *Si no hay filas, $mData será false o null
             *de modo que esto basta para verificar
             *si la consulta trajo filas o no
            */
            if ( $mData ) {
                /*
                 *Aquí ocurre lo que decíamos antes ...
                 *No hace falta asignar a mano las claves del array
                 *porque fetch ya lo hace ...
                 *Por otra parte asignaremos una variable $url
                 *para hacer una sola redirección, al final
                */
                $_SESSION['datos_logueo']= $mData;
                $url="../planes.php";
            } else {
                $url="../login.php?error=Datos incorrectos";
            }
      } else {
        /*
          *Evitar mensajes de errorInfo() en producción
          *Como dijimos, errorInfo() devuelve un array, y el mensaje de error 
          *se encuentra en la clave 2 de ese array
        */
        $url="../login.php?error=Datos incorrectos"+$conexion->errorInfo()[2];
          /*Aquí faltaría manejar cuando $correo y/o $clave vienen vacíos*/
      }
  } else {
    $url="../login.php?error=Datos incorrectos ... POST vacío";  
  }
  /*
    *Redireccionamos al valor que tenga $url
  */
  header("Location: $url");
?>
```

### PostData

Me parece que está todo explicado con claridad. Si no entiendes algo, pregunta en comentarios en esta respuesta.

No estoy en contra de los tutoriales, pero debes tener cuidado de dónde aprendes. Lamentablemente, no hay muy buen material de aprendizaje en castellano. Muchos tutoriales son antiguos y enseñan malas prácticas. La documentación de PHP es bastante buena y es la mejor fuente de aprendizaje, por lo general es muy rica en ejemplos de código y las notas de contribución son excelentes. En ese sentido, te recomiendo que no te lances en tutoriales sin antes leer la documentación. A veces uno cree que es tiempo perdido leer la documentación, pero no lo es. Es mucho mejor partir de bases sólidas, que corregir más adelante un código mal escrito.

Si en este mismo caso, lograras hacer funcionar malamente tu código y lo replicas en cientos de archivos, el código funciona, OK, pero es un código plagado de malas prácticas, de errores de seguridad, de funciones obsoletas. Y luego, cuando ese código empiece a dar problemas podrías pasarte meses/años corriegiéndolo en una aplicación más o menos grande.

Si vas a trabajar con PDO. [Esta guía (en inglés)](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) es de lectura obligatoria. Porque enumera todas las posibles malas prácticas (muchas de ellas muy peligrosas) en las que se podría incurrir al usar PDO. En [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81029/29967) a la pregunta *[Consultar y leer datos MySQL mediante PDO de forma segura y eficiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81028/29967)* yo quise traducir parte de esa guía, para que estuviese a disposición de los hispanohablantes, pero es verdad que al ser un tema muy amplio no se adaptaba al formato de Stackoverflow. Pero el esfuerzo está ahí, y lo puedes leer casi todo en castellano.

Comment: Gracias por responder y por la enseñanza impartida, claro igual quedan dudas al respecto puesto a que es algo nuevo para mi, debería en un canal de youtube subir tutoriales en la practica de consultas preparadas en PDO. He entendido el código pero la duda principal se basa aquí      `$_SESSION['datos_logueo']= $mData;
                $url="../planes.php";`  aquí a la variable de sesión se le está asignando el array asociativo contenido en la variable $mData; hasta allí comprendido, pero si por ejemplo yo inicio sesión y me voy a un modulo en donde yo como usuario debo ingresar datos (1/2)

Comment: y en esa  tabla donde se guardan esos datos que yo introduzco en un formulario, pero además también deben guardarse por ejemplo mi id_usuario y mi id_nivel_usuario que están cargados en esa variable de sesión pero el nombre y el correo no son necesarios guardarlos, sino especificamente esos dos id's ¿cómo accedo especificamente a esos dos datos para rescatarlos y almacenarlos?

Comment: @Apalazon, si los datos están en la variable de sesión, entonces tienes que leer la variable de sesión para obtenerlos. Como ya dije, antes de lanzarte a ver tutoriales, sin siquiera saber si están actualizados o qué pŕácticas se recomiendan en ellos, [lee la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php). PHP es uno de los lenguajes mejor documentados y con versión casi completa en castellano. Allí se mantiene todo actualizado y cuando algo no es recomendable o es obsoleto te lo dicen. Y las notas de contribución advierten también sobre posibles fallos...

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: En cuanto a lo que necesitas guardar o no, siempre se recomienda poner en el `SELECT` de la consulta SQL **unicamente aquellos datos que necesites, en vez de poner un `SELECT *`. La solución que te he propuesto trata en todos los casos de reducir líneas de código innecesarias, usando los métodos que existen en la clase PDO en este caso. Dado que no sé cómo se llaman tus columnas ni cuáles necesites exactamente, no las he puesto en el `SELECT` de forma explícita, eso podrás hacerlo sin ninguna dificultad.

Comment: En cuanto a tu duda sobre las variables de sesión, lee la documentación, revisa los ejemplos, luego intenta tu código y si tienes algún error puedes abrir una nueva pregunta y te ayudaremos por aquí. Yo soy de la vieja generación, lo siento, no puedo aprender viendo vídeos de Youtube, necesito leer y ver código escrito y luego hacer ensayos con ese código. Y, aunque quisiera, no tendría tiempo para ponerme a grabar tutoriales... Un saludo.

Comment: jajajaja! entiendo el tema de youtube, pero es que hace falta buen contenido para las nuevas generaciones. Perfecto, seguiré todas sus recomendaciones. Una vez más gracias por lo enseñado y el tiempo invertido.

Comment: Ahh lo otro que se me olvidaba es si finalmente cambiaba la función SHA1 para encriptar las claves.

Comment: @Apalazon puedes cambiar a `password_hash()` / `password_verify()`. Simplemente al momento de insertar debes guardar un hash y al momento de comprobar (SELECT), usas password_verifiy. Te remito de nuevo a la documentación y a este sitio, donde ya hay algunas preguntas/respuestas sobre este tema.

Comment: Si listo, ya había revisado la documentación para usarlo en la inserción pero ahora en esa inserción tengo una súper duda que voy a abrir en otro post

Comment: @Apalazon no hay ningún problema. En Stackoverflow puedes plantear todas las dudas que surjan y siempre habrá alguien que te ayude. En cuanto a esta pregunta, considera marcar la respuesta si ésta te ha mostrado el camino para resolver este problema concreto, de modo que no aparezca como sin resolver. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo haré, gracias

Comment: Saludos, me ha surgido una interrogante con respecto a este post, ¿cómo hago uso del arreglo de sesión  `$_SESSION['datos_logueo']= $mData;` en otro módulo?, si por ejemplo necesito el `id_usuario` en otro módulo para asignarlo a una variable y almacenarlo en la bd.