# ¿Cómo crear un sistema seguro de acceso con php & mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

Analices de acceso sistema seguro de diferentes plataforma **Google** **Payoneer** entre otras plataformas financieras.

En el siguiente analices encontré estas características:

- Al primer intento fallido muestra el código captcha.
- A los 5 intentos la cuenta del usuario es bloqueada por 15 minutos.
- Al tener acceso existan o no los historial de fallo debe responder una pregunta de seguridad para continuar.
- No permite un doble logueo.

> **Otras Referencias:** [crear script de inicio sesión segura](http://es.wikihow.com/crear-un-script-de-inicio-de-sesi%C3%B3n-segura-en-php-y-MySQL)

He logrado corregir mi antiguo código.

> **Nota:** Edite mi pregunta para evitar que exista una posible pregunta duplicada.

**Las correcciones:**

La `ip` continuara bloqueada, no afectara en nada porque al estar bloqueada la `ip` solo se mostrara el código captcha.

He creado una nueva tabla **fail_attempt** con las siguientes columna: algo así mi idea.

```
id_fail_attempt   id_user   attempt   ip       datetime                 time
      1              1        5      ::1   2017-08-23 17:57:46   2017-08-23 18:12:46
```

En la siguiente tabla `login_attempts` se registra los intentos fallidos de la `ip`

```
  id         ip        attempts        datetime               
  1         ::1           2       2017-08-23 17:57:46
```

La tabla `users`

```
id   username   email   password   lastname  active
1     Hola      hola@    Hola        Hola      1
```

Cómo puedo insertar en la tabla `fail_attempt` el `id` del usuario, los intentos fallido, la `ip` el tiempo en el que el usuario estará bloqueado su acceso y como controlar el doble logueo del mismo usuario en el mismo sistema.

**Código completo PHP**

> ¿Cómo añado las nuevas funciones y crear un sistema seguro?

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
$captcha = true;

//
$con =  @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'systemuser');

  if(count($_POST)>0 && isset($_POST["vcode"]) && $_POST["vcode"]!=$_SESSION["vcode"]) {
    $captcha = false;
    $message = "Los caracteres escritos no coinciden con la palabra de verificación. Inténtalo de nuevo.";
  }

  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  //Bloqueamos la ip por un día
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM failed_login WHERE ip='$ip' AND date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()");
  $row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  //Obtenemos datos para comprar intentos y para resetear intentos por su ultimo fecha.
  $failed_login_attempt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['attempts']);
  //Liberamos memoria.
  mysqli_free_result($result);

  if(count($_POST)>0 && $captcha == true) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password"]);
    $username = htmlentities($username);
    $password = htmlentities($password);
    $save_passw = sha1($password);
    $sql = "SELECT * fROM users where username='$username' AND password='$save_passw' AND active='1' ";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $rowU  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $UsernamaDB = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $rowU["username"]);
    $passwordDB = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $rowU["password"]);

    if($failed_login_attempt <1) {
            //Si es su primer intento fallido, incluimos el primer registro en la BD
            $con->query("INSERT INTO failed_login (ip,attempts,date) VALUES ('$ip', 1, NOW())");
            } else {
                if($failed_login_attempt <2){
                //En caso de ya estar en la BD, sacamos el valor y agregamos +1
                $contador = $row['attempts'] + 1;
                $con->query("UPDATE failed_login SET attempts='$contador', date=NOW() WHERE ip = '$ip'");
            }
        }


        if (empty($_POST) === false) {
            $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
            if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
                $message = "Es necesario introducir un nombre de usuario y contraseña";
             } elseif ($username != $UsernamaDB) {
                $message = "El 'Usuario' que has introducido no coincide. ";
             } elseif ($save_passw != $passwordDB) {
                $message = "Tu 'Contraseña' introducido no coincide. ";
             } elseif($save_passw == $passwordDB && $username == $UsernamaDB) {
                $_SESSION["id_user"] = 1;
                $con->query("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE ip = '$ip'");
             }
            }
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
            header("Location:http://localhost/index.php");
        }
?>
<h1><?php if($message!="") { echo $message; } ?></h1>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuario">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
  <!-- captcha-->
  <?php if (isset($failed_login_attempt) && $failed_login_attempt >= 1) { ?>
    <br><img src="image.php" id="phoca-captcha"/>
  <input name="vcode" type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
   <?php } ?>
  <!-- fin-->
  <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión" id="button-login">
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si varios usuarios comparten IP y uno se bloquea por accidente?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro El sistema no es mio amigo lo estaba buscando y lo encontré :) A ello me refiero amigo que el sistema no está bloqueando al usuario si no directamente esta bloqueando la entrada al sistema por medio de la dirección `IP` es decir si la `IP` está bloqueada ningún usuario que comparten la misma dirección `IP` No podrá ingresar al sistema ese es otro punto, y el que mencionas también amigo, lo ideal es no bloquear al sistema, si no al usuario que trata de ingresar con varios intentos fallidos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro y quizás alguna solución para evitar que un usuario se bloque por error es registrar la dirección `IP` única del equipo el que está accediendo al fin de cuentas el único que sabe como esta conformado el sistema seré yo, y mediante la dirección `ip` bloquear el usuario definitivamente si este se conecta en diferentes `ip` de diferentes localidades de países lo que quiero evitar es que un usuario premium comparta el acceso a su cuenta a otras personas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sobre todo lo que intento es crear un sistema seguro algo parecido al sistema de **Payoneer** Este sistema se refleja un poco al sistema de **Payoneer** Si se equivoca en el primer intento este muestra el código captcha y se se equivoca en los 3 intentos este bloquea la cuenta temporalmente por 15 minutos.

Comment: La pregunta en concreto sería esta: Donde crear los campos para guardar la información necesaria para bloquear a un usuario si consigue loguearse al sistema de 5 direcciones de ip que corresponden a países diferentes?

Comment: @Juan La verdad tiene lógica lo que me indicas amigo, pero como evito entonces que el usuario que tiene una cuenta premium comparta su información a otras personas, necesito tener un registro de actividad del usuario, quizás sea de está manera si el usuario inicia sesión en la misma `ip` no registrar ese registro pero si esta en otra `ip` registrarla hasta contabilizar estas irregularidades y bloquear la cuenta, estos sistemas lo tienen implementado las plataformas de Facebook, Hotmail, gmail, pero este caso sería un bloque definitivamente hasta que el usuario contacte con el administrador.

Comment: @Juan He actualizado mi pregunta, puedes ayudarme a corregir el código php, esta mal planteado, esta bloqueando la `ip` y puedes ayudarme a bloquear el usuario especifico en vez de la `ip` y posibles sugerencias o soluciones sobre el bloque definitivo del usuario.

Comment: @juliocpiro amigo crees poder tener una respuesta para este tema :)

Comment: @J.Mick lo primero que recomiendo cambies mysql, y corrijas las sentencias sql.

Comment: @vaavDev no entiendo amigo, la verdad estoy perdido, he tratado de hacerlo mejor aún no he podido migrar completamente a las nuevas versiones de mysqli a orientados a objetos.

Comment: @J.Mick sorry es que perdi el internet, mi recomendación seria que usaras PDO en vez de mysqli_query, ya sea de manera nativa u objeto, porque es muchisimo mas seguro, revisa esta respuesta que doy a otra persona: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80133/convertir-pdo-a-mysqli/80141#80141 - https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97719/encriptar-contrase%C3%B1a-o-datos-md5-sha1/97724#97724

Comment: @vaavDev amigo te juro que lo estuve intentando mira https://ideone.com/MIH7IP y me han imprimido algunos errores, no parece ser muy extenso mi código php porque no me ayudas a encriptar-contraseña como lo has dicho en tu respuesta, y a crear las consultas el código en mysqli orientados a objetos, yo se que es más seguro PDO, pero alguna penas estoy comprendiendo lo que es mysqli a orientados a objetos ayúdame a migrar al menos a migrar olvidando el resto y te doy los 200 puntos.

Comment: @J.Mick pues, la idea es que tu aprendas :), de nada sirve que te hagan las cosas, ademas es sencillo migrar a PDO, mucho mas sencillo que mysqli, te pasare el , y trabajar con PDO OO, tambien es facil, dejame publicarte la clase PDO que yo uso, y tambien pasarte una guia de ejemplos en PDO normal sin clase:

Comment: @vaavDev Esa es la idea pero con ejemplos sencillos, básicos y complicados aprendo, por ejemplo ya se en consultas sencillas con mysqli a orientado a objetos pero en esta no se me perdí como ya te habrás dado cuenta en el link que te pase, PDO no creo por ahora amigo debo ir por pasos, la verdad PDO tienes unos nombres raros que no lo entiendo aún no lo he estudiado apenas estamos en el modulo de mysqli a orientado a objetos.

Comment: @J.Mick leete este material => https://phpdelusions.net/pdo
y revisa este github

Comment: @J.Mick https://github.com/vaavJSdev/php-pdo-ejemplos/blob/master/guia.md

Comment: Hola @J.Mick, en la pregunta hay varios requerimientos, exactamente que es lo que te falta?

Comment: @juliocpiro No son requerimientos amigo, es solo un análisis de sitios seguros de algunas plataformas, que en fín si me gustaría implementar pero lo que realmente deseo es tener un sitio seguro ya el captcha ya esta añadido al primer intento fallido ahora lo que quiero implementar es bloquear el usuario después de haber fallado acceder 5 veces y evitar el doble logueo y si existe la posibilidad tomar en cuenta el análisis. Pero mi pregunta se basa es a lo que te acabo de comentar amigo :) pero no en PDO :)

Comment: ok, ya publique mi respuesta, revisalo amigo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Desde mi punto de vista ante todo debes proteger su Base de datos ante posibles ataques de inyección, piensa, para que sirve crear un sistema de login avanzado si después uno podría modificar fácilmente su Base de datos.  Para ello podrías usar [mysqli::prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php).

Si quieres saber más [como evitar la inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php), te dejo esta pregunta con grandes respuestas en SOes.

En mi ejemplo utilizo `mysqli::prepare`, el principal y más esencial beneficio de las declaraciones preparadas es la eliminación de todos los peligros del formato manual.

Otro factor importante es el almacenaje de contraseñas seguras. En mi ejemplo utilizo [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php), para comprobar si la contraseña conciden, importante, cuando registras un nuevo usuario utiliza la función [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) para crear un hash de contraseña seguro (No utilice `sha1` o `md5`, ya que son vulnerables).

Mas información sobre [Almacenamiento de contraseñas PHP y MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%C3%B1as-php-y-mysql)
 en SOes.

*Ejemplo crear un hash de contraseña:*

```
$contrasena = password_hash($_POST['contrasena'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

> **BCRYPT**, siempre tendrá 60 caracteres.

**Ejemplo completo:**

Voy a poner un posible ejemplo a tus deseos.

Desde mi punto de vista al primer intento mostrar el código captcha, podría ser incomodo, ya que un usuario se equivoca fácilmente en el primer intento, vamos a poner en el 3 intento, aunque este valor se podría modificar como uno desea en realidad.

Compuse el sistema basándome en los siguientes puntos (probado en localhost):

- 3 intento, mostramos el código captcha y incrementamos.
- 5 intento desactivamos el usuario durante 15min.
- Intento 8 fallido en `login_Attempts`, se bloquea el login durante 1 día por IP.
- En el intento 10, inactivamos el usuario hasta contactar con el
  administrador.
- En caso introducir datos no validos inserta un intento fallido mediante su IP.
- Inicia sesión mediante usuario y correo electrónico.
- Seguridad en la Base de datos mediante sentencias preparadas.
- password_hash, un hash de contraseña usando un algoritmo de hash
  fuerte de único sentido.

Lo del doble logueo, personalmente no lo veo cómodo para los usuarios, siempre hay que mirar la comodidad del usuario y en ocasiones depende la aplicación es más cómodo trabajar con dos sesiones abiertas en diferentes ordenadores, piensa que si uno realmente quiere podría también fácilmente, grabar la pantalla de su aplicación y dárselo a terceros XD.

*Base de datos*

```
CREATE TABLE `fail_attempt` (
  `id_fail_attempt` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attempt` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `login_attempts` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  `ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `attempts` smallint(2) NOT NULL,  
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL unique,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL unique,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` smallint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `lastname`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'Daniel', 'tucorreo@dominio.com', '$2y$10$IptiWEQlWuIZHPvl7wVXfele2nKi1ics9EuTzeHv29MT7KUZfYTGa', 'Bulten', 1);
```

> **Nota:** Para hacer pruebas la contraseña con hash `$2y$10$IptiWEQlWuIZHPvl7wVXfele2nKi1ics9EuTzeHv29MT7KUZfYTGa` equivale a `123` y deberás modificar el correo electrónico al suyo si uno quiere.

*index.php*

```
    <?php
      //Arrancamos sesión.
      session_start();
      //Comprobamos si esta iniciado sesión, caso contrario redirigimos al login.
      if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) { header('Location:login.php'); }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es-ES">
    <body>
        Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>  
        <a href="logout.php">Cerrar sesión</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*conexion.php* (Estilo orientado a objetos).

```
    <?php
        //Configuración.
        $ServerName = "Localhost";
        $Username = "root";
        $PassWord = "root";
        $DataBase = "login_stackoverflow";    

        //Creamos conexión.
        $con = new mysqli($ServerName, $Username, $PassWord, $DataBase);

        //Comprobamos conexión.
        if ($con->connect_error) {
            exit("La conexión fallo: " . $con->connect_error);
        }

        //Caracteres UTF-8 para MySQL.
        if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
            printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $con->error);
            exit();
        }
    ?>
```

*login.php*

En mi ejemplo he usado en vede usuario el correo electrónico para iniciar sesión, ya que es unique como un usuario, aunque este valor es fácilmente modificable por usuario si uno desea.

```
    <?php
    //Arrancamos sesión.
    session_start();

    //Caso estar iniciado sesión, redirigimos automatico al index.
    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) { header('Location:index.php'); }
    //Conexión -> SQL
    require_once'conect.php';
    //Calculamos intentos fallidos por IP.
    $stmtIP = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts,datetime FROM login_attempts WHERE ip=?");
    //Ligar parametros marcadores.
    $stmtIP->bind_param("s",$addres);   
    //Obtenemos IP.
    $addres = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//Ip          
    //Ejecutar sentencia.
    $stmtIP->execute();             
    //Ligar variables de resultados BD.
    $stmtIP->bind_result($totalattempt,$getdatetime);
    //Obtenemos valores.
    $stmtIP->fetch();   
    //Cerrar sentencia.
    $stmtIP->close();   
    //Si supera más de 10 intentos, el IP quedara inactivo durante 1 dia.
    if ($totalattempt===8) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['inactivo1day'])) {
            $_SESSION['inactivo1day'] = true;
        }
        //Reseteo intentos a 0 pasado 1 dia.
        if(strtotime($getdatetime) <= strtotime("-1 day")) { // -15 minutes podria ser -30minutes, -1hours, -day etc...
            //Sentencia.
            $stmtDel = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE ip=?");
            //Ligar parametros marcadores.
            $stmtDel->bind_param("s",$addres);          
            $stmtDel->execute();
            //Cerrar sentencia.
            $stmtDel->close();
            //Eliminamos session inactivo
            unset($_SESSION['inactivo1day']);           
            //Redirigimos a login
            echo '<script>window.location="login.php"</script>';
        } else {
            //Mensaje cuenta desactivado durante 15min.
            $msg = "La IP ha quedado desactivado desde las {$getdatetime}, durante 1 dia., intentelo más tarde.";
        }           
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>  
    <!-- Libreria jQuery. -->       
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  

    <meta charset="utf-8" /><!-- Character encoding. -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Formulario login.
            $(document).on('submit', '#login-form', function() {  
                //Data formulario    
                var data = $(this).serialize();                 
                $.ajax({        
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : 'login_control.php',
                    data : data,
                    success :  function(data) {            
                        $("#result-login").html(data);  
                    }
                });             
                return false;    
            });         
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <?php   
    if (!isset($_SESSION['inactivo1day'])) {            
        //En caso estar activado la sesión del captcha, se ativa el formulario captcha.         
    ?>      
            <h2>Por favor, introduce tu usuario / correo electrónico y contraseña para comenzar.</h2>               
            <form method="POST" id="login-form">                            
                <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario / Correo electrónico *" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a *" /> 
                <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['captchaValidar'])) {
                ?>
                <h2>Verifica los caracteres del 'Captcha' para continuar</h2>
                <img src='captcha_code.php' />              
                <input name='captcha_code' type='text' placeholder='Codigo captcha' />  
                <?php
                }
                ?>


                <button type="submit">Inicia sesión</button>                    
            </form>
            <br />
            <div id="result-login">
            <!-- Respuesta AJAX -->
                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['captchaValidar'])) {
                    echo $_SESSION['captchaValidar'];
                } ?>
            </div>      
        <?php

    } else {
        echo $msg;
    }
    ?>      
</body>
</html>
```

*login_control.php*

```
<?php
//Arrancamos sesión.
session_start();
//Zona region. 
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");

//Reseteo de variables.
$msg = $usuario = $password = $captcha_code = NULL;

//Definido formulario y no es NULL.
if (isset($_POST) && !isset($_SESSION['captchaValidar'])) {

    //Inputs vacios.
    if (empty($_POST['usuario'])) {
        $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>El usuario / correo electrónico es obligatorio.";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>La contraseña es obligatorio.";
    } else {
        //Obtenemos datos inputs.
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'] ?: '';
        $password = $_POST['password'] ?: '';
    }

    //Datos son verdadero.
    if ($usuario && $password) {        
        //Conexión -> SQL
        require_once'conect.php';
        //Obtenemos IP.
        $addres = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//Ip      
        //Comprobamos si existe usuario en la BD.
        //Sentencia.
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=? LIMIT 1");
        //Ligar parametros marcadores, es decir, el valor ?, es decir email='$usuario' y las "s", estamos diciendo que $usuario es un string (cadena), si existen más, es importante su orden.
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$usuario,$usuario);
        //Ejecutar sentencia.
        $stmt->execute();
        //Devuelve el número de filas de un conjunto de resultados de una sentencia.
        $stmt->store_result();
        //Comprobamos si existen registros
        if ($stmt->num_rows===1) {
            //Ligamos los datos desde la BD.
            $stmt->bind_result($id_user,$usernameBD,$passwordHASH);
            if ($stmt->fetch()) {

                //Comprobamos si el usuario esta desactivado  o tiene algun intento fallido, utilizamos el 'ID' del usuario.
                $stmtA = $con->prepare("SELECT attempt,datetime FROM fail_attempt WHERE id_user=? LIMIT 1");
                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                $stmtA->bind_param("i",$id_user);               
                //Ejecutar sentencia.
                $stmtA->execute();
                //Devuelve el número de filas de un conjunto de resultados de una sentencia.
                $stmtA->store_result();
                //Con esta variable sabemos si necesitamos un insert o un update, ya que si encuentra  0 registros es insert y si es 1 va ser un update.
                $check_attempt = $stmtA->num_rows;
                //Ligar variables de resultados BD.
                $stmtA->bind_result($attempts,$getdatetime);
                //Obtenemos valores.
                $stmtA->fetch();    
                //Cerrar sentencia.
                $stmtA->close();

                //Mientras los intentos no supera a 11, continuamos con el login.
                if ($attempts < 11) {
                    //Si existen 5 intentos fallidos, no continua con el login, sino esta en modo desactivado durante x tiempo.
                    if ($attempts==5) {
                        //Reseteo intentos a 6 pasado 15min., para continuar y evitar en este bucle.
                        if(strtotime($getdatetime) <= strtotime("-1 minutes")) { // -15 minutes podria ser -30minutes, -1hours, -dia etc...
                            //Sentencia.
                            $stmtUp = $con->prepare("UPDATE fail_attempt SET attempt=?, ip=?  WHERE id_user=? LIMIT 1");
                            //Ligar parametros marcadores (???, es decir, $attempt='$int' and $ip='$addres' etc...).
                            $stmtUp->bind_param("isi", $int,$addres,$id_user);
                            //valores parametros marcadores.        
                            $int = 6;//Inilizamos en 6 intentos.
                            //Ejecutar sentencia.
                            $stmtUp->execute();
                            //Cerrar sentencia.
                            $stmtUp->close();
                            //Eliminamos session inactivo
                            unset($_SESSION['inactivo15']);
                            //Alerta.
                            echo '<script>window.alert("Pasaron 15min., su cuenta ha sido activado");</script>';
                            //Redirigimos a acceder
                            echo '<script>window.location="login.php"</script>';
                        } else {
                            //Mensaje cuenta desactivado durante 15min.
                            $msg = "Tu cuenta ha quedado desactivado desde las {$_SESSION['inactivo15']}, durante 15min., intentelo más tarde.";
                        }           
                    } else {
                        //En caso contrario continuamos con el login.

                        //Comprobamos password mediante la función password_verify.
                        if (password_verify($password, $passwordHASH)) {//Correcto, creamos la sesión del usuario.                                      
                            //Reseteamos intentos fallidos.
                            if ($check_attempt===1) {
                                //Reseteamos intentos en 0 para fail_attempt.
                                //Sentencia.
                                $stmtUp = $con->prepare("UPDATE fail_attempt SET attempt=?, ip=?, datetime=? WHERE id_user=? LIMIT 1");
                                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                                $stmtUp->bind_param("issi",$reset_attempt,$addres,$datetime,$id_user);
                                //Creo valores marcadres.
                                $reset_attempt = 0;
                                //id_user ya lo hemos obtenido en la comprobacion si existe el usuario.
                                //Adrres ya es obtenido anteriormente.                      
                                $datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
                                //Ejecutar sentencia.
                                $stmtUp->execute();
                                //Cerrar sentencia.
                                $stmtUp->close();

                                //Eleminas registro de login_attempts
                                //Sentencia.
                                $stmtDel = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE ip=?");
                                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                                $stmtDel->bind_param("s",$addres);          
                                $stmtDel->execute();
                                //Cerrar sentencia.
                                $stmtDel->close();
                            }
                            //Creamos sesión al usuario.
                            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usernameBD;         
                            //Redirigimos a pagina protegida
                            echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';

                        } else { //Contraseña incorrecto, añadimos intentos fallidos.                                   

                            //Actualizamos intentos usuario.
                            if ($check_attempt===0) {                       
                                //Insertar primer intento fallido.

                                //Sentencia.
                                $stmtIn = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO fail_attempt (id_user,attempt,ip,datetime) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                                $stmtIn->bind_param("iiss",$id_user,$attempts,$addres,$datetime);
                                //Creo valores marcadres.
                                //id_user ya lo hemos obtenido en la comprobacion si existe el usuario.
                                //Adrres ya es obtenido anteriormente.
                                $attempts = 1;
                                $datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
                                //Ejecutar sentencia.
                                $stmtIn->execute();
                                //Cerrar sentencia.
                                $stmtIn->close();
                            } else {
                                //Actualizar, es decir, incrementar intento fallido.
                                //Sentencia.
                                $stmtUp = $con->prepare("UPDATE fail_attempt SET attempt=attempt+1, ip=?, datetime=? WHERE id_user=?");
                                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                                $stmtUp->bind_param("ssi",$addres,$datetime,$id_user);
                                //Creo valores marcadres.
                                //id_user ya lo hemos obtenido en la comprobacion si existe el usuario.
                                //Adrres ya es obtenido anteriormente.                      
                                $datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
                                //Ejecutar sentencia.
                                $stmtUp->execute();
                                //Cerrar sentencia.
                                $stmtUp->close();

                                //A no actualizar el navegador, incremento manualmente el attemp
                                $attempts = $attempts +1;       

                            }

                            //Comprobamos si ha excedido más de 8 intentos fallidos mediante su IP.                         
                            //Sentencia
                            $stmtIP = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM login_attempts WHERE ip=?");
                            //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                            $stmtIP->bind_param("s",$addres);                               
                            //Ejecutar sentencia.
                            $stmtIP->execute();
                            //Devuelve el número de filas de un conjunto de resultados de una sentencia.
                            $stmtIP->store_result();
                            //Comprobamos si existen algun registro, para asi diferenciar si hacer un insert o update.  
                            $check_ip_attempts = $stmtIP->num_rows;         
                            //Ligar variables de resultados BD.
                            $stmtIP->bind_result($ip_attempts);
                            //Obtenemos valores.
                            $stmtIP->fetch();   
                            //Cerrar sentencia.
                            $stmtIP->close();               


                            //Insertar fallo a tabla login_attempts mediante su IP.
                            if ($check_ip_attempts===0) { 

                                //Sentencia.
                                $stmtIn = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO login_attempts (ip,attempts,datetime) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                                $stmtIn->bind_param("sis",$addres,$int,$datetime);
                                //Creo valores marcadres.                                   
                                //Adrres ya es obtenido anteriormente.                                  
                                $int = 1;
                                $datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
                                //Ejecutar sentencia.
                                $stmtIn->execute();
                                //Cerrar sentencia.
                                $stmtIn->close();
                            } else { //Update fallo IP.
                                //Sentencia.
                                $stmtUp = $con->prepare("UPDATE login_attempts SET ip=?, attempts=attempts+1, datetime=? WHERE ip=?");
                                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                                $stmtUp->bind_param("sss",$addres,$datetime,$addres);
                                //Creo valores marcadres.                               
                                //Adrres ya es obtenido anteriormente.                      
                                $datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
                                //Ejecutar sentencia.
                                $stmtUp->execute();
                                //Cerrar sentencia.
                                $stmtUp->close();
                                //Incrementamos manualmente, a no actualizar navegador.
                                $ip_attempts = $ip_attempts+1;
                            }

                            //IP esta bloqueda.
                            if ($ip_attempts===8) {     
                                $_SESSION['inactivo1day'] = true;
                                //Redirigimos a acceder
                                echo '<script>window.location="login.php"</script>';        
                            }

                            //Mensajes contraseña fallidos.

                            //Primer fallo, mostramos el captcha.
                            if ($attempts<2) {
                                $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>Tu contraseña es incorrecto, vuelva a intentarlo.";   
                            } elseif ($attempts ==3) {                              
                                //Arrancamos sesión del captcha.
                                $_SESSION['captchaValidar'] = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>Tu contraseña es incorrecto, vuelva a intentarlo.<p>";
                                echo '<script>window.location="login.php"</script>';                            
                            } elseif ($attempts==4) {
                                $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>Tu contraseña es incorrecto, te queda un intento más para desactivar su cuenta durante 15min.</p>";
                            } elseif ($attempts==5) {
                                $_SESSION['inactivo15'] = date("H:i:s");
                                $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>Tu cuenta ha quedado desactivada desde las {$_SESSION['inactivo15']}, durante 15min., intentelo más tarde.</p>";
                            } elseif ($attempts <=9) {
                                $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>Tu contraseña es incorrecto, vuelva a intentarlo.<p>";
                            } elseif ($attempts<=10) {
                                $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>Tu contraseña es incorrecta, llevas 9 intentos fallidos, te queda un intento más, sino deberás ponerte en contacto con administración.</p>";
                            } else {
                                $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>Tu cuenta ha quedado desactivada, por favor ponte en contacto con admin@admin.com para activar su cuenta de nuevo.</p>";
                            }                           
                        }
                    }                   
                } else {
                //Supera el maximo de intentos permitido, cuenta esta inactivo durante X tiempo.
                    $msg = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>Tu cuenta ha quedado desactivada, por favor ponte en contacto con admin@admin.com para activar su cuenta de nuevo.";                          
                }
            } $stmt->close();
        } else {
            //Cerrar sentencia.
            $stmt->close(); 

            //Comprobamos si ha excedido más de 8 intentos fallidos mediante su IP.                         
            //Sentencia
            $stmtIP = $con->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM login_attempts WHERE ip=?");
            //Ligar parametros marcadores.
            $stmtIP->bind_param("s",$addres);                               
            //Ejecutar sentencia.
            $stmtIP->execute();
            //Devuelve el número de filas de un conjunto de resultados de una sentencia.
            $stmtIP->store_result();
            //Comprobamos si existen algun registro, para asi diferenciar si hacer un insert o update.  
            $check_ip_attempts = $stmtIP->num_rows;         
            //Ligar variables de resultados BD.
            $stmtIP->bind_result($ip_attempts);
            //Obtenemos valores.
            $stmtIP->fetch();   
            //Cerrar sentencia.
            $stmtIP->close();


            //IP esta bloqueda.
            if ($ip_attempts===8) {     
                $_SESSION['inactivo1day'] = true;
                //Redirigimos a acceder
                echo '<script>window.location="login.php"</script>';        
            }

            if ($check_ip_attempts===0) { //Insert fallo IP.

                //Sentencia.
                $stmtIn = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO login_attempts (ip,attempts,datetime) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                $stmtIn->bind_param("sis",$addres,$int,$datetime);
                //Creo valores marcadres.                                   
                //Adrres ya es obtenido anteriormente.                                  
                $int = 1;
                $datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
                //Ejecutar sentencia.
                $stmtIn->execute();
                //Cerrar sentencia.
                $stmtIn->close();
            } else { //Update fallo IP.
                //Sentencia.
                $stmtUp = $con->prepare("UPDATE login_attempts SET ip=?, attempts=attempts+1, datetime=? WHERE ip=?");
                //Ligar parametros marcadores.
                $stmtUp->bind_param("sss",$addres,$datetime,$addres);
                //Creo valores marcadres.                               
                //Adrres ya es obtenido anteriormente.                      
                $datetime = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', time());
                //Ejecutar sentencia.
                $stmtUp->execute();
                //Cerrar sentencia.
                $stmtUp->close();
            }           

            //Arrancamos sesión del captcha.
            $_SESSION['captchaValidar'] = "<p style='background-color:red; color:white; padding:1rem; margin-top:1rem; max-width:300px;'>El usuario / correo electrónico no existen.<p>";
            echo '<script>window.location="login.php"</script>';
        }
    }
} else {
    //Comprobamos que esten escrito correctamente los caracteres del captcha.
    if ($_POST["captcha_code"]!=$_SESSION["captcha_code"]) {                            
        $msg = "<div class='dangerB font1'>Los caracteres escritos no coinciden con la palabra de verificación. Inténtalo de nuevo.</div>";
    } else { //Caracteres coinciden.
        //Destruimos la sesión.             
        unset($_SESSION['captchaValidar']);
        //Redirigimos al login.
        echo '<script>window.location="login.php"</script>';
    }   
}
//Respuesta Ajax
echo $msg;
?>
```

*captcha_code.php*

> **Nota:** deberas crear dos carpetas `font/SpecialElite.ttf` y `img/captcha.png`, dicha imagen o fuente pueden ser personalizados a gusto de cada uno.

```
<?php
session_start();
$random_alpha = md5(rand());
$captcha_code = substr($random_alpha, 0, 6); // Numero total de caracters en el captcha

$_SESSION["captcha_code"] = $captcha_code;
$target_layer = imagecreatefrompng("img/captcha.png"); /// Fondo personalizado para el sistema de captcha.
$textColor = imagecolorallocate($target_layer, 71,171,118); // Color de la fuente
$lineColor = imagecolorallocate($target_layer, 255,255,255); // Color de las lineas del captcha
$imageInfo = getimagesize("img/captcha.png"); // fondo de la imagen

$linesToDraw = 40; // numero total de lineas en el captcha

for( $i = 10; $i < $linesToDraw; $i++ )  {      
    $xStart = mt_rand( 0, $imageInfo[ 0 ] );
    $xEnd = mt_rand( 0, $imageInfo[ 0 ] );    
    imageline($target_layer, $xStart, 0, $xEnd, $imageInfo[1], $lineColor );    
}

imagettftext($target_layer, 35, 2, 41, 50, $textColor, "font/SpecialElite.ttf", $captcha_code );

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($target_layer);
imagedestroy($target_layer); 
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    //Activar sesión.
    session_start();
    //Remover sesión.
    session_unset();
    //Destruir sesión.
    session_destroy();
    //Redirigimos
    header('location: login.php');
?>
```

> Estructura para hacer pruebas facilmente en `localhost`:

**RAIZ**
font / SpecialElite.ttf ([font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Special+Elite))
img / captcha.png (dimensiones: 250x60 pixeles)
captcha_code.php
conect.php
index.php
login.php
login_control.php
logout.php

Comment: Grandes conocimientos amigo +1, no esperaba menos de ti, conectate al face :)

Comment: @J.Doe gracias amigo. Eso intento, al menos ayudar y aprender también. Si he estado un poco desconectado, ya te comentaré por Facebook, que ahora mismo estoy con el móvil. Un abrazo

Comment: @D.Bulten vaya ejemplo, has eliminado una tabla, en una tabla quería almacenar los intentos fallidos de la `ip` para bloquear la `ip` si existen varios intentos fallidos por medio de esa tabla controlaría aquella `ip` que esta sufriendo ataques de seguridad, y en la otra tabla controlaría lo del usuario bloquear el usuario y inactivarlo como lo has indicado después de varios fallos algo así como ha implementado la base de datos en la respuesta de  juliocpiro

Comment: @D.Bulten Te acuerdas de la validación del **Wizard** ya existe una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96689/c%C3%B3mo-validar-datos-del-proceso-wizard-con-php) aún faltaría pequeños detalles ya te comentare como podríamos usarlo.

Comment: @J.Mick el código que puse siempre podrías crear un historial de fallos como tienes. Aún así podrían existir varios usuarios con el mismo IP desde ordenadores diferentes, así que siempre tendrás que añadir el id del usuario para evitar bloquear al resto de usuarios, por ese motivo solo utilizó una tabla con las mismas informaciones. Puse un ejemplo alternativa a los que hay, ya que la seguridad MySQL es también importante.

Comment: @J.Mick he modificado mi respuesta a tus deseos, a ver si te he entendido bien y he acertado, he puesto en el intento 1 se muestra el código captcha y si incremente el historial de `login_attempts`, cuando `fail_attempt` tiene 5 fallos el usuario será independiente bloqueado durante 15min., en caso que existen 10 será bloqueado hasta contactar con administración. Si hubiera 8 intentos fallidos en `login_attempts` el login queda desactivado durante 1 día por su `IP`. Ya me comentas, un saludo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65716/discussion-between-j-mick-and-d-bulten).

Comment: @D.Bulten Lo siento J.Mick por no dar la recompensa a esta respuesta pero debo ser justa al tiempo dedicado a la respuesta dada la recompensa sin embargo +1 y la pregunta como solucionada creo que si llegara al menos unos 100 puntos.

Comment: Gracias @May , no pasa nada, la respuesta de Juliocpiro es una gran respuesta también, como otros más que hay. Suerte y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es

1. En la tabla `login_attempts` cambiar el atributo `ip` por `user_id` o `username` (en el caso que no se repita) para establecer la relación por usuario en vez de por IP.
2. Cambiar la consulta en la query `$result5` para obtener los datos por el `user_id` que esta haciendo la conexión.
3. Si el bloqueo debe ser por siempre hay que quitar de `login_attempts` el atributo `time` o asignarlo en una fecha muy lejana con el bloqueo.
4. `$message` debería mostrar el mensaje de contacte al admin cuando llega al 5 error antes podrías mostrar el número de veces que ha fallado.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma de abordar este tipo de problemas es mediante una clase para poder tener una mínima abstracción.

Te expondré un ejemplo básico intentando no complicarlo demasiado de forma que se pueda entender facilmente el código, la realice de forma rápida por lo que tiene algunas carencias.

La clase nos permite:

- Validar un usuario, permitiendo un número de intentos en un tiempo determinado (por defecto 5 intentos en 1 minuto).
- Bloquear el usuario de forma permanente si se supera el tope máximo (por defecto 10 intentos en 1 minuto).
- Recuperar los datos del usuario
- Mantener un registro de login realizados.
- Conocer la IP.

La denegación de acceso y bloqueo de acceso, se realiza sobre el usuario sin tener en cuenta la IP, esto no quita que se pueda implementar un método para tal fin.

Deberemos tener las siguientes tablas en nuestra base de datos:

### users

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `login_success` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

### login_log

```
CREATE TABLE `login_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=112 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Creamos una clase básica para la conexión a la base de datos

### Class Conexion

```
class Conexion
{
    private $servidor ="localhost";
    private $usuario ="user";
    private $contrasena ="pass";
    private $nombre_bd ="login";
    public $link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->contrasena, $this->nombre_bd) or die("Error con la base de datos.");

        if ($this->link->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit;
        }
        if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
            printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
            exit;
        }

    }
}
```

### Clase LoginController

```
// Declaramos la clase y extendemos de Conexion
class LoginController extends Conexion
{
    // Datos recuperados del usuario, puede ser util para crear las sesiones
    public $dataUser = null;
    // Nombre de usuario a validar
    public $username;
    // Contraseña a validar
    public $password;
    // IP conexion user
    public $ip;
    // Numero de intentos antes de denegar el acceso
    public $attempt = 5;
    // Numero de intentos antes de bloquear al usuario
    public $attemptBan = 10;
    // Tiempo para los intentos en segundos
    public $attempt_time = 60;
    // Fecha actual
    public $now;
    // Fecha actual menos $attempt_time
    public $nowDiff;
    // mensaje del resultado del acceso
    public $msg;
    // salt para la encriptacion 
    protected $salt = '$6$rounds=5000$estoesunstringdesalt$';

    public function __construct()
    {
        /* Inicializamos la conexion a la base de datos */
        parent::__construct();

        /* Establecemos la IP */
        $this->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $time = new DateTime();
        // Establecemos la fecha actual
        $this->now = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $time->modify('-'.$this->attempt_time.' seconds');
        // Establecemos la fecha actual menos (intentos * tiempo por intento)
        $this->nowDiff = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    // Esta funcion se encargara de hacer las validaciones
    public function validate($username, $password)
    {
        // Establecemos usuario y contraseña
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        // Buscamos el usuario en la base de datos
        $sql = 'SELECT id, username, password, login_success, status FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1';
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
        // Comprobamos si se ha encontrado el usuario
        if ($resultado->num_rows)
        {
            $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            // Guardamos los datos del usuario
            $this->dataUser = $row;
            // Comprobamos si esta desactivado
            if (1 != $row['status'])
            {
                // Si esta desactivado registramos en el los el intento y retornanomos false
                $this->loginLog($this->username, $this->now, 'Usuario bloqueado' );
                return false;                    
            }
            // Comprobamos de si la contraseña es correcta
            if( hash_equals( $row['password'], crypt($this->password, $this->salt) ) )
            {
                // Actualizamos el ultimo inicio de sesion correcto
                $this->loginSuccess($row['id']);
                // Comprobamos los intentos
                return $this->attempt();
            }
            else
            {
                // Si la contraseña no es correcta registramos el log y retornamos false
                $this->loginLog($this->username, $this->now, 'Error de password' );
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Si no se encontro el usuario registramos log y retornamos false
            $this->loginLog($this->username, $this->now, 'Error de usuario' );
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Funcion para comprobar los pasos
    protected function attempt()
    {
        // Recuperamos del log los intentos desde la fecha nowDiff
        $sql = 'SELECT count(*) n FROM login_log WHERE username = ? AND fecha > ?';
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $this->username, $this->nowDiff);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
        // Comprobamos si se recuperaron registros
        if ($resultado->num_rows)
        {
            $rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            // Comprobamos si el numero de registros es menor al numero de intentos
            if ($this->attempt >= $rows['n']) 
            {
                // Si es menor a los intentos registramos el acceso y devolvemos true
                $this->loginLog($this->username, $this->now, 'success' );
                return true;
            }
            // Comprobamos si es mayor a attemptBan
            elseif ($this->attemptBan < $rows['n'])
            {
                // registramos el acceso
                $this->loginLog($this->username, $this->now, 'Se ha baneado el usuario' );
                // Bloqueamos el usuario
                $this->userBan();
                // Debolvemos false
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // En cualquier otro caso registramos el acceso y retornamos false
                $this->loginLog($this->username, $this->now, 'Login bloqueado durante '.$this->attempt_time );
                return false;
            }

        }
        // Se nunca se a logeado registramos el acceso
        $this->loginLog($this->username, $this->now, 'success' );
        // Devolvemos true
        return true;
    }

    // Esta funcion se encargara de registrar los accesos
    protected function loginLog($username, $fecha, $msg)
    {
        // registramos el acceso a la base de datos
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO login_log (username, fecha, msg, ip) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ); ';
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $fecha, $msg, $this->ip);
        $stmt->execute();
        // Guardamos el mensaje
        $this->msg = $msg;
        return true;
    }

    // Esta funcion se encarga de actualizar el ultimo acceso
    protected function loginSuccess(int $idUser)
    {
        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET login_success = NOW() WHERE id = '.$idUser;
        $stmt = $this->link->query($sql);
        return true;
    }

    // Esta funcion se encarga de bloquear el usuario
    protected function userBan()
    {
        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE username = ? ;';
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->username);
        $stmt->execute();
    }


    /* Esta funcion solo la pongo a modo ilustrativo para crear un usuario en la bd */
    public function createUser($username, $password)
    {
        $has = crypt($password, $this->salt);
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( ?, ? ); ';
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $has);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        // Cerrramos la conexion
        $this->link->close();
    }
}
```

### Uso básico de la clase

```
// Inicializamos la clase 
$auth = new LoginController();

// Validamos el usuario
if( $auth->validate('nombre_usuario_a_validar', 'contraseña_a_validar') )
{
    // Login OK
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($auth->dataUser);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo $auth->msg;
}
else
{
    // Login KO
    echo $auth->msg;
}
```

> Esta clase, aunque funcional, es una **clase de ejemplo** por lo que
>   no se capturan errores, ni se tienen encuenta que las consultas puedan
>   fallar. Tampoco se liberan los resultados de las consultas ni se 
>   tienen en cuenta la visibilidad de los métodos y propiedades. Entre otras cosas.

Comment: gracias amigo, solo por consultar es indispensable utilizar las class no puedo entenderlas, me cuesta entenderlas, no será posible mejor las function `function dato(){}` o algo similar al código como esta mi pregunta.

Comment: aunque esta muy bien la pregunta amigo :) solo por curiosidad es que me cuesta entender las class

Comment: o un apartado adicional, el código de class esta bien como una fuente de recomendación, lo podrías dejar, puedes crear un apartado sobre un código más simple por ejemplo el de la pregunta pero sin tantos líos ya me doy por vencido, entonces en un apartado solo tomar en cuneta las siguientes características a los 3 intentos fallidos mostrar el captcha, y a los 5 intentos fallidos bloquear el usuario por 15 minutos, registrar la actividad de ingreso al sistema.

Comment: mediante la actividad del usuario puedo bloquearlo desde la administración, así no me complico, ahora en lo que comente esta funcionando aquel código pero esta mal estructurado lo que realiza el código de mi pregunta es bloquear la ip, y lo que realmente debería hacer el bloquear el usuario por 15 minutos, puedes crear un aportado con las características que te comente. ***Es que no me gustan las class, no logro entenderlas a pesar de que la haz comentado perfectamente cada paso es genial, pero aún así no las comprendo***

Comment: Simplificando las cosas, piensa que una clase no es más que un grupo de funciones (métodos) y variables (propiedades), entiendo que no te gusten al principio pueden parecer complejas, pero son bastante simples y útiles, además de ayudar enormemente a separar las cosas (abstracción). @J. Mick , te agradecería que hicieras el intento de intentarlo, valga la redundancia, seguro que en un futuro lo agradeces, estaré por aquí para ayudarte, ahora no tengo tiempo para darte otra respuesta en estilo por procedimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te comento como tenemos nosotros securizado un sistema que gestiona contenido de video premium y evitar el doble uso así como el uso ilegítimo.

**Tablas:**

```
Usuarios
ID - Usuario - Email - Password - NumSession
```

Esta tabla reigstramos los diferentes usuarios, fecha de alta, fecha de modificación de password, etc.

```
Fails
ID - Usuario(nullable) - Email - Password - IP - UserAgent - SessionId - CloudflareID - DateTime
```

Esta tabla la utilizamos para gestionar los fallos erróneos de login, guardamos los datos que ha  enviado en el formulario, asociamos a un usuario si es posible, en nuestro caso utilizamos Cloudflare que nos provee un rico ID de usuario bastante acertado, y poco evitable, jeje, y para prevenir los logins incorrectos utilizamos estos datos, así como el user agent y los session id en vez de la ip. Nosotros utilizamos validación escalada, es decir vamos reduciendo factores para bloquear al usuario dependiendo del nº de intentos.

```
Sessions
ID - Usuario - Inicio - Fin - CloudflareID - IP - UserAgent
```

En esta tabla almacenamos las diferentes sesiones así como su estado, llamamos sesión al momento que el usuario hace login y es ok, primero verificamos que no haya sesiones activas, comparando el date de Fin para ver si está cerrada o no. En nuestro caso tenemos una opción para comprar una suscripción con acceso hasta 5 dispositivos, en este caso el número máximo de sessiones es de 5.

Dentro de nuestra plataforma al ser retransmisión en streaming se hacen peticiones continuas con lo que las sesiones con mas de 120 segundos desde el momento actual se entienden como cerradas

**Otros sistemas de protección activa**
Adicionalmente a lo anterior disponemos de varios sistemas de seguridad activa para prevenir usos no autorizados o compartición de cuentas.

*Seguimiento de dispositivos.*
Utilizando el user Agent y el proveedor de la IP (Movistar, Orange, Vodafone, etc) hemos creado una tabla devices que les asignamos a un usuario, de tal manera que cuando accede desde un dispositivo que anteriormente no ha accedido solicitamos una doble verificación del usuario. Otra funcionalidad es que no pueda acceder desde otros dispositivos. El asunto del proveedor de servicios aún está en pruebas pero apunta maneras XD Aquí también se ha planteado utilizar la resolución dela pantalla, ya que habitualmente vemos las series y películas en pantalla completa, pero aún estamos en pruebas.

*Doble factor de autentificación*
Para cosas "raras" cambio de password, cambio de email, nuevos dispositivos, ip de comunidad distinta, etc solicitamos una doble autentificación, bien por email, authy, SMS, llamada, etc.

*Uso de WAF*
No tengo acciones de Cloudflare, aunque me gustaría, pero en mi concepto de ciberseguridad es fundamental.

Por último te diría que la ciberseguridad hoy en día **es fundamental** en cualquier proyecto, por lo que debería ser gestionada y supervisada por una empresa especializada en este ámbito.

Comment: Adicionalmente a lo anterior te recomendaría utilizar encarecidamente PDO y versiones actualizadas tanto de PHP como de Mysql para evitar vulnerabilidades

Answer (score 0):

He realizado ajustes a tu código implementado lo que solicitas:

- Al primer intento fallido muestra el código captcha.
- A los 5 intentos la cuenta del usuario es bloqueada por 15 minutos.
- No permite un doble logueo.
- A los 8 intentos fallidos la IP es bloqueada por 1 Dia.

**La cantidad de intentos esta en una variable así podrás ajustarlo**. Si no quieres que bloquee la IP podrias ponerle a la variable `$intentosIP` = 1000 por ejemplo, o ajustar el codigo :)

Me gustaría aclarar que para realizar esto hay muchas formas, frameworks, librerías, patrones, etc. Me he limitado a seguir el estilo de tu código y he trabajado sobre ello, pero queda la recomendación de usar por ejemplo Programación Orientada a Objetos, evitar Inyección SQL, etc.

**Base de Datos**
Se mantuvo la Base de Datos publicada, solo a la tabla `users` se le agrego el campo `logindatetime` de tipo `datetime` que servira para validar el doble logueo.

`fail_attempt`

```
id_fail_attempt   id_user   attempt   ip       datetime                 time
      1              1        5      ::1   2017-08-23 17:57:46   2017-08-23 18:12:46
```

`login_attempts`

```
  id         ip        attempts        datetime               
  1         ::1           2       2017-08-23 17:57:46
```

`users`

```
id   username   email                    password                   lastname  active  logindatetime
1     Hola      hola@    4e46dc0969e6621f2d61d2228e3cd91b75cd9edc     Hola      1         NULL
```

"*4e46dc0969e6621f2d61d2228e3cd91b75cd9edc*" es "*Hola*" en `sha1`, al loguerase solo escribir "*Hola*", PHP lo convertira en sha1 para la comparacion con BD.

Cada vez que se agregue un usuario usar la funcion `sha1`, ejemplo:

```
insert into users (id, username, email, password, lastname, active) values (2,'juliocpiro',sha1('12345'),'jcsar',1);
```

**Doble logueo**

Usara el campo `logindatetime` de la tabla `users`. Cuando el usuario se loguea es redireccionado a la pagina `index.php` (codigo original).

En la pagina index.php se invoca un `ajax` que actualiza el campo `logindatetime` para saber que el usuario ha sido logueado satisfactoriamente. Tambien hay un boton `Cerrar Sesion` que limpia el campo `logindatetime`, de modo que cuando el campo esta *NULL* sabemos que el usuario ya no esta logueado.

Para el caso que el usuario cierre el navegador sin antes usar el boton `Cerrar Sesion`, ha considerado invocar al `ajax` cada 1 minuto. De modo que si `logindatetime` tiene una hora de mas de 2 minutos se entenderia que fue una sesion abandonada y se consideraria como que el usuario ya no esta logueado.

**Solucion**

Para correr este codigo, los archivos den estar dentro de una carpeta `login`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**captcha.php** Para generar dinamicamente la imagen captcha

```
<?php
session_start();
function obtenerTexto($longitud) {
    $patron = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";$texto=null;
    for($i=0;$i<$longitud;$i++) {$texto .= $patron{rand(0,35)};}
    return $texto;
}
$_SESSION['vcode'] = obtenerTexto(5);
$imgcaptcha = imagecreatefromgif("fondocaptcha.gif");
$color = imagecolorallocate($imgcaptcha, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($imgcaptcha, 5, 16, 7, $_SESSION['vcode'], $color);

header("Content-type: image/gif");
imagegif($imgcaptcha);
?>
```

requiere de esta imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**login.php** Codigo publicado reajustado

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
$captcha = true;
//indicador usuario logueado
$logueado = false;
//Nro intentos permitidos para IP
$intentosIP = 8;
//Nro intentos permitidos para Usuario
$intentosU = 5;

if(count($_POST)>0 && isset($_POST["vcode"]) && $_POST["vcode"]!=$_SESSION["vcode"]) {
    $captcha = false;
    $message = "Los caracteres escritos no coinciden con la palabra de verificación. Inténtalo de nuevo.";
}else{
    unset($_SESSION['id_user']);
}

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$con =  @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'systemuser');
//Bloqueamos la ip por un día
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login_attempts WHERE ip='$ip' AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()");
$row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
//Obtenemos datos para comprar intentos y para resetear intentos por su ultimo fecha.
$failed_login_attempt=0;
if($row!=null){
    $failed_login_attempt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['attempts']);
}
//Liberamos memoria.
mysqli_free_result($result);

if(count($_POST)>0 && $captcha == true) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password"]);
    $username = htmlentities($username);
    $password = htmlentities($password);
    $save_passw = sha1($password);

    //Buscar usuario ingresado - INICIO
    $sql = "SELECT *, CASE WHEN logindatetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 2 MINUTE ) AND NOW() THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as logueado FROM users where username='$username' AND active='1' ";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $rowU  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $UsernamaDB = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $rowU["username"]);
    $passwordDB = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $rowU["password"]);
    //Buscar usuario ingresado - FIN

    //registra intentos de login segun IP - INICIO
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    if($row==null){
        //Si es su primer intento fallido, incluimos el primer registro en la BD
        $con->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (ip,attempts,datetime) VALUES ('$ip', 1, NOW())");
    }else{
        //se actualiza mientras el nro de intentos este abierto, para evitar bug con calculo del dia bloqueado
        if($row['attempts']<$intentosIP){
            $contador = $row['attempts'] + 1;
            $con->query("UPDATE login_attempts SET attempts='$contador', datetime=NOW() WHERE ip = '$ip'");
        }       
    }
    //registra intentos de login segun IP - FIN

    //VALIDANDO DOBLE LOGUEO
    if($save_passw == $passwordDB && $username == $UsernamaDB && $rowU['logindatetime']!=null && $rowU['logueado']=='1') {
        $logueado = true;
    }else{  
        //registra intentos segun usuario - INICIO
        ////////////////////////////////////////
        $attempU = 0;
        if($UsernamaDB!= null && $UsernamaDB!=''){
            $id_user = $rowU['id'];
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM fail_attempt WHERE id_user ='$id_user' AND datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE ) AND NOW() ");
            $rowFA  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
            if($rowFA==null){
                $con->query("INSERT INTO fail_attempt (id_user, attempt, ip, datetime) VALUES ('$id_user', 1, '$ip', NOW())");
            }else{
                $attempU =$rowFA['attempt']+1;
                //se actualiza mientras el nro de intentos este abierto, para evitar bug con calculo de 15 minutos bloqueado
                if($rowFA['attempt']<$intentosU){
                    $con->query("UPDATE fail_attempt SET attempt='$attempU', ip = '$ip', datetime=NOW() where id_user ='$id_user' ");
                }
            }
        }
        //registra intentos segun usuario - FIN     
    }

    //validando Usuario y Contraseña - INICIO
    $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        $message = "Es necesario introducir un nombre de usuario y contraseña";
    } elseif($failed_login_attempt>=$intentosIP){
        $message = "'IP' bloqueada por 1 dia, contando desde las ".$row['datetime'];
    } elseif($logueado){
        $message = "'Usuario' ya se encuentra logueado.";
    } elseif($attempU>=$intentosU){
        $message = "'Usuario' bloqueado por 15 minutos, contando desde las ".$rowFA['datetime'];
    } elseif ($username != $UsernamaDB) {
        $message = "El 'Usuario' que has introducido no coincide. ";
    } elseif ($save_passw != $passwordDB) {
        $message = "Tu 'Contraseña' introducido no coincide. ";
    } elseif($save_passw == $passwordDB && $username == $UsernamaDB) {
        $_SESSION["id_user"] = $rowU['id'];
        $con->query("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE ip = '$ip'");
        $con->query("DELETE FROM fail_attempt WHERE id_user ='$id_user'");
    }
    //validando Usuario y Contraseña - FIN

    if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
        header("Location:http://localhost/login/index.php");
    }
}
?>
<h1><?php if($message!="") { echo $message; } ?></h1>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuario">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
  <!-- captcha-->
  <?php if ( (isset($failed_login_attempt) && $failed_login_attempt >= 1) || (count($_POST)>0) ) { ?>
    <img src="captcha.php" id="phoca-captcha"/>
    <input name="vcode" type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
   <?php } ?>
  <!-- fin-->
  <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión" id="button-login">
</form>
```

**index.php** Pagina de Bienvenida, luego del login.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
        header("Location:http://localhost/login/login.php");
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
        //al ingresar actualiza campo "logindatetime"
        refrescalogin();
        //invocar cada 1 minuto
        setInterval(refrescalogin,60000);
    });
    function refrescalogin(){
        $.ajax({url: "logueado.php?cerrar=0", success: function(result){console.log(result);}});
    }
  </script>
</head>
<style>
    .boton{text-align: right;background: #ccc;display: inline-block;right: 10px;position: absolute;padding: 5px;box-shadow:0px -5px 3px #bbb inset,-5px 0px 3px #bbb inset,5px 0px 3px #aaa inset,0px 5px 3px #aaa inset;   }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="boton"><a href="logueado.php?cerrar=1">Cerrar Sesion</a></div>
    Bienvenido
</body>
</html>
```

**logueado.php** Actualizara el campo `logindatetime` y cerrara sesion

```
<?php
session_start();
$id_user = $_SESSION["id_user"];
$con =  @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'systemuser');
$logindatetime=($_GET['cerrar']=='1')?"NULL":"NOW()";
$sql="UPDATE users SET logindatetime=$logindatetime WHERE id = $id_user";
$con->query($sql);

if($_GET['cerrar']=='1'){
    unset($_SESSION['id_user']);
    header("Location:http://localhost/login/login.php");
}else{
    echo("datos refrescados");
}
?>
```

*Captura*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrían surgir mas casos de uso o validaciones que ajustarían mas el código. Si tienes dudas, conversamos por lo comentarios.

Comment: no me registra datos en la tabla `login_attempts` solo en la tabla `fail_attempt` tengo un id (3) de un usuario pero en `fail_attempt` me registra el valor de un id (0) no entiendo, puedes enviarme los archivos por box o dropbox. me hubiese gustado que hubieses implementado las contraseña segura de `password_hash()` y orientado a objetos mysqli para que así se acople a la pregunta de un **sistema seguro** pero bueno amigo se que pido mucho :) puedes enviarme los archivos porque no entiendo no me registran datos en la tabla

Comment: y me registra los siguientes errores <br />
`<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\login.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\login.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />`

Comment: y el formulario del código del captcha se desaparece al actualizar la página.

Comment: Fijate en tu codigo publicado, dices "SELECT * FROM failed_login WHERE ip='$ip' AND **date**..." pero en la estructura de Base de Datos se llama **datetime** asegurate que en tu base de datos las tablas esten como la publicacion, osea **datetime**

Comment: Ese error es porque hay un problema en la consulta a BD, y desaparece el captcha porque no esta registrando en la BD

Comment: se soluciono todos los errores, solo que sigue mostrando el id en `0` y existe un nuevo error `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\`prueba\login.php</b> on line <b>71</b><br />`

Comment: Fijate en la BD de la publicacion, la tabla `users` su primer campo se llama `id`, verifica que en tu BD este asi, derepente lo tienes como "id_user" yo he armado la BD tal como tu publicacion, asegurate que tu BD este asi

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65621/discussion-between-j-mick-and-juliocpiro).

Comment: existe problemas en el código

Comment: al acceder al sistema correctamente me redirecciona al index hasta ahí bien pero si vuelvo a login.php este me deja ingresar al login.php y no debería porque el usuario ya se encuentra logueado.

Comment: Descomenta el primer else *else{
    unset($_SESSION['id_user']);
})*, esto se puso para limpiar el acceso por si el usuario cierra desde la pestaña sin usar el boton "cerrar"

Answer (score -2):

En realidad bloquear la IP no es una buena idea, ya que el 99% de los usuarios poseen IP dinámicas y solo reiniciar el router me permitiría obtener una nueva IP.

Una opción sería realizar un control más específico, pero la implementación requiere análisis ya que como en todo sistema; mientras más complejo, más fácil que presente errores y más caro de mantener.

**ESTADO DEL USUARIO**

Al realizar el logon el usuario podrías guardar un estado de online en la base y mientras el estado este presente nadie más puede conectarse al sistema.
El mismo se refresca después de unos minutos sin interacción del usuario en el sitio o al hacer logoff.

**ANÁLISIS DE ACTIVIDAD**

Podrías implementar una tabla de actividad para cada usuario, en el cual se registre las IP's y GEOlocalización desde las cuales se conectan al sistema, desde la misma tendrías que generar reportes y analizar o comprar un sistema que realice ese tipo de análisis.

**LOGIN CON DOBLE AUTENTICACIÓN**

Hay varias formas de implementarla, por ejemplo un Token con una serie de números los cuales debe ingresar, estos pueden ser enviados a través de un mensaje de correo, APP o por un SMS.

**INGENIERIA SOCIAL**

Linkear el acceso de tu plataforma a través de una cuenta de Facebook/Instagrama/Linekdin/etc. Este tipo de conexión con redes sociales reduce la posibilidad de compartir cuentas.

Dependiendo de la criticidad y el alcance de tu sistema, estos proyectos de seguridad dejan de ser opcionales para proteger tanto a la empresa como al cliente.

Comment: amigo si había comentado que no me parece bien bloquear la `ip` el código está mal planteado o no me parece el correcto pero si es buen ejemplo este código lo encontré en un artículo en la web, lo que si quiero es igual bloquear el usuario temporalmente por un tiempo de 15 minutos esté sistema lo utilizan los sistemas financieros, bancos etc. Ahora como mencionas realizar un control más específico me parece correcto.

Comment: crear una tabla de registro de actividad en ella igual registrar la IP contabilizar los intentos fallidos tomar el registro del ID del usuario y mediante a los 5 intentos fallidos bloquear al usuario por un tiempo de 15 minutos bloquear el usuario no el `Ip`. **Ahora** el bloqueo indifinivo del usuario es crear otra tabla con otros registros si el usuario inicio sesión es diferentes localidades de diferentes países bloquear el usuario al registrar estos datos con 3 direcciones distintas de diferentes localidades bloquear el usuario definitivamente

Comment: y adicional lo que me has comentado es perfecto sería genial pero no dejar aparte lo que he comentado me podrías crear un ejemplo un planteamiento del código PHP me cuesta guiarme, es fácil crear las tablas imaginar la lógica pero el porblema es el planteamiento me ayudas con un ejemplo sencillo

Comment: @J.Mick Claro para la geolocalización, puedes bajar una tabla para llenar tu base y desde ahi realizar las comparaciones o usar un servicio externo   
[$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
echo $details->city; // -> "Caracas"]

Comment: @J.Mick Ten en consideración que esto genera una carga para tu servicio de soporte, ya que mucha gente se conecta usando proxys enmascarando su sitio real y puedes terminar baneando usuarios legítimos.