# ¿Cómo configurar una base de datos para login?

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, apache, xampp

¿Cómo configuro la base de datos? Estoy usando XAMPP, quiero almacenar a los usuarios y comparar resultados para cuando pongan un mismo usuario diga que está en uso

Comment: Quizás puedes encontrar una respuesta en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96997/c%c3%b3mo-crear-un-sistema-seguro-de-acceso-con-php-mysqli

Comment: gracias por el dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que la base de datos sea sencilla, con que crees una tabla de 3 columnas (id, user, pass), es suficiente.

Ahora... si quieres que la base de datos sea un poco más segura o dinámica y con muchos datos, entonces te recomiendo crear 2, 3, 4 o más tablas (según la necesidad y el tipo de seguridad que vayas a implementar dependiendo de cómo programes):

- usuarios: Tabla con los datos de inicio de sesión de todos los usuarios registrados para poder ingresar al sistema (recomiendo usar SHA1 para encriptar las contraseñas).
  Ejemplo:
  id | user | pass
- datos_usuarios: Tabla con los datos personales de todos los usuarios.
  Ejemplo:
  id | id_user | nombre | apellido | nacimiento | email | id_foto
- fotos_usuarios: Taba con las direcciones de las fotos relacionadas a cada usuario.
  Ejemplo:
  id | id_user | foto
- lista_negra: Tabla con los IDs de usuarios bloqueados o eliminados.
  Ejemplo:
  id | id_user | bloqueado | eliminado

Como Ing. de Seg. Informática, siempre aconsejo hacer las cosas más seguras y no tan sencillas si es que tenés en mente trabajar en alguna empresa, dado que es la manera en que más se trabaja. Cabe aclarar que hacer varias tablas tiene sus beneficios y sus contras.

- Por un lado es últil, como dije más arriba, para trabajar de manera más dinámica y segura, además de que las tablas son más limpias al momento de hacer una petición SQL o al querer hacer una modificación manualmente desde PHPMyAdmin, NGinx o cualquiera sea que estés usando.
- Por otro lado, puede prestar a confusión si los nombres de las tablas o columnas no son muy claras, y además hay que saber entender bien cómo están vinculadas las tablas entre sí y para qué van a ser usadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente esto me ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Pues realmente lo único que necesitas después de crear tu base de datos es crear una tabla `usuarios` en dicha tabla puedes colocar las columnas mas esenciales (id, user, password) y listo con eso puedes realizar peticiones a dicha tabla ya sea para seleccionar, crear, editar o eliminar.

Comment: ¿Eso seria todo? ¿automaticamente compara los datos y te avisa en la app que ya hay un usuario?

Comment: Ya lo de comparar datos es código que debes hacer en tus archivos, esto no es magia, si preguntas como configurar la base de datos pues eso es lo básico a configurar para un login, el resto va por cuenta de tu lógica en código

Comment: se que no es magia por lo mismo pregunte sobre como comparar datos,mejor preguntar que quedar con la duda

Comment: Si claro tienes razón pero ya lo que quieres lograr es un desarrollo  de nivel intermedio, yo solo te respondí tu pregunta **¿Cómo configurar una base de datos para login?**

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Camilo, esto no es magia y la base de datos sólo te va a guardar los datos. Para hacer las comparaciones necesitas un lenguaje de programación para verificar al usuario y contraseña.
Si fueras un poco más específico sobre en qué trabajas, te podríamos ayudar.
Por ejemplo, yo hice un sistema de login en php con javascript y te puedo orientar.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion para alertar cuando estes en peligro y se mande mensajes a otros telefonos previamente seleccionados, claro solo cuando lo requieras sin que vigilen cada paso, respetando la privacidad, pero estoy algo atorado en la parte de la base de datos y la comparación.

Comment: La base de datos no te va a hacer la comparación, necesitas buscar en el lenguaje de programación en el que lo estás desarrollando, recuerda que la base de datos sólo guarda datos y algunas operaciones sobre estos