# Entrar a pagina con registro

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo en php el cual quiero entrar a una url con  mi user y pass

```
<?php
$user = "myUsser";
$pass = "myPass";

$url = "https://uqload.com/?user=$user&pass=$pass&op=my_files";
header("Location: $url");
exit; 
?>
```

mi problema es que tan solo me abre un link, que al pulsarlo si entro en la url como registrado, mi pregunta es: como puedo hacerlo para entrar direcctamente?

esta es la url que me muestra el navegador despues de el login y la que quiero entrar con php

> https://uqload.com/?op=my_files

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por *entrar directamente*?

Comment: Al abrir el archivo .php entrar en esa url logeado ya

Comment: Para logear directamente, tendrás que hacer una comprobación de los datos que obtienes por `GET` y redirigirlo / dar acceso directamente desde la página `uqload` en caso que sean correctos el usuario y su contraseña a la página deseada.

Comment: algun tuto)? no se ni como empezar

Comment: ¿Como estas creando tu login? ¿No veo la `$_SESSION` donde guardas al usuario, están usando Base de Datos para tu login? Te puedo dejar un ejemplo de un sistema de login: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96997/c%c3%b3mo-crear-un-sistema-seguro-de-acceso-con-php-mysqli

Comment: no, no es una base de datos es https://uqload.com/